# How does Java's serialization work and when it should be used instead of some other persistence technique?

Tags: java, serialization

I've been lately trying to learn more and generally test Java's serialization for both work and personal projects and I must say that the more I know about it, the less I like it. This may be caused by misinformation though so that's why I'm asking these two things from you all:

**1:** On byte level, how does serialization know how to match serialized values with some class?

One of my problems right here is that I made a small test with ArrayList containing values "one", "two", "three". After serialization the byte array took 78 bytes which seems awfully lot for such low amount of information(19+3+3+4 bytes). Granted there's bound to be some overhead but this leads to my second question:

**2:** Can serialization be considered a good method for persisting objects at all? Now obviously if I'd use some homemade XML format the persistence data would be something like this

```xml
<object>
    <class="java.util.ArrayList">
    <!-- Object array inside Arraylist is called elementData -->
    <field name="elementData">
        <value>One</value>
        <value>Two</value>
        <value>Three</value>
    </field>
</object>
```

which, like XML in general, is a bit bloated and takes 138 bytes(without whitespaces, that is). The same in JSON could be

```json
{
    "java.util.ArrayList": {
        "elementData": [
            "one",
            "two",
            "three"
        ]
    }
}
```

which is 75 bytes so already slightly  smaller than Java's serialization. With these text-based formats it's of course obvious that there has to be a way to represent your basic data as text, numbers or any combination of both.

So to recap, how does serialization work on byte/bit level, when it should be used and when it shouldn't be used and what are real benefits of serialization besides that it comes standard in Java?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I would personally try to avoid Java's "built-in" serialization:

- It's not portable to other platforms
- It's not hugely efficient
- It's fragile - getting it to cope with multiple versions of a class is somewhat tricky. Even changing compilers can break serialization unless you're careful.

For details of what the actual bytes mean, see the [Java Object Serialization Specification](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html).

There are various alternatives, such as:

- XML and JSON, as you've shown (various XML flavours, of course)
- [YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaml)
- Facebook's [Thrift](http://incubator.apache.org/thrift/) (RPC as well as serialization)
- [Google Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/)
- [Hessian](http://hessian.caucho.com/) (web services as well as serialization)
- [Apache Avro](http://avro.apache.org/)
- Your own custom format

(Disclaimer: I work for Google, and I'm doing a port of Protocol Buffers to C# as my 20% project, so clearly I think that's a good bit of technology :)

Cross-platform formats are almost always more restrictive than platform-specific formats for obvious reasons - Protocol Buffers has a pretty limited set of native types, for example - but the interoperability can be incredibly useful. You also need to consider the impact of versioning, with backward and forward compatibility, etc. The text formats are generally hand-editable, but tend to be less efficient in both space and time.

Basically, you need to look at your requirements carefully.

Comment: Another alternative would be to store it in a database like SQLite, especially if the objects aren't deeply nested.

Comment: I started down the java serialization path for some not very critical files we needed to persist because it was "simple".  Only it wasn't, because we had inheritance issues.  I solved all this but I was unhappy that I couldn't read the files.  Then I realized that since we were already using JSON for our wire protocol, I could use JSON for serialization.  It all worked without changing all the data classes to implement Serializable and writing readObject() methods.  And anyway, how the heck are they calling private methods like readObject() and writeObject().  Much happier this way.

Comment: @JonSkeet : Can you please elaborate internal architecture of this marker interface and **When we should go for serialization**

Comment: @VedPrakash: I'm not sure what you mean by "internal architecture of this marker interface" but in terms of when you should Java's own binary implementation of serialisation, I'd pretty much always avoid it, using one of the schemes listed in my answer instead.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Got it your answer and understood.

Answer (score 11):

The main advantage of serialization is that it is extremely easy to use, relatively fast, and preserves actual Java object meshes.

But you have to realize that it's not really meant to be used for storing data, but mainly as a way for different JVM instances to communicate over a network using the RMI protocol.

Answer (score 5):

see the Java Object [Serialization Stream Protocol](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html) for a description of the file format an grammar used for serialized objects.

Personally I think the built-in serialization is acceptable to persist short-lived data (e.g. store the state of a session object between to http-requests) which is not relevant outside your application.

For data that has a longer live-time or should be used outside your application, I'd persist either into a database or at least use a more commonly used format...

Comment: I agree. It meant for something like transfer object over the wire, or activate/passivate kinda things, not for persisting objects, nor for outside usage.

Answer (score 4):

> How does Java's built-in serialization works?

Whenever we want to serialize an object, we implement java.io.Serializable interface. The interface which does not have any methods to implement, even though we are implementing it to **indicate something to compiler or JVM** (known as **Marker Interface**). So if JVM sees a Class is Serializable it perform some pre-processing operation on those classes. The operation is, it adds the following two sample methods.

```
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream stream)
            throws IOException {
        stream.writeObject(name); // object property
        stream.writeObject(address); // object property
    }

    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream stream)
            throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        name = (String) stream.readObject(); // object property
        address = (String) stream.readObject();// object property
    }
```

> When it should be used instead of some other persistence technique?

The built in `Serialization` is useful when sender and receiver both are Java.   If you want to avoid the above kind of problems, we use XML or JSON with the help of frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into this dilemma about a month ago (see [the question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244493/homemade-vs-java-serialization)).

The main lesson I learned from it is use Java serialization only when necessary and if there's no other option. Like Jon said, it has it's downfalls, while other serialization techniques are much easier, faster and more portable.

Answer (score 0):

Serializing means that you put your structured data in your classes into a flat order of bytecode to save it.

You should generally use other techniques than the buildin java-method, it is just made to work out of the box but if you have some changing contents or changing orders in future in your serialized classes, you get into trouble because you'll cannot load them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of Java Object Serialization (JOS) is that it just works.  There are also tools out there that do the same as JOS, but use an XML format instead of a binary format.

About the length: JOS writes some class information at the start, instead of as part of each instance - e.g. the full field names are recorded once, and an index into that list of names is used for instances of the class.   This makes the output longer if you write only one instance of the class, but is more efficient if you write several (different) instances of it.  It's not clear to me if your example actually uses a class, but this is the general reason why JOS is longer than one would expect.

BTW: this is incidental, but I don't think JSON records class names (as you have in your example), and so it might not do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why storing a tiny amount of information is serial form is relatively large is that it stores information about the classes of the objects it is serialising. If you store a duplicate of your list, then you'll see that the file hasn't grown by much. Store the same object twice and the difference is tiny.

The important pros are: relatively easy to use, quite fast and can evolve (just like XML). However, the data is rather opaque, it is Java-only, tightly couples data to classes and untrusted data can easily cause DoS. You should think about the serialised form, rather than just slapping `implements Serializable` everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have too much data, you can save objects into a java.util.Properties object.  An example of a key/value pair would be user_1234_firstname = Peter. Using reflection to save and load objects can make things easier.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest to write a custom written API.