# serialization and externalization in java

Tags: java, serialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between Serializable and Externalizable in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817853/what-is-the-difference-between-serializable-and-externalizable-in-java)

what is the difference between serialization and externalization in java?

Comment: -1 as duplicate (see answer by Macarse)

Answer (score 4):

Basically, the difference between [`Serializable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) and [`Externalizable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html) is that with classes which implement `Serializable`, the serialization of the object is taken care of automatically, while classes that implement `Externalizable` is responsible for serializing itself, without the help of default serialization procedures.

There is more information provided in the API Specification for the [`Externalizable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html) interface, and the [`Serializable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface. From the `Externalizable` interface documentation:

> Only the identity of the class of an
>   Externalizable instance is written in
>   the serialization stream and it is the
>   responsibility of the class to save
>   and restore the contents of its
>   instances. The writeExternal and
>   readExternal methods of the
>   Externalizable interface are
>   implemented by a class to give the
>   class complete control over the format
>   and contents of the stream for an
>   object and its supertypes.

The [Discover the secrets of the Java Serialization API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javaserial-1536170.html) article has a discussion on the `Externalizable` interface in the "Create Your Own Protocol: the Externalizable Interface" section.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend reading an article called [**Understand When to Serialize v. Externalize Objects in Java**](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/understand-when-to-serialize-v-externalize-objects-in-java/) that described the differences between serialization and externalization.

First is describes what serialization is:

> The serialization of objects in Java
>   allows you to make a byte sequence
>   from any object that has implemented
>   the Serializable interface; it also
>   allows you to turn that byte sequence
>   back into an object.

Next it describes a situation in which externalization might be preferable to serialization:

> There might be times when you have
>   special requirements for the
>   serialization of an object. For
>   example, you may have some
>   security-sensitive parts of the
>   object, like passwords, which you do
>   not want to keep and transfer
>   somewhere. Or, it may be worthless to
>   save a particular object referenced
>   from the main object because its value
>   will become worthless after restoring.
>
> You can control the process of
>   serialization by implementing the
>   Externalizable interface instead of
>   Serializable. This interface extends
>   the original Serializable interface
>   and adds writeExternal() and
>   readExternal(). These two methods will
>   automatically be called in your
>   object's serialization and
>   deserialization, allowing you to
>   control the whole process.

I recommend reading the entire article, because the excerpts above do not cover the details. The article also contains several code snippets you might find useful.

Comment: Fixed the link, thanks!