# Serialising and immutable objects

Tags: java, serialization, final

I have a class which is intended for immutable use, hence I would like to label all the fields `final`.

However the class is serialized and deserialized to send over the network. For this to work an empty constructor is required. This prevents me creating the final fields.

I'm sure this is a fairly common problem but I can't find a solution. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the typical serialization case, it is not required that class have an empty constructor or non-final fields to be serializable.

Now, if you have to do your own serialization, or you need to subclass a class that doesn't implement Serializable, that is a different story.

So you need to provide some more details of how you are having a problem.

Comment: Thanks, I was using the typical method of serialization but had always supplied an empty constructor as that was how I thought it worked.

Answer (score 9):

A no-arg constructor is not required. The most derived non-serialisable class does need a no-arg constructor available to the least-most derived serialisable class.

If you need to mutate fields inside a `readObject`, then use a serial proxy through `readResolve` and `writeReplace`.

Answer (score 5):

This issue is an [open bug on the Java language](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6379948).  (Note that this only applies if you have to do the serialization manually, such as with readObject)

Comment: From the evaluation: "the problem applies to final instance fields other than the class's serializable fields" so in the standard case it works fine. Nick seems to be doing something different.

Comment: Ah yes, I should add a disclaimer that this only applies if you have to hook into readObject or something like that.

Answer (score 4):

To echo what has been said, no-arg constructors are not a requirement if you are taking the route of implementing the `java.io.Serializable` interface. Take a look at the `java.lang.Integer` source code for example, a simple serializable/immutable class that has two constructors: one that takes an int, and one that takes a String. Source code: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Integer.java.html. Javadoc: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html.

Also depending on the complexity of your class and what you are doing, you could consider implementing serialization via the `java.io.Externalizable` interface (although some consider it outdated, and it DOES require a no-arg constructor). Here's an overview on SO: [What is the difference between Serializable and Externalizable in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817853/what-is-the-difference-between-serializable-and-externalizable-in-java), and here's the official Java tutorial: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/javabeans/persistence/index.html.

Answer (score 3):

For the record, since I had a similar issue:
I had a message "*java.io.InvalidClassException: com.example.stuff.FooBar; com.example.stuff.FooBar; no valid constructor*"

I thought it was because it was lacking a default constructor. But the above answers confirm it is not mandatory (but our app. uses an old serializer that indeed require a default constructor, so the case can arise).

Then I found a page stating:

> If a class that is designed for inheritance is not serializable, it
>   may be impossible to write a serializable subclass. Specifically, it
>   will be impossible if the superclass does not provide an accessible
>   parameterless constructor.

Hence the message I got, I suppose. It appeared that the core issue was classical: I declared a class as serializable, but the superclass was not! I moved the Serializable interface up in the hierarchy, and all was well.

But the message was a bit misleading... :-)

Answer (score 3):

A no-arg constructor is not required. Let's read the source code:

```
// java.io.ObjectStreamClass
private static Constructor<?> getSerializableConstructor(Class<?> cl) {
    Class<?> initCl = cl;
    while (Serializable.class.isAssignableFrom(initCl)) {
        if ((initCl = initCl.getSuperclass()) == null) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

So, actually the no-arg constructor is required in the nearest not `Serializable` class in the type hierarchy.

It means the following class `Domain` can be serialized.

```
class Domain implements Serializable {
    private final int a;

    public Domain(int a) {
      this.a = a;
    }
}
```

But the class `Son` can't:

```
class Father{
  private final int a;

  public Father(int a) {
    this.a = a;
  }
}

class Son extends Father implements Serializable {
  public Son(int a) {
    super(a);
  }
}
```