# Serialize property of a field instead of entire field

Tags: java, json, jackson

I've searched on internet about my problem.. but I not found a good solution.

I need to get the json showed at the end:

I've 2 classes

```
class Order {
    Long id;

    Client client;
}

class Client {
    Long id;
}
```

When I serialize Order I get:

```
[{"id":1,"client":{"id":1}]
```

But I want instead to obtain:

```
[{"id":1,"client":1}]
```

How can i reach this?

Thank you for any solution!!!
Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**-** When a class implements `Serializable`, then **its** object or the object of **its Sub-class** are made to be `Serialized`.

**-** Now its the `Fields` of the Object, **Not** the `Object` itself that is being Serialized.

**-** And the `entire object graph` **needs** to be serialized, if **not the Serialization fails.**

**-** So `Client` being an `Object Reference Variable` in `Order` Class will get Serialize, and so does its `Field` **id**.

**-** You **canNot Serialize** property of a field instead of entire field, **but** if you want you can **prevent** `Field` from being serialized using `transient` keyword.

Comment: I can hardly read what you are writing. Seriously you should not overuse `code` and **bold** words.

Comment: This is also my JPA domain class.. I cannot make it transient. One solution is to use @JSonIgnore on the field and use a transient getter like getClientId()..

Comment: @mserioli...you dont need to make it transient.... that will lead to the prevention of id field to be serialized...i think you don't want that... i just mentioned it, to tell you that what you want is not possible

Comment: Frankly i have read it online before, but never tried implementing it..... Moreover i am bit confused...whats wrong in this.. `"client":{"id":1}` This says that when the object graph was Serialized, then `an Object Reference Variable in Order class, named client of type Client which have a Field name id whose value is 1`

Answer (score 1):

Use `@JsonValue` annotation:

```
class Client {
    @JsonValue Long id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your own serialization method for this class.

For example check this Thread: [Implementing my own serialization in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929577/implementing-my-own-serialization-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You could also try genson library http://code.google.com/p/genson/.
It has most of Jackson features and some other nice ones that jackson does not provide.

To solve your problem with genson and few code you can do it that way:

```
public class Order {
    Long id;
    @JsonIgnore Client client;
    @JsonProperty("client") public Long getClientId() {
        return client.id;
    }
}

public static class Client {
    Long id;
}

System.out.println(new Genson().serialize(order));
```

If you prefer you can also write a custom serializer with genson see [here](http://code.google.com/p/genson/wiki/GettingStarted#Custom_Converter). But in your case it is not necessary.