# Java List.add() UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, list, exception, arraylist, unsupportedoperation

I try to add objects to a `List<String>` instance but it throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`.
Does anyone know why?

My Java code:

```
String[] membersArray = request.getParameterValues('members');
List<String> membersList = Arrays.asList(membersArray);

for (String member : membersList) {
    Person person = Dao.findByName(member);
    List<String> seeAlso;
    seeAlso = person.getSeeAlso();
    if (!seeAlso.contains(groupDn)){
        seeAlso.add(groupDn);
        person.setSeeAlso(seeAlso);
    }
}
```

The error message:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)
    java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Answer (score 569, accepted):

Not every [`List`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) implementation supports the `add()` method.

One common example is the `List` returned by [`Arrays.asList()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29): it is documented **not** to support any structural modification (i.e. removing or adding elements) (emphasis mine):

> Returns a **fixed-size** list backed by the specified array.

Even if that's not the specific `List` you're trying to modify, the answer still applies to other `List` implementations that are either immutable or only allow some selected changes.

You can find out about this by reading the documentation of [`UnsupportedOperationException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html) and [`List.add()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28E%29), which documents this to be an "(optional operation)". The precise meaning of this phrase is explained at the top of the `List` documentation.

As a workaround you can create a copy of the list to a known-modifiable implementation like `ArrayList`:

```
seeAlso = new ArrayList<>(seeAlso);
```

Comment: so i have to use the list instance to test if it contain my element and the array instance when i have to add an element? that's write?

Comment: @Florito: This will work though: `List<String> listMembres = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(tabMembres));` :)

Comment: or maybe i have to cast my List object to ArrayList or another?

Comment: No, not really. If you want to add an element to a `List` implementation that doesn't allow addition, then you'll have to copy that `List` to an implementation that does (`ArrayList` is a common candidate) and add to that.

Answer (score 13):

Many of the List implementation support limited support to add/remove, and Arrays.asList(membersArray) is one of that. You need to insert the record in java.util.ArrayList or use the below approach to convert into ArrayList.

With the minimal change in your code, you can do below to convert a list to ArrayList. The first solution is having a minimum change in your solution, but the second one is more optimized, I guess.

```
    String[] membersArray = request.getParameterValues('members');
    ArrayList<String> membersList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(membersArray));
```

OR

```
    String[] membersArray = request.getParameterValues('members');
    ArrayList<String> membersList = Stream.of(membersArray).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Answer (score 5):

Form the Inheritance concept, If some perticular method is not available in the current class it will search for that method in super classes. If available it executes.

> It executes **`AbstractList<E>`** class **`add()`** method which throws [`UnsupportedOperationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html).

---

When you are converting from an Array to a Collection Obejct. i.e., array-based to collection-based API then it is going to provide you fixed-size collection object, because Array's behaviour is of Fixed size.

> java.util.Arrays.asList( T... a )

Souce samples for conformation.

```
public class Arrays {
    public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
        return new java.util.Arrays.ArrayList.ArrayList<>(a); // Arrays Inner Class ArrayList
    }
    //...
    private static class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E> implements RandomAccess, java.io.Serializable {
        //...
    }
}
public abstract class AbstractList<E> extends AbstractCollection<E> implements List<E> {
    public void add(int index, E element) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    public E set(int index, E element) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    public E remove(int index) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return new Itr();
    }
    private class Itr implements Iterator<E> {
        //...
    }

    public ListIterator<E> listIterator() {
        return listIterator(0);
    }
    private class ListItr extends Itr implements ListIterator<E> {
        //...
    }
}
```

Form the above Source you may observe that `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` class doesn't `@Override add(index, element), set(index, element), remove(index)`. So, From inheritance it executes super `AbstractList<E>` class `add()` function which throws `UnsupportedOperationException`.

As `AbstractList<E>` is an abstract class it provides the implementation to `iterator() and listIterator()`. So, that we can iterate over the list object.

```java
List<String> list_of_Arrays = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "a", "b" ,"c"});

try {
    list_of_Arrays.add("Yashwanth.M");
} catch(java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException e) {
    System.out.println("List Interface executes AbstractList add() fucntion which throws UnsupportedOperationException.");
}
System.out.println("Arrays → List : " + list_of_Arrays);

Iterator<String> iterator = list_of_Arrays.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) System.out.println("Iteration : " + iterator.next() );

ListIterator<String> listIterator = list_of_Arrays.listIterator();
while (listIterator.hasNext())    System.out.println("Forward  iteration : " + listIterator.next() );
while(listIterator.hasPrevious()) System.out.println("Backward iteration : " + listIterator.previous());
```

You can even create Fixed-Size array form Collections class `Collections.unmodifiableList(list);`

Sample Source:

```
public class Collections {
    public static <T> List<T> unmodifiableList(List<? extends T> list) {
        return (list instanceof RandomAccess ?
                new UnmodifiableRandomAccessList<>(list) :
                new UnmodifiableList<>(list));
    }
}
```

---

A [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/index.html) — sometimes called a container — is simply an object that groups multiple elements into a single unit. Collections are used to store, retrieve, manipulate, and communicate aggregate data.

@see also

- [HashMap `vs` HashTable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48094803/5081877)
- [Object Serialization uses the Serializable and Externalizable interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48301301/5081877)

Answer (score 3):

You will also get this exception if you attempt to `add` to a `List<T>` returned by  [`Collections.singletonList(T o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonList(T)):

> Returns an **immutable** list containing only the specified object. The returned list is serializable.

The JVM does not implement `add()` for `Collections.singletonList`

Answer (score 2):

List membersList = Arrays.asList(membersArray);

returns immutable list, what you need to do is

new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(membersArray)); to make it mutable

Comment: It is not an immutable list.  Mutation operations that don't change the list length are supported / will work.  The key thing is that the list's length cannot change because the list is backed by an array ... whose length can't change.

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize your List seeAlso :

```
List<String> seeAlso = new Vector<String>();
```

or

```
List<String> seeAlso = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: An uninitialized variable won't cause `UnsupportedOperationException` in `add()`.  You would get an NPE instead.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the UnsupportedOperationException is because the Arrays.asList() method returns a fixed-size list backed by the original array. This means that you cannot modify the size of the list by adding or removing elements, and attempting to do so will result in an UnsupportedOperationException.

Answer (score -3):

You cannot modify a result from a LDAP query. Your problem is in this line:

```
seeAlso.add(groupDn);
```

The seeAlso list is unmodifiable.

Comment: the problem is not due to that but as Joachim pointed out above it is to do with implementations of List that might not support add().

Answer (score -4):

instead of using add() we can use addall()

```
{ seeAlso.addall(groupDn); }
```

add adds a single item, while addAll adds each item from the collection one by one. In the end, both methods return true if the collection has been modified. In case of ArrayList this is trivial, because the collection is always modified, but other collections, such as Set, may return false if items being added are already there.