# Check if Windows XP or later in Java?

Tags: java, windows, operating-system, detect

What would be the easiest way to check that the operating system running my Java application is Windows XP  or later?

**EDIT:** I know about `System.getProperty("os.name")` but I don't know the best way and/or most efficient way to check what version of  Windows is running. Ideally, I would also like to make it future proof so that if another version of Windows is released I don't need to change the code.

Comment: Check `System.getProperty("os.name")`

Comment: @BackSlash Is that the only way? If so, how could I make the if statement as short as possible rather than having masses of conditions.

Comment: @Andy Use a regular expression. e.g., match against `Windows (?:XP|Vista|7|8)`.

Comment: I was hoping that there might also be a way to future proof it, so I could rather check if the OS is not XP or higher

Comment: So you want to be able to get some sort of os version number?

Comment: @BenjaminDale Yes, that would probably be best

Comment: @BenjaminDale That is a shame, I guess I will just have to check according to the latest version of Windows and release a new version of my application if anything changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mkyong has given a tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-detect-os-in-java-systemgetpropertyosname/

It relies on `System.getProperty("os.name")`

Comment: Wow, you must have been milliseconds away from not being able to post an answer

Comment: That only determines whether the OS is Windows though, not which version

Comment: @Andy On my system, the `os.name` property says `Windows 8`.

Comment: @Andy: You will probably get better results using `"os.version"`, parsing it, and comparing it with [windows versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Although this may be helpful to determine if someone is running Windows, it's useless to find out if the Windows version is higher than a specific version.  For specific versions, I'd recommend the property `System.getProperty("os.version")` instead.  More detailed answer provided below.

Answer (score 0):

Since Windows reliably reports its version information as a `float`, "XP or higher" can be calculated by knowing what each Windows version is and comparing.

The shorthand:

```
// Is this XP or higher?
// Well, XP Reports as 5.1 (32-bit) or 5.2 (64-bit).  All higher OSs use a higher version
final boolean XP_OR_HIGHER = (Float.parseFloat(System.getProperty("os.version")) >= 5.1f);
```

But due to exceptions that can be raised with parsing a System value, combined with the fact that XP is EOL and it's more likely that someone is looking for a newer OS comparison... here's a more comprehensive way to do it.

**Note:** With Windows 10, all versions are reported as `10.0` regardless of how much Microsoft changed between releases.  For finer detail, you will have to look into the registry (See also `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ReleaseId`).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class WinVer {
    enum WindowsType {
        /*
         * Keep descending for best match, or rewrite using comparitor
         */
        WINDOWS_10(10.0f),
        WINDOWS_8_1(6.3f),
        WINDOWS_8(6.2f),
        WINDOWS_7(6.1f),
        WINDOWS_VISTA(6.0f),
        WINDOWS_XP_64(5.2f),
        WINDOWS_XP(5.1f),
        WINDOWS_ME(4.9f),
        WINDOWS_2000(5.0f),
        WINDOWS_NT(4.0f), // or Win95
        UNKNOWN(0.0f);

        private float version;

        WindowsType(float version) {
            this.version = version;
        }

        public static float parseFloat(String versionString) {
            float version = 0.0f;
            /*
             * Sanitize the String.
             *
             * Windows version is generally formatted x.x (e.g. 3.1, 6.1, 10.0)
             * This format can later be treated as a float for comparison.
             * Since we have no guarantee the String will be formatted properly, we'll sanitize it.
             * For more complex comparisons, try a SemVer library, such as zafarkhaja/jsemver. <3
             */
            List<String> parts = Arrays.asList(versionString.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "").split("\\."));

            // Fix .add(...), .remove(...), see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5755510/3196753
            parts = new ArrayList<>(parts);

            // Fix length
            while (parts.size() != 2) {
                if (parts.size() > 2) {
                    // pop off last element
                    parts.remove(parts.size() - 1);
                }
                if (parts.size() < 2) {
                    // push zero
                    parts.add("0");
                }
            }

            String sanitized = String.join(".", parts.toArray(new String[0]));
            try {
                version = Float.parseFloat(sanitized);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.err.println("ERROR: Something went wrong parsing " + sanitized + " as a float");
            }

            return version;
        }

        public static WindowsType match(float version) {
            WindowsType detectedType = UNKNOWN;

            // Warning: Iterates in order they were declared.  If you don't like this, write a proper comparator instead. <3
            for (WindowsType type : WindowsType.values()) {
                if (type.version >= version) {
                    detectedType = type;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return detectedType;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String... args) {

        String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
        String osVer = System.getProperty("os.version");

        if (osName.toLowerCase().startsWith("windows")) {
            System.out.println("Yes, you appear to be running windows");
            float windowsVersion = WindowsType.parseFloat(osVer);
            System.out.println(" - Windows version reported is: " + windowsVersion);
            WindowsType windowsType = WindowsType.match(windowsVersion);
            System.out.println(" - Windows type is detected as: " + windowsType);

            if(windowsVersion >= WindowsType.WINDOWS_XP.version) {
                System.out.println("Yes, this OS is Windows XP or higher.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("No, this OS is NOT Windows XP or higher.");
            }
        }
    }

}
```