# deleting an element in debug mode in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I'm running my code in debug mode in eclipse and in the middle of it, I want to change the size of a List,say from 9 to 6, by deleting 3 elements.

But I'm not seeing any option to do that, in fact what I'm seeing is the option to change the values present in the elements.

So how can I delete the elements itself from the List ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the "Variables" tabs on eclipse "Debug" view focused on your current evaluated code.
In "Debug" view,  right-click on "Value" cell inside the "Variables" table, and select "Change value".
You will have an option to write a Java expression so you can add something like:
`yourList.add("newItem");`  or: `yourList.remove(0);`
Make sure to reload the variable ("F5") once you are done and you will see the updated state.

Note that not every `List` implementation supports `add()` or `remove()` methods.
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5755510/4214287) for more details if you encounter an exception.

See also:
[Eclipse docs - Variables view](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fvariables%2Fref-variables_view.htm)
[Eclipse docs - Change variable value](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fshared%2Fref-changevarvalue.htm)

Comment: Doesn't work. The error is "Unsupportd Boolean Operation"

Comment: @geneb - Updated my answer on exceptions when using fixed-sized or immutable lists

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to do something similar.  I had an ArrayList containing 1 element, and I wanted to remove it.

I tried @Leet-Falcon's answer, e.g. yourList.remove(0), and Eclipse replied "Unsupported operation exception".

What ended up working was : return new java.util.ArrayList<>();

Comment: As a side-note, the ArrayList used had been created through Arrays.asList(), which returns a fixed-size list, hence you cannot remove items from it.  Had the ArrayList been created with new ArrayList<>(), I'm sure Leet-Falcon's answer would have worked just fine.

Comment: So what do you do if you need 1-2 specific elements there, not an empty list?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the "**Debug Shell**" view allows this, or additionally if it's a simple enough list, the following simple Change Variable can also work:

```
new ArrayList<String>(java.util.Arrays.asList("1","2")) // or any other simple list
```

[Modifying Java Collection (List) Variable in Eclipse Debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64430629/modifying-java-collection-list-variable-in-eclipse-debugger)