# Groovy: Creating a list with range operator

Tags: list, exception, groovy, range

I was trying to pick a random element from a list of int and the list elements are created with range operator:

```
def date_range = 1..28
assert ('a'..'d').collect() == ['a','b','c','d'] // So this is instanceof List
assert ('a'..'d') == ['a','b','c','d'] // So this is instanceof List
def x1 = (1..28).collect().sort{new Random()}?.take(1)[0] // works
def x2 = date_range.collect().sort{new Random()}?.take(1)[0] // works
def x3 = date_range[0..27].sort{new Random()}?.take(1)[0] //works
def x4 = date_range.sort{new Random()}?.take(1)[0] // does not works
```

x4 yielding below Exception

```
Caught: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at listManipulation.run(listManipulation.groovy:21)
```

What is my mistake on x4?

Update:

My confusion is : if I define date_range as `def date_range = 1..28`  and check like:  `assert date_range instanceof List`  , than it passes. Why I should again convert it to list ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`date_range` is of type `IntRange`. No sure really why `sort` is unsupported on `Range`. But `toSorted` be used to achieve the same.

You should be able to call it using below:

```
def date_range = 1..28 
def x4 = date_range.toSorted {new Random()}?.take(1)[0]​
println x4
```

Also, convert range to an `array` or `list` before `sort`(this is what happened in case of `x3`) like below:

```
println date_range.toList().sort {new Random()}?.take(1)[0]
println date_range.toArray().sort {new Random()}?.take(1)[0]
```

**Edit:** Based on OP's comments.

`date_range` is immutable list.

In all your x1, x2, x3, you are creating a collection / list only(over immutable list) which becomes mutable and then able to do `sort`. Similarly above.

`sort` not allowed on `immutable list`.

Below works.

```
def mutableList = ['Groovy', 'Java', 'JRuby']
mutableList.sort()
```

However, once the list is immutable, then it does now allow and results `UnsupportedOperation` Exception.

```
def immutableList = ['Groovy', 'Java', 'JRuby'].asImmutable()
immutableList.sort()
```

Hope it is clear now.

Comment: Not every list might support `sort`. for ex see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755477/java-list-add-unsupportedoperationexception

Comment: Thank you very much for this valuable information and update !
So it means range operator (..)  creates immutable list.