# Adding value to existing key in List<class> in java

Tags: java

I need a help in this program. I am trying to add list value to existing key in Map. Please find below program. Kindly let me know where I am wrong and how I can do.
`

```
  public class UpStreamFileCount
      {


   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
   {
    String App_code = args[0];
    String App_Ctry_code = args[1];
    String hostname=null;
    Map<List<String>, List<FC>> fileNeedCheck = new HashMap<List<String>, List<FC>>();
    try
    {
        InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        hostname=inetAddress.getHostName();
    }
    catch(UnknownHostException unknownHostException)
    {
        unknownHostException.printStackTrace();
     }

    BatchDateCalculation cmd = new BatchDateCalculation ();

    String Batch_date = cmd.Compare();
    Date currTime = cmd.CurrTime();
    Date timeBeforeOnehour = cmd.BeforOneHour();

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(",");
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("FC.csv"));)
    {
         Map<List<String>,List<FC>> grouped = in
                                             .lines()
                                             .skip(1)
                                             .map(line -> {
                                             String[] arr = pattern.split(line);
                                             return new  FC(arr[0],
                                                               arr[1],
                                                               arr[2],
                                                               arr[3],
                                                               arr[4],
                                                               arr[5]);
                                             })
                                             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> {
                                              return new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(x.getUpstreamAppCode(), x.getUpstreamGrpAppCode()));
                                             })); 

         File data = new File("newFile.txt");
         if (data.exists()) 
         {
            data.delete();
         }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(data,true);

        for(Map.Entry<List<String>,List<FC>> entry : grouped.entrySet() )
        {        
            List<String> list1 =  entry.getKey();
            for(FC  value : entry.getValue() )
            {
                String a = value.getSlaTime() ;
                Date newTime = cmd.covertTimeToDate(a);

                if (timeBeforeOnehour.before( newTime ) && currTime.after(newTime)) 
                {
                    String result  = String.join(",", list1);
                    String[] parts = result.split(",");
                    String part1 = parts[0];
                    String part2 = parts[1];
                    String path = value.getPath();
                    String stagPath = value.getStagPath();
                    String file = value.getFile();
                    String s = result + "," + path + "," + stagPath + "," + file + "," + a ;
                    String addMapValue = path  + "," + stagPath + "," + file + "," + a ;
                    fw.write(s);
                    fw.write(System.getProperty( "line.separator" ));
                    if(!fileNeedCheck.containsKey(list1))
                    {
                        fileNeedCheck.put(list1,Arrays.asList( new FC(part1,part2,path,stagPath,file,a)) );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        List<FC> t = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new FC(part1,part2,path,stagPath,file,a)));
                        t.add(value);
                        fileNeedCheck.get(list1).put(t);
                    }   
                }
            }
         }
        fw.close();
    }
      `
```

The issue is here: - in the else part of the code . Please let me know how I can do this

```
  if(!fileNeedCheck.containsKey(list1))
                    {
                        fileNeedCheck.put(list1,Arrays.asList( new FC(part1,part2,path,stagPath,file,a)) );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        List<FC> t = new ArrayList<FC>(Arrays.asList(new FC(part1,part2,path,stagPath,file,a)));
                        t.add(value);
                        fileNeedCheck.get(list1).add(value);
                       // fileNeedCheck.get(list1).put(t);
                    }
```

I am getting the error below:-

>

> ```
>    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
>    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
>    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
>    at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:344)
>   at UpStreamFileCount.main(UpStreamFileCount.java:107)
> ```

Comment: `List<FC> t = new ArrayList<String>` `String` to `FC`? what is the error?

Comment: Hi I changed else portion with below 'fileNeedCheck.get(list1).add(value);` .Instead of pu(t), i took add(value). It compile fine, but giving runtime error. `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` and commented all lines in above portion

Comment: post the stacktrace of the error

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
        at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
        at UpStreamFileCount.main(UpStreamFileCount.java:109)
`

Comment: move the full stacktrace in the question body please

Comment: If I keep this line `fileNeedCheck.get(list1).put(value);`  gives compile time error which is below  `UpStreamFileCount.java:109: error: cannot find symbol
                                                        fileNeedCheck.get(list1).put(value);
                                                                                ^
  symbol:   method put(FC)
  location: interface List<FC>
1 error
'

Comment: that is because `List` doesn't have the function `.put()`. change it to `fileNeedCheck.get(list1).addAll(t);`

Comment: changed according to comment, but still getting same runtime error

Comment: ` java UpStreamFileCount FC V
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
        at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
        at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:344)
        at UpStreamFileCount.main(UpStreamFileCount.java:109)
`

Comment: can you please add the full stacktrace to your question via the edit button? makes it much easier to read if its formatted

Comment: Why are you creating a new list if you want to add an FC object to the list against the existing key in the map? Just create a new FC object and add it.

Comment: could you please let me know how i can do, i am just new in java programming, and just hit and trial i did

Comment: change the whole `else` block to `fileNeedCheck.get(list1).add(new FC(part1,part2,path,stagPath,file,a));`. after that save and compile and execute. the error should at least be another one

Comment: Hi mikea, i have put these code in else according to ur suggestion, then getting compile time error. `FC f = new FC(part1,part2,path,stagPath,file,a);
       fileNeedCheck.get(list1).put(f);`

Comment: Hi Baumer, getting the same runtime error

Comment: just changed the line, try now. is the error still same line and really because of the same reason?

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
        at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
        at UpStreamFileCount.main(UpStreamFileCount.java:109)
`

Comment: what is in line 109?

Comment: `fileNeedCheck.get(list1).add(new FC(part1,part2,path,stagPath,file,a));
`

Comment: i am not sure where you create the `List<FC>` in the map, but this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5755510/7109162) might describe the problem we have

Comment: Hi Baumer, any update. Please help me ... I am totally stuck on this and i Need to deliver this code today

Comment: HI Joe,how i can solve this.

Answer (score 0):

The exception occurs when your code tries to add a new element to a list created by `Arrays.asList()` from an array. This method produces a fixed-size list and new elements can not be added to it. See [javadoc of `asList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) for further explanation.

An easy way to fix this is to use an `ArrayList` (or other implementation of `List`) instead, and initialize it with the list obtained from `Arrays.asList()` call.

From the stack traces you posted I assume it's the list you put as a value to the map here:
`fileNeedCheck.put(list1,Arrays.asList( new FC(part1,part2,path,stagPath,file,a)) );`

Change this to:
 `fileNeedCheck.put(list1, new ArrayList<FC>(Arrays.asList(new FC(part1,part2,path,stagPath,file,a))));`

Comment: hi David, how i can solve this

Comment: Hi David, but i want to add value to existing key .when i tried ur code, it only shows me last value for the key, not 2 value.

Comment: I updated my answer. Also note that the code you posted contained references to classes that were not included. It was not possible to compile it and it was a little hard to understand. See how to create a code example here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: HI David, how i can add another class here,

Comment: @PallviMahajanSapen, about your 2nd comment: I don't see how it can be caused by the change I proposed. Can you explain what your test is? Also, are you able to see two values in the list without my change in place (or is it just the exception then) ?

Comment: @PallviMahajanSapen `if (!fileNeedCheck.containsKey(list1)) {
   fileNeedCheck.put(list1, new ArrayList<FC>(Arrays.asList(new FC(part1, part2, path, stagPath, file, a))));
  } else {
   fileNeedCheck.get(list1).add(new FC(part1, part2, path, stagPath, file, a));
  }` this should be how your if-else looks like

Comment: HI Baumer, yes my if else block looks like that, if key is not present, then they add key, value pair and if key is present then it only add value on that keys in map . I have declared my map like that  at top of my code.  Map<List<String>, List<FC>> fileNeedCheck = new HashMap<List<String>, List<FC>>();'

Comment: HI David, i added ur code i have existing key and for that i want to add another value but by doing that way it only add one value not 2 value. I tested and it did not work. It only shows me last value .

Comment: I suggest you to debug and see if both branches of that `if` statement are indded called and when they're called.