# Creating new Object (extending Thread) results in UnsupportedOperationException when deleting from member List<E>

Tags: java, list, foreach

I have a `MyObject() extends Thread` which creates a new `MyObject` of itself in the `run()` method.
This object has a `List<E>` as a member, where I delete from under certain conditions.

I when creating the new Object I call `start()` afterwards to start it's run method. But as soon as I spawn the new Object, it throws an

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at java.base/java.util.ImmutableCollections.uoe(ImmutableCollections.java:73)
at java.base/java.util.ImmutableCollections$AbstractImmutableCollection.remove(ImmutableCollections.java:80)
at mypackage.MyMainClass.MyObject.run(MyObject.java:87)  <- here I remove from my List
```

Example:

```
public class MyObject extends Thread {
    List<SomeType> list = new ArrayList<SomeType>();
    SomeType st;

    public MyObject(SomeType st) {
        this.st = st;
        // returns a List of SomeType
        list = st.getList();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(!done) {
            SomeType toDelete;
            if (condition) {
                toDelete = st.getToDelete();
            }
            // Checks for null etc are done and not important
            for (SomeType sometype : list) {
                if (somecondition) {
                    // toDelete is always in that List
                    list.remove(toDelete)
                } 
            }

            if (lastcondition) {
                MyObject newObject = new MyObject(this.st);
                newObject.start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why do I get this error? Since the List is a member of each instance of the Object, why is it immutable for the new Threads, but not for my initial object?

Comment: Please make a [mcve].

Comment: Show your code. This doesn't make sense when you say copy

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I added a stripped down example. I suspect the for loop being the cause for all of this.

Comment: The error says it all: you're trying to remove an element from a list which is immutable, and thus doesn't support removal. You probably want to create a mutable *copy* of `st.getList()` in the constructor.

Comment: `SomeType.getList` returns a `List` implementation that does not support structural modification (or maybe no modification at all). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755477/java-list-add-unsupportedoperationexception) for a similar problem (with `add()`, but the problem source and solution is very similar).

Comment: @JoachimSauer You were right, this list gets created usin List.of() so I need to think of another way...

Comment: Creating a new object extending Thread has nothing to do with it. The object has already been created long before the error.

Comment: You shouldn't extend `Thread`, but instead implement `Runnable`, and pass that to an instance of a normal `Thread` (or to an executor service).

Answer (score 1):

Even when you fix `UnsupportedOperationException` your code that removes elements from list will throw `ConcurrentModificationException` because you are modifying list without using iterator while traversing list using iterator

```
for (SomeType sometype : list) { // this creates iterator behind the scene
    if (somecondition) {
        // toDelete is always in that List
        list.remove(toDelete); // this modifies the list and makes iterator throw ConcurrentModificationException
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was pointed out by @Joachim Sauer:

> `SomeType.getList` returns a `List` implementation that does not support structural modification (or maybe no modification at all). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755477/java-list-add-unsupportedoperationexception) for a similar problem (with `add()`, but the problem source and solution is very similar).

The used list got created with `List.of()`which is immutable.