# Updating an entry of a HashMap whose values is a List

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have a `HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>` "`sq_diff`" and I am trying to update an entry.

I tried:

```
List<Integer> values = sq_diff.get(diff);
values.add(c);
values.add(d);
sq_diff.put(diff, values);
```

and

```
sq_diff.get(diff).add(c);
sq_diff.get(diff).add(d);
```

and

```
sq_diff.computeIfPresent(diff, (k, v) -> v.add(c);
sq_diff.computeIfPresent(diff, (k, v) -> v.add(d);
```

None of them working:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

**The map contains an entry of** "`diff`"

**Highly appreciated if you can indicate problems on each of them.**

Comment: What actual type is the List you are using? It looks very much like you are using some kind of fixed-size list that does not allow inserting new objects. (Like the List you get When you use `Arrays.asList` method)

Comment: see: [Java List.add() UnsupportedOperationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755477/java-list-add-unsupportedoperationexception)

Comment: @OH GOD SPIDERS, on creation I am using "sq_diff.putIfAbsent(diff, Arrays.asList(c, d));"

Comment: @ManojBanik is your question resolved?

Comment: Yes, I used Java ArrayList provided by @abhimanyue.

Comment: @User_67128 have attention to answer at which all cases are working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(c, d));
sq_diff.put(diff, values);
```

instead of

```
sq_diff.put(diff, Arrays.asList(c, d));
```

Comment: It works but "sq_diff.computeIfPresent(diff, (k, v) -> v.add(c);" still not working.

Answer (score 2):

Trouble is when you initialize your list by [Arrays.asList()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)). As mentioned at the documentation:

> This method also provides a convenient way to create a fixed-size list initialized to contain several elements

And later when you want to update your ***fixed-size list*** with adding new elements you got: `UnsupportedOperationException`.

**As a soltion** you can use a quite useful Guava's [Lists](https://guava.dev/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html) utilities class:

> Lists.newArrayList(c, d);

It also provides `Maps` utilities as well.

Code for it will look like:

```
public class MapDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int diff = 42;
        HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> map = Maps.newHashMap();
        map.putIfAbsent(diff, Lists.newArrayList(1, 2));
        // 1:            
        final List<Integer> integers = map.get(diff);
        integers.add(10);
        integers.add(11);
        // 2: 
        map.get(diff).add(20);
        map.get(diff).add(21);
        // 3:    
        map.computeIfPresent(diff, (k, v) -> {
            v.add(30);
            return v;
        });
        map.computeIfPresent(diff, (k, v) -> {
            v.add(31);
            return v;
        });

        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> {42=[1, 2, 10, 11, 20, 21, 30, 31]}

As you can see all 3 cases are executed well.