# How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException ? ( Kotlin - Android Studio )

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to add an intem to my arrayList when there new values added on my firebase database using this peace of code THIS IS A [SAMPLE CODE](https://github.com/Aniskonig/My-MSG-App) ( the error happens when you click on send button ):

```
ref.addChildEventListener(object : ChildEventListener {

        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
        }

        override fun onChildMoved(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
        }


        override fun onChildChanged(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
        }

        @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
        override fun onChildAdded(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot, s: String?) {

            val newMSG: Messages? = dataSnapshot.getValue(Messages::class.java)

            val myrv = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.msgRV)
            name = dataSnapshot.child("name").value.toString()
            muid = dataSnapshot.child("muid").value.toString()
            time = dataSnapshot.child("time").value.toString()
            message = dataSnapshot.child("message").value.toString()
            var contained = false
                messagesArrayList.forEach{ contained =  it.time !=time}
            if (messagesArrayList.isNotEmpty() && contained){
                messagesArrayList.add(Messages(newMSG?.name, newMSG?.mUID, newMSG?.time, newMSG?.message)) // The error is pointing here
                messagesArrayList = messagesArrayList.sortedWith(compareBy { it.time }) as MutableList<Messages>
                val myModulesAdapter = MessageRV(this@MessageActivity, messagesArrayList)
                myrv.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this@MessageActivity, 1)
                myrv.adapter = myModulesAdapter
                myrv.scrollToPosition(myModulesAdapter.itemCount - 1)

            }

        }

        override fun onChildRemoved(p0: DataSnapshot) {
        }
    })
```

But i got this error :

> ```
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>     Process: com.medanis.medmax, PID: 3533
>     java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
>         at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:153)
>         at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:111)
>         at com.medanis.medmax.messages.MessageActivity$onCreate$3.onChildAdded(MessageActivity.kt:148)
>         at com.google.firebase.database.core.ChildEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:79)
>         at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:63)
>         at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:55)
>         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7478)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
> ```

Can anyone tell me what went wrong? How can I fix it?

> NOTE : your database must be structred like this:
>   Messages/MoIfH0sbt2UjJj7yozXRQF72RgK2/w691O35sZ2hvDpkTbAnm6aaTjZj1/
>   then a value of time in this format yyyyMMddHHmmss the Message Model content

**SOLLUTION:**
Thanks to @Slaw and @AlexMamo, i solved the problem by changing {  as MutableList } to { .toMutableList() }

(name, muid, time, message)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java List.add() UnsupportedOperationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755477/java-list-add-unsupportedoperationexception)

Comment: no because the add operation is supported by ArrayList and it works fine outside the addChildEventListener

Comment: @MEDANIS Somewhere along the way you're getting an unmodifiable `List`.

Comment: i already used the same ArrayList to collect data from the firebase DB using AddSingleValueListner and it works correctly

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting that error? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: Then I suggest providing a [mre]. (@Alex there's a code comment indicating the line, though you have to scroll to the right)

Comment: You mention collecting data into (supposedly) the same list. What does that look like?

Comment: @Slaw i will make one wait for me please

Comment: How is `messagesArrayList` defined?

Comment: @AlexMamo private var messagesArrayList: MutableList<Messages> = ArrayList() i'm working to make a sample just u will got the full idea

Comment: DONE check now the example don't forget to read the note in the last lines and for the first use just stop the addChildEventListener to pass data to the db then refrech

Comment: @Slaw is there anything i can help you with ?

Comment: @AlexMamo is there anything i can help you with ?

Comment: I believe your problem is here: `messagesArrayList = messagesArrayList.sortedWith(compareBy { it.time }) as MutableList<Messages>`. While you may be casting to a mutable list I believe the returned list remains unmodifiable. Perhaps you want https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sort-with.html instead, as that sorts the list in-place.

Comment: @MEDANIS instead of casting it i.e. `as MutableList<..>` just use the extension function `.toMutableList()` it'll actually make the list mutable (by copying out the values). The original list returned from `sortedWith` might be immutable as pointed out by Slaw.

Comment: Thank you. The answer is correct. It is sufficient to change "as MutableList<Messages>" by ".toMutableList()"... Please add it as an answer to let the rest know...as Slaw said sortedWith returns immtablelist so the sollution is to turn it to mutableList again as Animesh Suhu said...thank you all

Comment: Depending on your use case, you may want to consider using `sortWith` (note _not_ `sortedWith`), which I linked to in my previous comment. It will sort the list in-place rather than copying the elements into a new list.

Comment: Thank you please juste put your answer your solution like an "answer" so i can approved to help others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLLUTION:** 
Thanks to @Slaw and @AlexMamo, i solved the problem by changing { as MutableList } to { .toMutableList() }