# Java ArrayList method addAll() on empty list throwing UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, exception, arraylist, collections

I have a code as below where I am trying to add an ArrayList(componentList) to another ArrayList(SpareParts). It works fine a long as spareParts list is not empty. When the spareParts List is empty it throws `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null`

```
List<ProductReferenceData> spareParts = new ArrayList<ProductReferenceData>();
/**
 Method which fills spareParts List and does not return null. Checked in Debugger as well.
*/
if(componentLabels!=null && !CollectionUtils.isEmpty(componentLabels))
 {
    spareParts.addAll(componentLabels);
 }
```

I can put an if else loop to check if spareParts list is empty to patch this issue but is there an elegant solution to this? Maybe in Java 8

---edit---
Adding stacktrace

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/08/07 20:10:39.309 | java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/08/07 20:10:39.316 |     at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/08/07 20:10:39.316 |     at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/08/07 20:10:39.316 |     at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:344) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/08/07 20:10:39.316 |     at com.ge.hc.storefront.controllers.pages.ProductPageController.productDetail(ProductPageController.java:418) ~[classes/:?]
```

Comment: Please provide a full stacktrace and a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that we can run and figure out what is happening.  I suspect that the `UnsupportedOperationException` is due to something in your `CollectionUtils` method rather than the `spareParts.addAll(componentLabels)` call.

Comment: Also, please provide the full stack trace.

Comment: AFAIK, `ArrayList` in Java 8 does not throw `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: I suspect that some kind of immutable or unmodifyable list is at work here.

Comment: Added the full stacktrace...below that stacktrace is just custom code.

Comment: What line is line `418` in `ProductPageController`?

Comment: Make sure are you using java 8 in runtime or not?

Comment: Similar to this stack trace.  [Java List.add() UnsupportedOperationException - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755477/java-list-add-unsupportedoperationexception)

Comment: Line 418 is `spareParts.addAll(componentLabels);`

Comment: Can you check if method filing `spareParts` returns `Arrays.asList()`

Comment: Then, `spareParts` is not referencing an `ArrayList` at the point of time when the exception happens. Besides that, what’s the point of writing `CollectionUtils.isEmpty(componentLabels)` instead of a straight-forward `componentLabels.isEmpty()`?

Comment: @Holger- Thanks it turns out method which fills spareParts is actually returning List and not ArrayList maybe that is the problem. Also previously we have seen `componentLabels.isEmpty()`  throws NPE if list is null but `CollectionUtils.isEmpty(componentLabels)` returns a proper true/false.