# Error while trying to use post metod in springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm learning Spring Boot rn and I'm getting errors on my way when I'm trying to use POST method.

HTTP code is 400.

That's the error:[image]

Here is the code of my rest controller c:

```java
package com.example.carsapi;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/cars")
public class CarRestController {

    private final CarService carService;

    @Autowired
    public CarRestController(CarService carService) {
        this.carService = carService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List> getCars(){
        return new ResponseEntity(carService.findAllCars(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/id/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<List> getCarById(@PathVariable Integer id){
        Optional<CarDTO> found = carService.findAllCars().stream().filter(car -> car.getCarId() == id).findFirst();
        if(found.isPresent()){
            return new ResponseEntity(found.get(), HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/color/{color}")
    public ResponseEntity<List> getCarByColor(@PathVariable String color){
        Optional<CarDTO> found = carService.findAllCars().stream().filter(car -> car.getColor().equals(color)).findFirst();
        if(found.isPresent()){
            return new ResponseEntity(found.get(), HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/add")
    public ResponseEntity addCar(@RequestBody CarDTO car){
        carService.findAllCars().add(car);
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

And there is my JSON code which I'm using:

```json
[ 
    {
        "carId": 3,
        "carBrand": "Audi",
        "carModel": "RS6",
        "color": "red"
    }
]
```

Hope you'll help me I had even tried with `@RequestParam`, getting all of the values like `id`, `brand`, `model` and `color` and then adding a new object with these values which I've got from the query but it still didn't work.

Comment: Please, don't do that. Don't change the question after it was correctly answered already. By doing it you make the answer obsolete. Accept the answer and create a new question instead. Thanks!

Comment: I can post once for 90 mins and I need the solution as fast as possible

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755477/java-list-add-unsupportedoperationexception.

Comment: Didn't work, still 500 error. Btw I checked it closely and error is occurring while it's going to add to list.

Comment: Can you please create a new question and include there the code for `carService.findAllCars()`?

Comment: sure, I'll do it when I come back from school

Comment: @JoãoDias done :)

Comment: I will take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request is an array while `CarDTO` is a single object. You can make the request with a body like this(notice the absence of `[]`):

```json
{
    "carId": 3,
    "carBrand": "Audi",
    "carModel": "RS6",
    "color": "red"
}
```

Comment: now i got Http 500 code

Comment: So you've gone past the 400. The 500 is likely caused by something else now.

Comment: yup ik, code is the same do you know a reason mby?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: I've eddited a post, you can look around