# Application protocol implementation in Java

Tags: java, protocols

I want to implement an existing protocol (server side only) in Java. The client is an old game client that I would like to write a server for.

The protocol is structured like this:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----//----+--------+--------+
| size0  | size1  |  seq0  |  seq1  | sessID0| sessID1| param0 | param1 |   id0  |   id1  |  payload | trash  | trash  |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----//----+--------+--------+
```

Now the protocol, being pretty old, defines many versions, where the header (up until including `id1`) stays the same (as do the last two padding bytes).

The `payload` varies from version to version, so it needs to be decoded differently. See simplified example below (`pl#` for payload byte number):

```
Version 1.00    
    ...+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------/--------+--------+...
(HEAD) |  pl0   |  pl1   |  pl2   |  pl3   |  pl4   |  pl5  ...  pl22 |  pl23  |
    ...+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------/--------+--------+...
       | clientVersion (little endian)     | userName (fixed String l=20)      |
    ...+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------/--------+--------+


Version 1.10
    ...+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------/--------+--------+...
(HEAD) |  pl0   |  pl1   |  pl2   |  pl3   |  pl4   |  pl5  ... plN-1 |  plN   |
    ...+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------/--------+--------+...
       | clientVersion (big endian)        | userName (pascal String)          |
    ...+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------/--------+--------+
```

The question for me now is two-fold.

First and foremost, how do you implement such a protocol without getting into `switch()` hell? I have read that a lot of people recommend a FSM (or maybe State-pattern) for that, but I didn't get how this should work. I have also been looking into (and playing with) Google's ProtoBuf, which sadly does not support any int16 / uint16 data types.

Secondly, how to implement this, so that I end up with a nice, clean `PacketHandler`-interface that may look like this:

```
public interface PacketHandler {

    void onLoginRequest(Client client, LoginRequest request);
    void onHeartbeatRequest(Client client, HeartbeatRequest request);
    ...

}
```

The purpose of that Handler would be that the classes `LoginRequest` and `HeartbeatRequest` are the same, no matter the client version.

On the outgoing side of things I want to be able to write these kind of POJOs as well, for example:

```
public class PacketHandlerImpl implements PacketHandler {

    void onLoginRequest(Client client, LoginRequest request) {
        if(success)
            client.send(new LoginGrantedResponse(...));
        else
            client.send(new LoginDeniedResponse(...));
    }
    ...

}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: One way is to write custom (de)serialization logic for packets, so Java serialization framework will do significant part of job for you. Or consider faster option using JDK `Externalizable`. See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817853/what-is-the-difference-between-serializable-and-externalizable-in-java

Comment: @VictorSorokin And how would I react to the different kinds of client versions with serialization? I mean when I (de-)serialize I am stuck with the same (un-)marshalling logic, no?

Comment: I assume, your protocol has fixed layout prefix you can use to deduce version. If this is true, your marshalling logic can branch out to correct deserialization code. I guess, need to branch inside marshalling code means you need `Externalizable`, not `Serializable`.

Comment: If you are implementing server for tcpi protocol, Apache MINA https://mina.apache.org couls be good starting point. Handles socket connections, buffering, fram borders etc. And transport, protocol and logic can be on separate layers.