# Is selective Serialization possible with the Serializable Interface?

Tags: java, serialization

Lets us say my class `MyClass` has 10 variables. By marking the class with `Serializable` we serialize all the 10 variables.

My question is is there any way to serialize only some of these variables, let us say 5 only?

I know it can be done by marking the variables as `transient`. But I want to know if there is any other way to do that than using `transient` keyword.

Comment: Why do you need another way? Either way, you can take the entire process into your hand if you want to by creating a `readObject()`/`writeObject()` method.

Comment: either you use transient or you make fields static because static variables are not saved anyway during serialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your class implements the [`Externalizable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html) interface, then you will have better control of how the object will be serialized.

Note that, unlike `Serializable`, the `Externalizable` interface is not a marker one and you will need to implement the `readExternal()` and `writeExternal()` methods, where you can actually *pick* programmatically which class members to be serialized and how de-serialization will be done.

More info:

- [Difference between `Serializable` and `Externalizable`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817853/what-is-the-difference-between-serializable-and-externalizable-in-java)

Comment: There is also the technique of using serialization proxies as an alternative to `Externalizable`.

Comment: Can you share some resource regarding this, @biziclop? :)

Answer (score 0):

Java supports Custom Serialization. Read the section Customize the Default Protocol.

> There is, however, a strange yet crafty solution. By using a built-in
> feature of the serialization mechanism, developers can enhance the
> normal process by providing two methods inside their class files.
> Those methods are:
>
> private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException;
>
> private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException,
> ClassNotFoundException;

Answer (score 0):

An option when you want to customize serialization is to use **serialization proxies**: instead of your "real" object you create a substitute that is serialized instead. The serialization framework uses the `writeReplace()/readResolve()` methods, which allow you to do exactly this.

This is roughly what it looks like:

```
public class Foo implements Serializable {
    private final String bar;
    private final String baz;

    private static class FooProxy implements Serializable {
        private final String barBaz;

        private FooProxy(Foo foo) {
           this.barBaz = foo.bar + "|" + foo.baz; //don't do this for real
        }

        private Object readResolve() {
           String [] arr = this.barBaz.split( "|" );
           return new Foo(arr[0], arr[1]);
        }   

    }

    private Object writeReplace() {
        return new FooProxy(this);
    }

    // this method is required to stop a maliciously constructed serialized form to be deserialized
    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream ois) throws InvalidObjectException {
       throw new InvalidObjectException( "Use a proxy." );
    }

}
```

So every time `Foo` is to be serialized, it is replaced with a `FooProxy` object that has completely different fields, and every time `FooProxy` is deserialized, it's replaced with a corresponding `Foo`.

The advantage of this technique is that you can separate the serialized form from the internal representation completely, allowing you to change the internal representation arbitrarily, so long as it can be rebuilt from the serialized form.