# Any use case which can only be solved using Externalizable and can't be solved using Serializable and vice-versa

Tags: java, serialization

We already have lot of differences available in internet for these two interfaces but curious to know that any task which Externalizable can do but Serializable can't do and vice-versa.

The shared resource is more about differences between these two interface and describes when should we use which?

[What is the difference between Serializable and Externalizable in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817853/what-is-the-difference-between-serializable-and-externalizable-in-java)

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen The shared resource is more about differences between these two interface and describes when should we use which?

Comment: 'Any task which `Externalizable can do but `Serializable` can't do': `Externalizable` can do almost anything it likes. 'and vice-versa' Nothing really, except save you code space.