# Do I need explicit default constructor when implementing Externalizable?

Tags: java, externalizable

I know that if class `A` implements Externalizable it should have no-arg constructor, but if class doesn't have any constructors (like my `A` class) java provides empty no-arg constructor for it. So why I have an error there? If I explicitly add no-arg constructor (`public A() {}`) to the `A` class everything will be ok.
Error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.InvalidClassException: A; no valid constructor
> at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass$ExceptionInfo.newInvalidClassException(ObjectStreamClass.java:159)
> at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.checkDeserialize(ObjectStreamClass.java:864)
> at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2061)
> at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1594)
> at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430)
> at Test.main(Test.java:19)

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test implements Serializable
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {

        // initiaizing
        A a1 = new A();

        // serializing
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        oos.writeObject(a1);
        oos.close();

        // deserializing
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()));
        A a2 = (A) ois.readObject();
    }
}

class A implements Externalizable
{
    @Override
    public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput objectOutput) throws IOException {}

    @Override
    public void readExternal(ObjectInput objectInput) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {}
}
```

Comment: Read ***all*** answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36484886/2055998

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Externalizable requires a `public` no-args constructor, but provided no-arg constructor have default access modifier (also called package private)
Try this: `public class A() {}`

Comment: whether java provides not public no-arg constructor if other not provided?

Comment: The class must be public.  The no-arg constructor will be provided as normal.

Comment: a public constructor does not make a package access class magically turn into a public class.  The ability to call the constructor is a requirement, but access to the class is an implied requirement as well.