# In Java, how do you determine if a thread is running?

Tags: java, multithreading

How do you determine if a thread is running?

Answer (score 100):

`Thread.isAlive()`

Comment: I guess it has some difference from `Thread.State.RUNNABLE` (the last one seems more reliable)

Answer (score 34):

You can use this method:

```
boolean isAlive()
```

It returns true if the thread is still alive and false if the Thread is dead.
This is not static. You need a reference to the object of the Thread class.

One more tip:
If you're checking it's status to make the main thread wait while the new thread is still running, you may use join() method. It is more handy.

Answer (score 21):

I think you can use [GetState()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getState()); It can return the exact state of a thread.

Answer (score 9):

Check the thread status by calling `Thread.isAlive`.

Answer (score 8):

To be precise,

`Thread.isAlive()` returns true if the thread has been started (may not yet be running) but has not yet completed its run method.

`Thread.getState()` returns the exact state of the thread.

Answer (score 6):

***Thread.State** enum class and the new **getState()** API are provided for querying the execution state of a thread.*

*A thread can be in only one state at a given point in time. These states are virtual machine states which do not reflect any operating system thread states* [`NEW, RUNNABLE, BLOCKED, WAITING, TIMED_WAITING, TERMINATED`].

> enum [Thread.State](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html) extends Enum implements [Serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31651945/5081877), [Comparable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31244596/5081877)

- **getState()**<sup>[*`jdk5`*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/enhancements.html#jdk5.0lang)</sup> - `public State getState() {...}` **«** *Returns the state of `this` thread. This method is designed for use in monitoring of the system state, not for synchronization control.*
- **isAlive()** - `public final native boolean isAlive();` **«** *Returns **true** if the thread upon which it is called is still alive, otherwise it returns **false**. A thread is alive if it has been started and has not yet died.*

*Sample Source Code's of classes [`java.lang.Thread`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/db8272cb8c99/src/share/classes/java/lang/Thread.java#l140) and [`sun.misc.VM`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/sun/misc/VM.java#l369).*

```java
package java.lang;
public class Thread implements Runnable {
    public final native boolean isAlive();

    // Java thread status value zero corresponds to state "NEW" - 'not yet started'.
    private volatile int threadStatus = 0;

    public enum State {
        NEW, RUNNABLE, BLOCKED, WAITING, TIMED_WAITING, TERMINATED;
    }

    public State getState() {
        return sun.misc.VM.toThreadState(threadStatus);
    }
}

package sun.misc;
public class VM {
    // ...
    public static Thread.State toThreadState(int threadStatus) {
        if ((threadStatus & JVMTI_THREAD_STATE_RUNNABLE) != 0) {
            return Thread.State.RUNNABLE;
        } else if ((threadStatus & JVMTI_THREAD_STATE_BLOCKED_ON_MONITOR_ENTER) != 0) {
            return Thread.State.BLOCKED;
        } else if ((threadStatus & JVMTI_THREAD_STATE_WAITING_INDEFINITELY) != 0) {
            return Thread.State.WAITING;
        } else if ((threadStatus & JVMTI_THREAD_STATE_WAITING_WITH_TIMEOUT) != 0) {
            return Thread.State.TIMED_WAITING;
        } else if ((threadStatus & JVMTI_THREAD_STATE_TERMINATED) != 0) {
            return Thread.State.TERMINATED;
        } else if ((threadStatus & JVMTI_THREAD_STATE_ALIVE) == 0) {
            return Thread.State.NEW;
        } else {
            return Thread.State.RUNNABLE;
        }
    }
}
```

---

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37116094/5081877) with `java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch` to execute multiple threads parallel, After completing all threads main thread execute. (until parallel threads complete their task main thread will be blocked.)

```java
public class MainThread_Wait_TillWorkerThreadsComplete {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Main Thread Started...");
        // countDown() should be called 4 time to make count 0. So, that await() will release the blocking threads.
        int latchGroupCount = 4;
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(latchGroupCount);
        new Thread(new Task(2, latch), "T1").start();
        new Thread(new Task(7, latch), "T2").start();
        new Thread(new Task(5, latch), "T3").start();
        new Thread(new Task(4, latch), "T4").start();

        //latch.countDown(); // Decrements the count of the latch group.

        // await() method block until the current count reaches to zero
        latch.await(); // block until latchGroupCount is 0
        System.out.println("Main Thread completed.");
    }
}
class Task extends Thread {
    CountDownLatch latch;
    int iterations = 10;
    public Task(int iterations, CountDownLatch latch) {
        this.iterations = iterations;
        this.latch = latch;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        System.out.println(threadName + " : Started Task...");
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            System.out.println(threadName + " : "+ i);
            sleep(1);
        }
        System.out.println(threadName + " : Completed Task");
        latch.countDown(); // Decrements the count of the latch,
    }
    public void sleep(int sec) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000 * sec);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

@See also

- [“implements Runnable” vs. “extends Thread”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/541487/5081877)
- [Thread States](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27406503/5081877)
- [Thread States Diagram](http://bighai.com/ppjava/?p=144)
- [How to start two threads at “exactly” the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3379003/5081877)

Comment: `A thread is alive if it has been started and has not yet died`. What mean died? State is `TERMINATED`?

Comment: @KunLun A java instance go through a several state trough out its lifecycle, from born(`NEW`) to dead (`TERMINATED`), A `TERMINATED` thread is just thread that has completed its job

Answer (score 2):

Have your thread notify some other thread when it’s finished. This way you’ll always know exactly what’s going on.

Answer (score 2):

You can use: `Thread.currentThread().isAlive();`. Returns **true** if this thread is alive; **false** otherwise.

Comment: Wouldn't this always return true? I think it has to be a handle to another thread. After all, wouldn't the current thread be executing `Thread.currentThread().isAlive()` thus always returning true?

Answer (score 2):

Use **Thread.currentThread().isAlive()** to **see if the thread is alive**[output should be true] which means thread is still running the code inside the run() method or use **Thread.currentThread.getState()** method to **get the exact state** of the thread.

Answer (score 1):

Thought to write a code to demonstrate the ***isAlive() , getState()*** methods, this example monitors a thread still it terminates(dies).

```
package Threads;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ThreadRunning {


    static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

        private void method1() {

            for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
                try{
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                }catch(InterruptedException ex){}
                method2();
            }
            System.out.println("Existing Method1");
        }

        private void method2() {

            for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
                try{
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                }catch(InterruptedException ex){}
                method3();
            }
            System.out.println("Existing Method2");
        }

        private void method3() {

            for(int i=0;i<1;i++){
                try{
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                }catch(InterruptedException ex){}

            }
            System.out.println("Existing Method3");
        }

        public void run(){
            method1();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyRunnable runMe=new MyRunnable();

        Thread aThread=new Thread(runMe,"Thread A");

        aThread.start();

        monitorThread(aThread);

    }

    public static void monitorThread(Thread monitorMe) {

        while(monitorMe.isAlive())
         {
         try{   
           StackTraceElement[] threadStacktrace=monitorMe.getStackTrace();

           System.out.println(monitorMe.getName() +" is Alive and it's state ="+monitorMe.getState()+" ||  Execution is in method : ("+threadStacktrace[0].getClassName()+"::"+threadStacktrace[0].getMethodName()+") @line"+threadStacktrace[0].getLineNumber());  

               TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(700);
           }catch(Exception ex){}
    /* since threadStacktrace may be empty upon reference since Thread A may be terminated after the monitorMe.getStackTrace(); call*/
         }
        System.out.println(monitorMe.getName()+" is dead and its state ="+monitorMe.getState());
    }


}
```