# How to wait for a number of threads to complete?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, wait

What is a way to simply wait for all threaded process to finish?  For example, let's say I have:

```
public class DoSomethingInAThread implements Runnable{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int n=0; n<1000; n++) {
            Thread t = new Thread(new DoSomethingInAThread());
            t.start();
        }
        // wait for all threads' run() methods to complete before continuing
    }

    public void run() {
        // do something here
    }


}
```

How do I alter this so the `main()` method pauses at the comment until all threads' `run()` methods exit? Thanks!

Answer (score 164, accepted):

You put all threads in an array, start them all, and then have a loop

```
for(i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
  threads[i].join();
```

Each join will block until the respective thread has completed. Threads may complete in a different order than you joining them, but that's not a problem: when the loop exits, all threads are completed.

Comment: @Mykola: what *exactly* is the advantage of using a thread group? Just because the API is there doesn't mean you have to use it...

Comment: Thanks guys.  I will look into ThreadGroup, but using join() seems so much simpler for working with existing code!

Comment: See: "A thread group represents a set of threads."

This is semantic correct for this use-case! 

And: "A thread is allowed to access information about its own thread group"

Comment: @Martin K: A variable of type Thread[] or ArrayList<Thread> also represents a group of threads. There are many ways to represent a group of threads; in general, container types are best if you want to iterate over elements. For the specific problem, it is not relevant that a thread knows its thread group. So this entire thread group API is artificial, and useless for the problem at hand.

Comment: The book “Effective Java” recommends avoiding thread groups (item 73).

Comment: The bugs mentioned in Effective Java should have been fixed in Java 6.

If newer java versions aren't a restriction, it's better to use Futures to solve thread problems.

Martin v. Löwis: You're right. It's not relecant for that problem, but it's nice to get more Information about the running threads from one Object (like the ExecutorService). 

I think it's nice to use given features to solve a problem; maybe you'll need more flexibility (thread information) in the future. 

It's also right to mention the old buggy classes in older JDKs.

Comment: ThreadGroup does not implement a group-level join, so why people are pushing ThreadGroup is a little baffling. Are people really using spin locks & querying the group's activeCount? You'd be hard-pressed to convince me that doing so it better in any way when compared to just calling join on all of the threads.

Comment: Hi, it didn't work for me for some reason. Here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/users/5144855/ruchir-baronia

Comment: What if main() is midway interrupted, how do you cleanup the started threads?

Answer (score 44):

One way would be to make a `List` of `Thread`s, create and launch each thread, while adding it to the list. Once everything is launched, loop back through the list and call `join()` on each one. It doesn't matter what order the threads finish executing in, all you need to know is that by the time that second loop finishes executing, every thread will have completed.

A better approach is to use an [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and its associated methods:

```
List<Callable> callables = ... // assemble list of Callables here
                               // Like Runnable but can return a value
ExecutorService execSvc = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
List<Future<?>> results = execSvc.invokeAll(callables);
// Note: You may not care about the return values, in which case don't
//       bother saving them
```

Using an ExecutorService (and all of the new stuff from Java 5's [concurrency utilities](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/concurrency/)) is incredibly flexible, and the above example barely even scratches the surface.

Comment: ThreadGroup is the way to go! With a mutable List you'll get in trouble (synchronisation)

Comment: What? How would you get in trouble? It's only mutable (only readble) by the thread that is doing the launching, so as long as it doesn't modify the list *while* iterating through it, it's fine.

Comment: It depends on how you use it. If you'll use the calling class in a thread you'll have problems.

Answer (score 29):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class DoSomethingInAThread implements Runnable
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException
   {
      //limit the number of actual threads
      int poolSize = 10;
      ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize);
      List<Future<Runnable>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<Runnable>>();

      for (int n = 0; n < 1000; n++)
      {
         Future f = service.submit(new DoSomethingInAThread());
         futures.add(f);
      }

      // wait for all tasks to complete before continuing
      for (Future<Runnable> f : futures)
      {
         f.get();
      }

      //shut down the executor service so that this thread can exit
      service.shutdownNow();
   }

   public void run()
   {
      // do something here
   }
}
```

Comment: worked like a charm... i have two sets of threads which should not run simultaneously because of issues on multiple cookies. I used your example to run one set of threads at a time.. thanks for sharing your knowledge...

Comment: @Dantalian - In your Runnable class (likely in the run method), you would want to capture any exceptions that occurred and store them locally (or store an error message/condition). In the example, f.get() returns your object that you submitted to the ExecutorService. Your object could have a method for retrieving any exceptions/error conditions. Depending on how you modify the provided example, you might need to cast the object turned by f.get() to your expected type.

Answer (score 14):

instead of `join()`, which is an old API, you can use [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html). I have modified your code as below to fulfil your requirement.

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
class DoSomethingInAThread implements Runnable{
    CountDownLatch latch;
    public DoSomethingInAThread(CountDownLatch latch){
        this.latch = latch;
    } 
    public void run() {
        try{
            System.out.println("Do some thing");
            latch.countDown();
        }catch(Exception err){
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class CountDownLatchDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1000);
            for (int n=0; n<1000; n++) {
                Thread t = new Thread(new DoSomethingInAThread(latch));
                t.start();
            }
            latch.await();
            System.out.println("In Main thread after completion of 1000 threads");
        }catch(Exception err){
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Explanation**:

1. `CountDownLatch` has been initialized with given count 1000  as per your requirement.
2. Each worker thread `DoSomethingInAThread`  will decrement the `CountDownLatch`, which has been passed in constructor.
3. Main thread `CountDownLatchDemo` `await()` till the count has become zero. Once the count has become zero, you will get below line in output.

   ```
   In Main thread after completion of 1000 threads
   ```

More info from oracle documentation page

```
public void await()
           throws InterruptedException
```

> Causes the current thread to wait until the latch has counted down to zero, unless the thread is interrupted.

Refer to related SE question for other options:

[wait until all threads finish their work in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939257/wait-until-all-threads-finish-their-work-in-java/36797569#36797569)

Answer (score 8):

Avoid the Thread class altogether and instead use the higher abstractions provided in java.util.concurrent

The ExecutorService class provides the [method invokeAll](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection)) that seems to do just what you want.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on your needs, you may also want to check out the classes CountDownLatch and CyclicBarrier in the java.util.concurrent package.  They can be useful if you want your threads to wait for each other, or if you want more fine-grained control over the way your threads execute (e.g., waiting in their internal execution for another thread to set some state).  You could also use a CountDownLatch to signal all of your threads to start at the same time, instead of starting them one by one as you iterate through your loop.  The standard API docs have an example of this, plus using another CountDownLatch to wait for all threads to complete their execution.

Answer (score 6):

Consider using `java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch`. Examples in [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)

Comment: Is a latch for threads, the latch lock works with a countdown. In the run() method of your thread explicitly declare to wait for a CountDownLatch to reach it's countdown to 0. You can use the same CountDownLatch in more than one thread to release them simultaneously. I don't know if it is what you need, just wanted to mention it because it's useful when working in a multithread environment.

Comment: Maybe you should put that explanation in the body of your answer?

Comment: The examples in the Javadoc are very descriptive, that's why I didn't add any. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html. In the first example, all the Workers threads are releases simultaneously because they wait for the CountdownLatch startSignal to reach zero, which happens in startSignal.countDown(). Then, the mian thread waits until all the workes finish using the instruction doneSignal.await(). doneSignal decrease its value in each worker.

Answer (score 5):

As Martin K suggested   `java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch` seems to be a better solution for this. Just adding an example for the same

```
     public class CountDownLatchDemo
{

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int noOfThreads = 5;
        // Declare the count down latch based on the number of threads you need
        // to wait on
        final CountDownLatch executionCompleted = new CountDownLatch(noOfThreads);
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfThreads; i++)
        {
            new Thread()
            {

                @Override
                public void run ()
                {

                    System.out.println("I am executed by :" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    try
                    {
                        // Dummy sleep
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                        // One thread has completed its job
                        executionCompleted.countDown();
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e)
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }.start();
        }

        try
        {
            // Wait till the count down latch opens.In the given case till five
            // times countDown method is invoked
            executionCompleted.await();
            System.out.println("All over");
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you make a list of the threads, you can loop through them and .join() against each, and your loop will finish when all the threads have. I haven't tried it though.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()

Comment: Hi, it didn't work for me for some reason. Here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/users/5144855/ruchir-baronia

Answer (score 1):

Create the thread object inside the first for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
     threads[i] = new Thread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             // some code to run in parallel
         }
     });
     threads[i].start();
 }
```

And then so what everyone here is saying.

```
for(i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
  threads[i].join();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the Object ["ThreadGroup" and its parameter activeCount](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html#activeCount--):

Comment: Not sure how you exactly propose to do it. If you propose to poll activeCount in a loop: that's bad, since it's busy-wait (even if you sleep between polls - you then get a tradeoff between business and responsiveness).

Comment: @Martin v. Löwis: "Join will wait for just a single thread. A better solution might be a
java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch. Simply initialize the latch with
the count set to the number of worker threads. Each worker thread
should call countDown() just before it exits, and the main thread
simply calls await(), which will block until the counter reaches zero. The problem with join() is also that you can't start adding more threads dynamically.  The list will explode with a Concurrent
Modification." Your solution works fine for the Problem but not for general purpose.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to **CountDownLatch** you can also use **CyclicBarrier** e.g.

```
public class ThreadWaitEx {
    static CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(100, new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            System.out.println("clean up job after all tasks are done.");
        }
    });
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            Thread t = new Thread(new MyCallable(barrier));
            t.start();
        }       
    }

}    

class MyCallable implements Runnable{
    private CyclicBarrier b = null;
    public MyCallable(CyclicBarrier b){
        this.b = b;
    }
    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            //do something
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" is waiting for barrier after completing his job.");
            b.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }       
}
```

To use CyclicBarrier in this case barrier.await() should be the last statement i.e. when your thread is done with its job. CyclicBarrier can be used again with its reset() method. To quote javadocs:

*A CyclicBarrier supports an optional Runnable command that is run once per barrier point, after the last thread in the party arrives, but before any threads are released. This barrier action is useful for updating shared-state before any of the parties continue.*

Comment: I don't think that is is a good example for CyclicBarrier. Why do you use a Thread.sleep() call?

Comment: @Guenther - yes, I changed the code to suite the requirement.

Comment: CyclicBarrier is not an alternative to CountDownLatch. When threads must repeatedly count down you should create a CyclicBarrier, otherwise default to CountDownLatch (unless otherwise requiring additional abstraction of  Execution, at which point you should look to the higher-level, Services).

Answer (score 0):

The `join()` was not helpful to me. see this sample in Kotlin:

```
    val timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
    ThreadUtils.startNewThread(Runnable {
        for (i in 1..5) {
            val t = Thread(Runnable {
                Thread.sleep(50)
                var a = i
                kotlin.io.println(Thread.currentThread().name + "|" + "a=$a")
                Thread.sleep(200)
                for (j in 1..5) {
                    a *= j
                    Thread.sleep(100)
                    kotlin.io.println(Thread.currentThread().name + "|" + "$a*$j=$a")
                }
                kotlin.io.println(Thread.currentThread().name + "|TaskDurationInMillis = " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - timeInMillis))
            })
            t.start()
        }
    })
```

The result:

```
Thread-5|a=5
Thread-1|a=1
Thread-3|a=3
Thread-2|a=2
Thread-4|a=4
Thread-2|2*1=2
Thread-3|3*1=3
Thread-1|1*1=1
Thread-5|5*1=5
Thread-4|4*1=4
Thread-1|2*2=2
Thread-5|10*2=10
Thread-3|6*2=6
Thread-4|8*2=8
Thread-2|4*2=4
Thread-3|18*3=18
Thread-1|6*3=6
Thread-5|30*3=30
Thread-2|12*3=12
Thread-4|24*3=24
Thread-4|96*4=96
Thread-2|48*4=48
Thread-5|120*4=120
Thread-1|24*4=24
Thread-3|72*4=72
Thread-5|600*5=600
Thread-4|480*5=480
Thread-3|360*5=360
Thread-1|120*5=120
Thread-2|240*5=240
Thread-1|TaskDurationInMillis = 765
Thread-3|TaskDurationInMillis = 765
Thread-4|TaskDurationInMillis = 765
Thread-5|TaskDurationInMillis = 765
Thread-2|TaskDurationInMillis = 765
```

Now let me use the `join()` for threads:

```
    val timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
    ThreadUtils.startNewThread(Runnable {
        for (i in 1..5) {
            val t = Thread(Runnable {
                Thread.sleep(50)
                var a = i
                kotlin.io.println(Thread.currentThread().name + "|" + "a=$a")
                Thread.sleep(200)
                for (j in 1..5) {
                    a *= j
                    Thread.sleep(100)
                    kotlin.io.println(Thread.currentThread().name + "|" + "$a*$j=$a")
                }
                kotlin.io.println(Thread.currentThread().name + "|TaskDurationInMillis = " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - timeInMillis))
            })
            t.start()
            t.join()
        }
    })
```

And the result:

```
Thread-1|a=1
Thread-1|1*1=1
Thread-1|2*2=2
Thread-1|6*3=6
Thread-1|24*4=24
Thread-1|120*5=120
Thread-1|TaskDurationInMillis = 815
Thread-2|a=2
Thread-2|2*1=2
Thread-2|4*2=4
Thread-2|12*3=12
Thread-2|48*4=48
Thread-2|240*5=240
Thread-2|TaskDurationInMillis = 1568
Thread-3|a=3
Thread-3|3*1=3
Thread-3|6*2=6
Thread-3|18*3=18
Thread-3|72*4=72
Thread-3|360*5=360
Thread-3|TaskDurationInMillis = 2323
Thread-4|a=4
Thread-4|4*1=4
Thread-4|8*2=8
Thread-4|24*3=24
Thread-4|96*4=96
Thread-4|480*5=480
Thread-4|TaskDurationInMillis = 3078
Thread-5|a=5
Thread-5|5*1=5
Thread-5|10*2=10
Thread-5|30*3=30
Thread-5|120*4=120
Thread-5|600*5=600
Thread-5|TaskDurationInMillis = 3833
```

As it's clear when we use the `join`:

1. The threads are running sequentially.
2. The first sample takes 765 Milliseconds while the second sample takes 3833 Milliseconds.

---

Our solution to prevent blocking other threads was creating an ArrayList:

```
val threads = ArrayList<Thread>()
```

Now when we want to start a new thread we most add it to the ArrayList:

```
addThreadToArray(
    ThreadUtils.startNewThread(Runnable {
        ...
    })
)
```

The `addThreadToArray` function:

```
@Synchronized
fun addThreadToArray(th: Thread) {
    threads.add(th)
}
```

The `startNewThread` funstion:

```
fun startNewThread(runnable: Runnable) : Thread {
    val th = Thread(runnable)
    th.isDaemon = false
    th.priority = Thread.MAX_PRIORITY
    th.start()
    return th
}
```

Check the completion of the threads as below everywhere it's needed:

```
val notAliveThreads = ArrayList<Thread>()
for (t in threads)
    if (!t.isAlive)
        notAliveThreads.add(t)
threads.removeAll(notAliveThreads)
if (threads.size == 0){
    // The size is 0 -> there is no alive threads.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with:

```java
for(i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
  threads[i].join();
```

...is, that `threads[i + 1]` never can join before `threads[i]`.
Except the "latch"ed ones, all solutions have this lack.

No one here (yet) mentioned [ExecutorCompletionService](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html), it allows to join threads/tasks according to their completion order:

> `public class ExecutorCompletionService<V>`
> `extends Object`
> `implements CompletionService<V>`
>
> A `CompletionService` that uses a supplied `Executor` to execute tasks. This class arranges that submitted tasks are, upon completion, placed on a queue accessible using take. The class is lightweight enough to be suitable for transient use when processing groups of tasks.
>
> **Usage Examples.**
>
> Suppose you have a set of solvers for a certain problem, each returning a value of some type Result, and would like to run them concurrently, processing the results of each of them that return a non-null value, in some method `use(Result r)`. You could write this as:
>
> ```java
> void solve(Executor e, Collection<Callable<Result>> solvers) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
>   CompletionService<Result> cs = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(e);
>   solvers.forEach(cs::submit);
>   for (int i = solvers.size(); i > 0; i--) {
>     Result r = cs.take().get();
>     if (r != null)
>       use(r);
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Suppose instead that you would like to use the first non-null result of the set of tasks, ignoring any that encounter exceptions, and cancelling all other tasks when the first one is ready:
>
> ```java
> void solve(Executor e, Collection<Callable<Result>> solvers) throws InterruptedException {
>   CompletionService<Result> cs = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(e);
>   int n = solvers.size();
>   List<Future<Result>> futures = new ArrayList<>(n);
>   Result result = null;
>   try {
>     solvers.forEach(solver -> futures.add(cs.submit(solver)));
>     for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
>       try {
>         Result r = cs.take().get();
>         if (r != null) {
>           result = r;
>           break;
>         }
>       } catch (ExecutionException ignore) {}
>     }
>   } finally {
>     futures.forEach(future -> future.cancel(true));
>   }
>
>   if (result != null)
>     use(result);
> }
> ```
>
> ##### Since: 1.5 (!)

Assuming `use(r)` (of Example 1) also asynchronous, we had a big advantage. #