# ExecutorCompletionService? Why do need one if we have invokeAll?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice, java.util.concurrent

If we use an [ExecutorCompletionService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) we can submit a series of tasks as `Callable`s and get the result interacting with the `CompletionService` as a `queue`.

But there is also the `invokeAll` of `ExecutorService` that accepts a `Collection` of tasks and we get a list of `Future` to retrieve the results.

As far as I can tell, there is no benefit in using one or over the other (except that we avoid a `for` loop using an `invokeAll` that we would have to `submit` the tasks to the `CompletionService`) and essentially they are the same idea with a slight difference.

So why are there 2 different ways to submit a series of tasks? Am I correct that performance wise they are equivalent? Is there a case that one is more suitable than the other? I can't think of one.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Using a `ExecutorCompletionService.poll/take`, you are receiving the `Future`s as they finish, in completion order (more or less). Using `ExecutorService.invokeAll`, you do not have this power; you either block until are all completed, or you specify a timeout after which the incomplete are cancelled.

---

```
static class SleepingCallable implements Callable<String> {

  final String name;
  final long period;

  SleepingCallable(final String name, final long period) {
    this.name = name;
    this.period = period;
  }

  public String call() {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(period);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) { }
    return name;
  }
}
```

Now, below I will demonstrate how `invokeAll` works:

```
final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
final List<? extends Callable<String>> callables = Arrays.asList(
    new SleepingCallable("quick", 500),
    new SleepingCallable("slow", 5000));
try {
  for (final Future<String> future : pool.invokeAll(callables)) {
    System.out.println(future.get());
  }
} catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException ex) { }
pool.shutdown();
```

This produces the following output:

```
C:\dev\scrap>java CompletionExample
... after 5 s ...
quick
slow
```

---

Using `CompletionService`, we see a different output:

```
final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
final CompletionService<String> service = new ExecutorCompletionService<String>(pool);
final List<? extends Callable<String>> callables = Arrays.asList(
    new SleepingCallable("slow", 5000),
    new SleepingCallable("quick", 500));
for (final Callable<String> callable : callables) {
  service.submit(callable);
}
pool.shutdown();
try {
  Future<String> future;
  do {
    future = pool.isTerminated() ? service.poll() : service.take();
    if (future != null) {
      System.out.println(future.get());
    }
  } while (future != null);
} catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException ex) { }
```

This produces the following output:

```
C:\dev\scrap>java CompletionExample
... after 500 ms ...
quick
... after 5 s ...
slow
```

Note the times are relative to program start, not the previous message.

---

Test out a [working example on Replit](https://replit.com/@ashrams-haggard/OverjoyedSquigglySigns#Main.java).

Comment: So you are saying that in the `List<Future>` returned from `invokeAll` if start to iterate over the results, I could block on the first until it finishes, while in the `ExecutioncCompletion` I would block until any one result is available?Have I got your point?

Comment: +1 Yeah that's right @user384706.  Underneath the `ExecutorCompletionService` is a `BlockingQueue<Future<V>>` so you can wait for the _first_ job to complete instead of all of them.

Comment: @user384706 well, using the non-timeout form returns the `Future`s after all have completed, blocking indefinitely.

Comment: @Gray:But in `invokeAll` I don't wait for all to complete either

Comment: @user384706 when you call `invokeAll` it waits for all of the them to complete before finishing.  When `ExecutorCompletionService.poll/take` returns, you know that the resulting `get()` is not going to block.

Comment: @user384706 then perhaps you don't want `invokeAll`, unless you're OK with [cancelling unfinished tasks using a timeout](http://goo.gl/9gHG1).

Comment: @Gray actually I was incorrect... as it turns out, `ExecutorService.invokeAll` waits for completion.

Comment: @Gray:Ok, but it will block on `take` instead

Comment: I've added an answer with more details @user384706.  Yes it blocks on `take()`.

Comment: Btw @veer.  `take()` never returns `null`.

Comment: @Gray yes I know, but for some odd reason I felt compelled to put the assignment into the loop condition :p

Comment: Heh.  I _never_ put the assignment in the loop condition. A pet peeve I guess.  Good answer. :-)

Comment: @veer:I don't understand why in your first example (`invokeAll`) it prints `slow` first.I believe that I have read that the `Future` are returned in the same order are the `Iterator` of the passed `Collection` to `invokeAll` would return them.So I would expect to see `quick` first since `quick` is first in the passed `List` of the `invokeAll`

Comment: @user384706 good catch, I changed the order I submit them in without updating the output. It was to demonstrate that it waits for both to complete regardless of the order you put them in. I have since updated the output. Feel free to compile and run the full code from the paste.

Comment: @user384706 since you appear newer here, please don't forget to mark the answer [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) which helped most in solving the problem.

Comment: @veer:Good point. Thanks for ALL the great answers here by Gray and esaj as well

Comment: What do you mean by "in completion order _(more or less)_" ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D the order in which tasks complete i.e. if B finishes before A then the order would be B, A regardless of the order in which they're submit

Comment: @oldrinb: thanks - the _more or less_ part confused me - so they are guaranteed to return in the order they finish. You may want to edit this to make it more clear and let me know to delete the comments :)

Comment: But the executor can be terminated before we take all futures. For example, two callables complete almost at the same time, the first will be taken, second - no, as the executor will be terminated at that point.
I don't understand your `pool.shutdown()` +  `!pool.isTerminated()`

Comment: @Ivan [`shutdown`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown--) refuses new tasks & initiates an _orderly_ shutdown but the pool is not [`terminated`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#isTerminated--) until previously submitted tasks are completed

Comment: @obataku Yes, but tasks can be completed and the pool terminated before we call get on all futures in your example, so some results can be lost. Simulate longer processing after `future.get()`, in your example `Thread.sleep(4550)` and you never see "slow"

Comment: @Ivan I see your point, thanks for noting; should be addressed now

Comment: @obataku current example doesn't compile around `while (future != null)`

Comment: @Ivan corrected and updated with live replit link; I previously had introduced a `terminated` variable for the loop condition but refactored it away in the slackoverflow editor incorrectly

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D reported completion order for concurrent tasks is somewhat inexact and subject to a race for tasks that complete at nearly the same time

Answer (score 20):

> So why are there 2 different ways to submit a series of tasks? Am I correct that performance wise they are equivalent? Is there a case that one is more suitable than the other? I can't think of one.

By using an `ExecutorCompletionService`, you can get immediately notified when *each* of your jobs completes.  In comparison, `ExecutorService.invokeAll(...)` waits for *all* of your jobs to complete before returning the collection of `Future`s. This means that (for example), if all but one job completes in 10 minutes but 1 job takes 30 minutes, you will get no results for 30 minutes.

```
// this waits until _all_ of the jobs complete
List<Future<Object>> futures = threadPool.invokeAll(...);
```

Instead, when you use a `ExecutorCompletionService`, you will be able to get the jobs as soon as each of them completes which allows you to (for example) send them on for processing into another thread pool, log results immediately, etc..

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
ExecutorCompletionService<Result> compService
      = new ExecutorCompletionService<Result>(threadPool);
for (MyJob job : jobs) {
    compService.submit(job);
}
// shutdown the pool but the jobs submitted continue to run
threadPool.shutdown();
while (true) {
    Future<Result> future;
    // if pool has terminated (all jobs finished after shutdown) then poll() else take()
    if (threadPool.isTerminated()) {
        future = compService.poll();
        if (future == null) {
            break;
        }
    } else {
        // the take() blocks until any of the jobs complete
        // this joins with the jobs in the order they _finish_
        future = compService.take();
    }
    // this get() won't block
    Result result = future.get();
    // you can then put the result in some other thread pool or something
    // to immediately start processing it
    someOtherThreadPool.submit(new SomeNewJob(result));
}
```

Comment: `while(!threadPool.isTerminated())` is not it a busy formal waiting?

Comment: It is but `take()` blocks so it isn't spinning.  Did I answer your question @Sergio?

Comment: Yes thanks! I was digging on how to limit the blocking queue that there is inside `Executors.newFixedThreadPool`. In particular I am using the `ListenableFuture`

Comment: @Gray I did not understand your explanation of `while(!threadPool.isTerminated())`. Why is it needed? What purpose does it serve?

Comment: `isTerminate()` is true if the pool has shutdown and all of the jobs have completed.  Is that what you are asking @tinkuge?

Comment: @Gray The edit makes it a lot more clearer, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I haven't ever actually used ExecutorCompletionService, but I think the case where this could be more useful than "normal" ExecutorService would be when you want to receive the Futures of completed tasks in completion order. With invokeAll, you just get a list that can contain a mix of incomplete and completed tasks at any given time.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing by Considering only the Order of Results:

When we use `CompletionService` whenever a job submitted is finished the result will be pushed to the queue (Completion Order). Then the order of the submitted jobs and the returned results  is no more same. So if you are concerned about the order which tasks got executed use `CompletionService`

Where As `invokeAll` returns a  list of Futures representing the tasks, in the same sequential order as produced by the iterator for the given task list, each of which has completed.