# Open a new terminal window and execute command in it by java without using bash script

Tags: java, macos, bash, terminal

For examples, this is my bash script

```
osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"
 do script "./process1"
end tell'

osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"
 do script "./process2"
end tell'
```

Basically, it will open two different terminal windows (on mac) and execute defined commands. I try to do this in java by

```
process1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"process1"});
process2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"process2"});
```

The problem is it seems that there is only one terminal is opened (and not visible - it runs in background) and then two command process1 and process2 are executed. But because the process 1 will keep that terminal busy thus process2 cannot run. That's why I want to open different terminal to execute those commands.

Comment: You could always create a thread for each process. Then you can what until process1 is complete before starting process2

Comment: I did try to wrap them in different Threads, then execute each thread, but there was no successful

Comment: Have you tried with ProcessBuilder instead of Runtime ? You might need to redirect standard input, output and error also to make the new process independent of the JVM process.

Comment: I will try it, but i dont think they are different

Comment: Could you post your threading code?

Comment: basically i wrap each process in this   Thread thread = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
      System.out.println("Thread Running");  
    }
  }
 
  thread.start();

Comment: but then do you wait for the the first thread to stop? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361029/waiting-on-multiple-threads-to-complete-in-java

Comment: if the first thread stop , will the process 1 will also be killed ? that's what i dont want...

Comment: basically, what i did was thread1.start() then thread2.start()

Answer (score 0):

Create a thread for each one of them. and give a time space "sleep(for some time thread 1 or 2)" and this will run both depending on you operating system.