# How can I run my last thread to run once all my threads completes their execution?

Tags: java, multithreading

Lets say I have X number of threads are running in parallel mode and at the same time I want my new thread to be run only after all X numbers are finished?

Comment: Did you start the threads yourself? Because then you could keep a counter of the number of threads started, have them callback on completion to reduce the counter, and if the last one sets the counter to 0 run your new thread.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Waiting on multiple threads to complete in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361029/waiting-on-multiple-threads-to-complete-in-java)

Comment: You won't be able to create complex programs if you think that pissing after all threads terminated is different from the problem of doing poos after threads terminated. Start exercising [reductionism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductionism).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [`CyclicBarrier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html), or a [`Phaser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html) if you need multiple stages with different numbers of threads in each one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CountDownLatch`. Just

- set `n` in Latch constructor
- at the end of each worker thread use `yourLatchInstance.countDown()`
- at start of waiting thread use `await()`. After `countDown()` will be invoked `n` times waiting thread will be free.

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/FMaIPI)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Thread thread: threads)
  thread.join();

new MyNewThread().start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public class Main {

    /** The initial number of threads launched*/
    public static final int INITIAL_THREADS = 10;

    /** When less than MIN_THREADS are running, a new Thread is thrown. */ 
    public static final int MIN_THREADS = 5;

    /**  */
    public static final int TOTAL_THREADS_TO_PROCESS = 30;


    /** Launches INITIAL_THREADS and ends  */
    public static void main(String[] args){


            for(int i=0; i<INITIAL_THREADS; i++)
                new Thread( new MyThread() ).start();
        }

}


class MyThread implements Runnable{

    /** Stores the number of Threads runnning running. */
    private static int threadsRunning = 0;

    /** Stores the number of total thread processed.  Used as a exit confition */
    private static int threadProcessed = 0;


    @Override
    public  void run(){

        //With this synchronized block we modify the threadsRunning safely
        //synchronized(this)  <- Not valid because Threads objects are
        //  not the same instance.
        synchronized(MyThread.class){
            threadsRunning++;
            threadProcessed++;

            System.out.println("Threads running:" + threadsRunning +
                               ", Total Threads processed:" + threadProcessed +".");
        }


        //Thread Code here.  I simulate it with a 10 second sleep.
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        //Needed to read/write threadsRunning and threadProcessed safely
        synchronized(MyThread.class){

            threadsRunning--;

            if(threadsRunning < Main.MIN_THREADS &&
                    threadProcessed < Main.TOTAL_THREADS_TO_PROCESS)

                new Thread( new MyThread() ).start();
        }
    }
}
```

You could see that in specific moments, there will be less than 5 process running.  This is because a Threads ends and the system continues another Thread that also ends before the new Thread started by the first is launched (is still waiting).  This is less likely if the process is more heavy (in the example, if you change the 10 seconds by 100 or more).

If you wish to use another exit condition, for example, a variable calculated in the middle of the run method, remember to make it static, and the reads/writes to that variable must be enclosed by a synchronized(MyThread.class) block.