# How to wait for all threads (variable number of threads) to finish to move on with Main?

Tags: java, multithreading

I will make many threads according to user input in a for loop. Therefore I won't be able to assign names for them. Is there a way to wait all of them to finish to move on with my main thread? I want them to be finished out of that for loop. I know I need to use a join but with many many threads, how will I use it? Or is there another way? It will be like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i<inputs.size(); i++)
  new SimpleThread(parameters).start();
```

go on with only main thread, others finished.

How can I do this?

Comment: You may want to consider using one work thread and adding [SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)s to it

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to wait for a set of threads to complete?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252190/how-to-wait-for-a-set-of-threads-to-complete)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Store the threads in a `List<Thread>`, then iterate the list and use `thread.join()`

You can also take a look at `java.util.concurrent` aids. [`CyclicBarrier`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) or `CountDownLatch` (as indicated by others) for example.

Comment: Thank you I guess this is a simpler approach. I did it

Answer (score 5):

Use a `java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch`. Pass it along with parameters.

Also consider using a `java.util.concurrent.Executors.newFixedThreadPool()` to manage your thread life cycles (starting, stopping threads).

Answer (score 2):

Create a countdown latch in the main thread, passed to the threads you spawn:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html