# Shutdown connection to RabbitMQ

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I have created a simple Console Application listening to messages on Rabbit MQ. Works fine. No problems there. But how do I close the connection. I've been googleing arround a lot, but I didn't find any clear answers. The closest I got to an answer is this SO question: [What is the best way to safely end a java application with running RabbitMQ consumers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699669/what-is-the-best-way-to-safely-end-a-java-application-with-running-rabbitmq-cons), but the answer omits the most important part: The code!

Here is my code:

```
package com.company;

import com.rabbitmq.client.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

interface ObjectRecievedListener {
    void objectRecieved(Object obj);
}

public class RabbitMQReceiver extends RabbitMQBase
{

    ArrayList<DefaultConsumer> consumers = new ArrayList<>();

    private List<ObjectRecievedListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();
    private final Connection connection;
    private final Channel channel;

    public RabbitMQReceiver(RabbitMQProperties properties) throws IOException, TimeoutException {
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost(properties.getHost());
        factory.setPassword(properties.getPassword());
        factory.setUsername(properties.getLogin());

        connection = factory.newConnection();
        channel = connection.createChannel();
        channel.queueDeclare(properties.getInboundQueueName(), true, false, false, null);
        channel.basicQos(1);

        final Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
            @Override
            public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body) throws IOException {
                String message = new String(body, "UTF-8");


                try {
                    doWork(message);
                } finally {
                    channel.basicAck(envelope.getDeliveryTag(), false);
                }
            }
        };

        consumers.add((DefaultConsumer) consumer);

        boolean autoAck = false;
        channel.basicConsume(properties.getInboundQueueName(), autoAck, consumer);
    }

    public void addListener(ObjectRecievedListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void stop() {
        try {
            channel.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    private void doWork(String message) {
        Object obj = getObjectFromXML(message);

        for (ObjectRecievedListener l : listeners)
            l.objectRecieved(obj);
        stop();
    }
}
```

But it doesn't stop just because I called `stop()`

So in short: How do I close the connection to Rabbit MQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "it doesn't stop" have you confirmed that the `stop()` method is actually called? Is your code hanging on one of the `close()` methods?

The `channel` instance will have a [`basicCancel` method](https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html) that you could call to cancel the current consumer before closing the channel and connection. To be honest, closing the channel will cancel your consumer so I doubt this is the root cause of the issue.

Answer (score -3):

**Try this:**

```
let connection = null;

    connection = await amqp.connect(`amqp://${config.username}:${config.password}@${config.host}:${config.port}`);

    connection.close();
```

Comment: This is JavaScript