# Trying to wait for all threads to finished

Tags: java, multithreading

For some reason after the second iteration in the for loop I get a java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException right when thread1 is started for the second time. I thought i using join properly according to the answer here [How to wait for a number of threads to complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252190/how-to-wait-for-a-set-of-threads-to-complete). My question is why on the second iteration am i getting an exception.

```
public void runThreads(){
        int numofTests;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number of iterations to be completed:");
        numofTests = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());///Gets the number of tests from the user
        Agent agent = new Agent(numofTests);
        Smoker Pat = new Smoker ("paper", "Pam");
        Smoker Tom = new Smoker ("tobacco", "Tom");
        Smoker Matt = new Smoker ("matches", "Matt");
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(Pat);
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(Tom);
        Thread thread3 = new Thread(Matt);
        Thread thread4 = new Thread(agent);

        for (int i = 0; i < numofTests; i++){
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        thread3.start();
        thread4.start();
        try {
            thread1.join();
            thread2.join();
            thread3.join();
            thread4.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't start a thread multiple times. If you want to execute a runnable multiple times, re-create a new thread.

Comment: I had no idea thanks a lot i just moved my Threads intialztion into the loop and it works like a charm