# How do I stop a subroutine from ending before all contained threads are finished?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-fragments, android-activity

Basically, I have several threads each completing tasks.

Although I have multithreaded the tasks within this subroutine to speed up overall program speed.

I need this subroutine to only close when **all** threads within it are finished, as after this subroutine is complete the information generated is required by the next subroutine to run in the program.

In contrast to what happens now, which is allowing the subroutine to close and leaving contained threads to run in their own time, in the background. Which forces the next subroutine to run, to only act on partial data.

How do I do this?

Code:

```
public void MainSetupTasks() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            // Tasks to be complete

        }
    }).start();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            // Tasks to be complete

        }
    }).start();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            // Tasks to be complete

        }
    }).start();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            // Tasks to be complete

        }
    }).start();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            // Tasks to be complete

        }
    }).start();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            // Tasks to be complete

        }
    }).start();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            // Tasks to be complete

        }
    }).start();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            // Tasks to be complete

        }
    }).start();

}
```

Comment: Sounds like you should get familiar with the Java Concurrency docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Comment: you want each one to wait the other ? or you want to get an event when all of them are done ?

Comment: Well, why don't you use an `ExecutorService` instead?

Comment: I've never used "ExecutorService" before, could you please show a code example?

Comment: if i m getting your problem,You need Cyclicbarrier or countdownlatch.is it not possibble by join?

Answer (score 1):

To solve your immediate problem, you could use something like [How to wait for a set of threads to complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252190/how-to-wait-for-a-set-of-threads-to-complete)

But this is pretty ugly.  The built-in [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) lets you launch background threads in a much cleaner way.

Comment: ExecutorService seems like the much better choice, do you mind showing a code example?

Comment: [This](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html) looks like a pretty good tutorial.