# What is the Java equivalent of Golang's WaitGroup

Tags: java, go

Golang has something called a `WaitGroup` which is sort of like in Java a `CompletionService` or a `CountDownLatch` or a `Semaphore` or some combination of the latter.

I'm not entirely sure how you would implement a WaitGroup in Java. I would imagine a custom CompletionService with some sort of Poison message would be the route to go (since queues can't say when they are done) but perhaps there is a better concurrent data structure/lock?

EDIT I posted a possible solution below using `Semaphore` that I think is more analogous than using `thread.join`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to wait for a set of threads to complete?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252190/how-to-wait-for-a-set-of-threads-to-complete)

Comment: I don't know Java but, for the case where you `wg.Add(n)` before starting all *n* tasks, [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) looks like a fit, using `countDown()` for `wg.Done()` and `await()` for `wg.Wait()`.

Comment: The accepted answer on the linked question could work too, since threads are objects in Java. But they're slightly different: with CountDownLatch a thread can do other work after it finishes the task (so you could use it handing tasks to a pool of long-lived threads), with `thread.join()` it can't. Since the tasks differ a little I'm not voting to close as dupe.

Comment: I'm using CountdownLatch for most cases I'd use a WaitGroup in Go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`WaitGroup` has `Add(delta)` method that can be called after a `WaitGroup` has been created. `CountDownLatch` doesn't support this, number of tasks needs to be specified in advance. JDK7 `Phaser` can be used instead in this case:

```
phaser.register = wg.Add(1)
phaser.arrive = wg.Done
phaser.await = wg.Wait
```

Comment: One important note is that the main thread must register or set the number of parties to `1` initially (WaitGroup has this as 0) . If this isn't done, there can be problems with threads arriving at different phases making the final await never complete.

Answer (score 5):

```
public class WaitGroup {

    private int jobs = 0;

    public synchronized void add(int i) {
        jobs += i;
    }

    public synchronized void done() {
        if (--jobs == 0) {
            notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void await() throws InterruptedException {
        while (jobs > 0) {
            wait();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @kostya's answer.
I write a WaitGroup class with [Phaser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html)

```java
public class WaitGroup {

    Phaser phaser = new Phaser(1);

    public void add() {
        phaser.register();
    }

    public void done() {
        phaser.arrive();
    }

    public void await() {
        phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the golang doc and confirming that Semaphore won't break with an enormous amount of permits I think a `Semaphore` set to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is the closest to a golang `WaitGroup`.

The `thread.join` is probably more similar to how you would use WaitGroup with goroutines since it deals with the cleanup of the threads however an isolated `WaitGroup` just like a `Semaphore` is agnostic of what increments it.

CountdownLatch doesn't work because you need to know a priori how many threads you want to run and you cannot increment a CountdownLatch.

Assuming the semaphore is set to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`:

`wg.Add(n)` == `semaphore.acquire(n)`

`wg.Done()` == `semaphore.release()`

and in your thread where you want everything to stop:

`wg.Wait()` == `semaphore.acquire(Integer.MAX_VALUE)`

However I'm not sure all the semantics carryover so I'm not going to mark this correct for now.

Comment: Why would wg.wait() == acquire(Integer.MAX_VALUE), wg.Wait() in go would block current go routine until all Add has been Done.

Comment: Because Semaphore.acquire blocks till it can get all permits. The only way it can get all permits at Integer.MAX_VALUE is everyone else has released their permit.

Answer (score -3):

No, there is no 'CountDownLatch' in Go.

`sync.WaitGroup` may have the 'wait task finish' feature, but this API's `Add()` doesn't happens-befor `Done()`.

Comment: Please remember that we have a **[Be Nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)** policy on Stack Overflow; this includes not using profanity or obscenities in your posts. In the future, please keep all posts profanity-free. In the meantime, this post has been edited to keep it in line with the policies. Thanks for understanding.