# How to use java.Set

Tags: java, collections, interface, set

I'm trying to make it working for quite some time,but just can't seem to get it. I have object Tower built of Block's. I've already made it working using arrays, but I wanted to learn Set's. I'd like to get similar functionality to this:

```
public class Tower {


public Tower(){
}

public Tower add(Block k1){

    //(...)
    //if block already in tower, return "Block already in tower"
}

public Tower delete(Block k1){

    //(...)
    //if block already dleted, show "No such block in tower"
}

}
```

Someone gave me some code, but I constantly get errors when trying to use it :

```
Set<Block> tower = new HashSet<Block>();

boolean added = tower.add( k1 );
if( added ) {
System.out.println("Added 1 block.");
} else {
System.out.println("Tower already contains this block.");
}
```

How to implement it ?

Comment: What are the errors that you get?

Comment: Well I just have no idea how to use it. Do I need add, delete methods ? Do I need constructor, or this code I've pasted is everything I need ?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The first thing you need to study is the [`java.util.Set` API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).

Here's a small example of how to use its methods:

```
    Set<Integer> numbers = new TreeSet<Integer>();

    numbers.add(2);
    numbers.add(5);

    System.out.println(numbers); // "[2, 5]"
    System.out.println(numbers.contains(7)); // "false"

    System.out.println(numbers.add(5)); // "false"
    System.out.println(numbers.size()); // "2"

    int sum = 0;
    for (int n : numbers) {
        sum += n;
    }
    System.out.println("Sum = " + sum); // "Sum = 7"

    numbers.addAll(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5));
    System.out.println(numbers); // "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]"

    numbers.removeAll(Arrays.asList(4,5,6,7));
    System.out.println(numbers); // "[1, 2, 3]"

    numbers.retainAll(Arrays.asList(2,3,4,5));
    System.out.println(numbers); // "[2, 3]"
```

Once you're familiar with the API, you can use it to contain more interesting objects. If you haven't familiarized yourself with the [`equals`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [`hashCode`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) contract, already, now is a good time to start.

In a nutshell:

- `@Override` **both or none; never just one.** (very important, because it must satisfied property: `a.equals(b) == true --> a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()`

  - Be careful with writing `boolean equals(Thing other)` instead; this is not a proper `@Override`.
- For non-null references `x, y, z`, `equals` must be:

  - reflexive: `x.equals(x)`.
  - symmetric: `x.equals(y)` if and only if `y.equals(x)`
  - transitive: if `x.equals(y) && y.equals(z)`, then `x.equals(z)`
  - consistent: `x.equals(y)` must not change unless the objects have mutated
  - `x.equals(null) == false`
- The general contract for `hashCode` is:

  - consistent: return the same number unless mutation happened
  - consistent with `equals`: if `x.equals(y)`, then `x.hashCode() == y.hashCode()`

    - strictly speaking, object inequality does not require hash code inequality
    - but hash code inequality necessarily requires object inequality
- What counts as mutation should be consistent between `equals` and `hashCode`.

Next, you may want to impose an ordering of your objects. You can do this by making your type implements [`Comparable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), or by providing a separate [`Comparator`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Having either makes it easy to sort your objects (`Arrays.sort`, `Collections.sort(List)`). It also allows you to use `SortedSet`, such as `TreeSet`.

---

Further readings on stackoverflow:

- [Overriding equals and hashCode in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)
- [When to use Comparable vs Comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266827/when-to-use-comparable-vs-comparator)

Answer (score 2):

Did you override [equals and hashCode](http://bytes.com/topic/java/insights/723476-overriding-equals-hashcode-methods) in the Block class?

EDIT:

I assumed you mean it doesn't work at runtime... did you mean that or at compile time?  If compile time what is the error message?  If it crashes at runtime what is the stack trace?  If it compiles and runs but doesn't work right then the equals and hashCode are the likely issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to answer this question with the information given.  Nothing looks particularly wrong with how you are using HashSet.

Well, I'll hazard a guess that it's not a compilation issue and, when you say "getting errors," you mean "not getting the behavior [you] want."

I'll also go out on a limb and suggest that maybe your Block's equals an hashCode methods are not properly overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a HashSet you will need to override **hashCode** and **equals** methods. http://preciselyconcise.com/java/collections/d_set.php has an example explaining how to implement hashCode and equals methods

Answer (score 0):

If You have to take pair of strings separated by white space and counting unique string present in each level then following logic will help you.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        Set<String> st=new HashSet<>();
        int t = s.nextInt();
        String [] pair_left = new String[t];
        String [] pair_right = new String[t];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            pair_left[i] = s.next();
            pair_right[i] = s.next();

        }
        for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
        {
            st.add(pair_left[i]+" "+pair_right[i]);
            System.out.println(st.size());
        }

//Write your code here

   }
}
```

OutPut:
3
A B
A B
C D
1
1
2