# How do I go through 2 list and check if the content of one element in the same as another element in a different list?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

```
private List<Actor> actors = new ArrayList<>();

public void addActors(Movie x)
{
if(actors.isEmpty())
{
    actors.addAll(x.getListOfActors());
}
else
{
    List<Actor> movieActors = x.getListOfActors();
    ArrayList<Actor> tempActors= new ArrayList<Actor>();
    for(int z = 0 ; z <actors.size(); z++)
    {

        for(int n = 0 ; n <movieActors.size();n++)
        {
            if(actors.get(z).getName().equals(movieActors.get(n).getName()))
                actors.get(z).addCount(); // actor count 
            else
            {
                tempActors.add(movieActors.get(n));
            }
        }
    }
    actors.addAll(tempActors);
}
}
```

So each movie object have a list of actors. And each actor objects have a int count object which is initialized at 1. Everything I run addActors(Movie x), 
i want to check if there is any actors in movie x that is in List actors. if there is, i want to increment count by 1 else just add it to List actors. This is my current way of doing it, i realized its wrong but i dont know how to fix it. I run the method twice or more, repeated actors will be added to List actors because of actors.addAll(tempActors). Is there a better way to do this ?

update: So the problem isnt with the string comparing. Even if i use .equals, it isnt the result i want.
sample test case:

movie: "frozen"

actors: Kristen Bell, Idina Menzel, Jonathan Groff, Josh Gad

movie: "the boss"

actors: Melissa McCarthy, Kristen Bell, Peter Dinklage, Ella Anderson

so if I use addActors(movie x) on these two movies, each actors should only appear once. In the List actors. And count for kristen bell should be at 2 now. everyone else is 1.(count is number of movies they are in)

however when i run this method with these two movies, my List actors now contains:

Kristen Bell
Idina Menzel
Jonathan Groff
Josh Gad
Melissa McCarthy
Peter Dinklage
Ella Anderson
Melissa McCarthy
Kristen Bell
Peter Dinklage
Ella Anderson
Melissa McCarthy
Kristen Bell
Peter Dinklage
Ella Anderson
Melissa McCarthy
Kristen Bell
Peter Dinklage
Ella Anderson

(sorry for long explanation, I don't know how else to explain this )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: No, the problem is not comparing strings. using == or .equals gives me same result.

Comment: @JackieChen by incrementing actor count what do you want to achieve? Do you want to save this count somewhere or what?

Comment: count in each actor is the number of movies they are in , so i add two movies with same actors, the actor count should now be 2. @nullpointer

Comment: you can maintain a `Map<Actor,Count>` (not literally | more of `Map<String, Integer>`) in general to store the count. and inside your `if` increment the count for each actor key.

Comment: okay , but how would i added other actors that are not in the List actors to the list ? @nullpointer

Comment: @JackieChen that is already taken care by your `else` code I guess. You are adding the actors not present already in a list to `tempActors` and eventually to `actors`

Comment: @nullpointer I think my problem is i'm repeatedly adding the same actors in each loop because of that else statement.

Comment: oh if you don't want duplicates , you can use `Set` instead of `List`

Comment: You store the count of occurence in `Actor` for each one ? I don't think an actor should store this information since this depends on the list you are comparing.

Comment: I was think if i can do this in one loop , it should be fine. But set would work so thanks! @nullpointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove every thing from else condition and replace with following code. Though its not an optimal solution but might serve your purpose.

```
else {
        List<Actor> movieActors = (List<Actor>) x.getListOfActors();
        for (int z = 0; z < x.getListOfActors().size(); z++) {
            Actor actor = movieActors.get(z);
            if (actors.contains(actor)) {
                actors.get(actors.indexOf(actor)).addCount();
            }else{
                actors.add(actor);
            }
        }
    }
```

And you have to Override equals method in Actor class

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(obj instanceof Actor){
        Actor a = (Actor)obj;
        if(this.name.equals(a.name)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: `count++` - count may not be visible here. Use `addCount()`

Comment: This assumes that Actor.equals() is implemented by comparing the actor names.

Comment: yea i altered the code. this question doesn't have all the details though. so had to assume a bit.

Comment: This is what im looking for. Thanks ! @AhmedRaaj

Comment: Cheers mate! Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Few open points --

*One*, I would suggest using `foreach` for DS like `List` to iterate through.
Take a look at [How does the Java 'for each' loop work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work)

*Two*, use `equals` to compare strings. Help -  [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

*Third*, use a counter variable, e.g. `int counter = 0;` which can be used to count the number of duplicate occurrences as

```
if(actors.get(z).getName().equals(movieActors.get(n).getName())) {
    counter++; //currently just saving the count, you can save the name as well
}
```

Updating from the comments discussion, to keep a count of actors that appeared in different movies :

You can maintain a `Map<Actor,Count>` (not literally | more of `Map<String, Integer>`) in general to store the count. and inside your if increment the count for each actor key.

Further to keep a unique list of actors, would suggest using `Set` instead of `ArrayList`. Please read [How to use java.Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490178/how-to-use-java-set)

Comment: Im not sure how a counter would help? Maybe I didnt explain it well but i edit it just now . The actor count variable is the number of movies they are in so if i added 2 movies with same actor in both movie, the count of that actor would be 2 now because that actor is in the two movies. @nullpointer

Answer (score 0):

When you do

> actors.get(z).getName() == movieActors.get(n).getName()

I suppose name is a string, in that case it will not be true for same names. You need to do

> actors.get(z).getName().equals(movieActors.get(n).getName())

Refer this - [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: ok, ill fix that. But i think the initial problem will still stand because i'm looking through movieActors, z times which will keep adding duplicate actor objects. @vijay jain

Comment: Correct me, if I am wrong, It will add duplicates if there are already duplicates in actors or movieActors. In that case you can opt for a set/hashset and override equals and hashcode methods in Actors class.

Comment: you're correct , it keeps adding duplicates because its loop n*z times. Using hashset would work. If i can do this using one loop , it should be fine , but not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ".equals" instead of "=="

Answer (score 0):

Same as @Ahmed Raaj.

```
else{

        List<Actor> movieActors = x.getListOfActors();      
        List<Actor> duplicateActors = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Actor> uniqueActors = new ArrayList<>();

        for(Actor eachActor : movieActor){
            if(actors.contains(eachActor))
                duplicateActors.add(eachActor);
            else
                uniqueActors.add(eachActor);
        }

        for(Actor eachDuplicateActor : duplicateActors){
            for(Actor eachOriginalActors : actors){
                if(eachOriginalActors.getName().equals(eachDuplicateActor.getName())
                        eachOriginalActors.addCount();
            }
        }

        actors.addAll(uniqueActors);
    }
```

I haven't tested the code, so there might be errors

Answer (score 0):

I think you should reverse the order of the loops, and only add the actor if it is not found:

```
for(int n = 0 ; n <movieActors.size();n++)
{
    boolean found = false;
    for(int z = 0 ; z <actors.size(); z++)
    {
        if(actors.get(z).getName().equals(movieActors.get(n).getName())) {
            actors.get(z).addCount(); // actor count
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        tempActors.add(movieActors.get(n));
    }
}
```

But I don't get the signification of `count`

Comment: thanks for the input , i found that if i just change tempActors to a hashset , everything will work fine.