# String, StringBuffer, and StringBuilder

Tags: java, string, oop, stringbuilder

Please tell me a real time situation to compare `String`, `StringBuffer`, and `StringBuilder`?

Answer (score 400, accepted):

**Mutability Difference:**

`String` is **immutable**, if you try to alter their values, another object gets created, whereas `StringBuffer` and `StringBuilder` are **mutable** so they can change their values.

**Thread-Safety Difference:**

The difference between `StringBuffer` and `StringBuilder` is that `StringBuffer` is thread-safe. So when the application needs to be run only in a single thread then it is better to use `StringBuilder`. `StringBuilder` is more efficient than `StringBuffer`.

**Situations:**

- If your string is not going to change use a String class because a `String` object is immutable.
- If your string can change (example: lots of logic and operations in the construction of the string) and will only be accessed from a single thread, using a `StringBuilder` is good enough.
- If your string can change, and will be accessed from multiple threads, use a `StringBuffer` because `StringBuffer` is synchronous so you have thread-safety.

Comment: Also, using String for logic operations is rather slow, and is not advised at all, since the JVM converts the String to a StringBuffer in the bytecode. A lot of overhead is wasted converting from String to StringBuffer and then back to String again.

Comment: So in `Strings` when we alter the value another object is created. Does the old object reference is nullified so that it may be garbage collected by the `GC` or is it even garbage collected?

Comment: @PietervanNiekerk What do you mean with logic operations?

Comment: logic operations i mean are basic String ones, Now one thing I would like to ask, as stated by @Peter should we start using StringBuffer instead on String in all cases or there are some specific cases?

Comment: @bakkal Can I use all the methods of `String` with `StringBuilder`?

Answer (score 49):

- You use [`String`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) when an immutable structure is appropriate; obtaining a new character sequence from a `String` may carry an unacceptable performance penalty, either in CPU time or memory (obtaining substrings is CPU efficient because the data is not copied, but this means a potentially much larger amount of data may remain allocated).
- You use [`StringBuilder`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) when you need to create a mutable character sequence, usually to concatenate several character sequences together.
- You use [`StringBuffer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) in the same circumstances you would use `StringBuilder`, but when changes to the underlying string must be synchronized (because several threads are reading/modifyind the string buffer).

See an example [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html).

Comment: concise, but incomplete, it misses the fundamental reason to use StringBuilder/Buffer and that is to reduce or eliminate the re-allocation and array copy of the regular String concatenation behavior.

Comment: "You use String when you are dealing with immutable strings" - doesn't make sense.  Instances of String ARE immutable, so maybe the comment should read "Use String when the memory usage due to immutability doesn't matter".  The accepted answer covers it's bases pretty well.

Answer (score 29):

**The Basics:**

`String` is an immutable class, it can't be changed.
[`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) is a mutable class that can be appended to, characters replaced or removed and ultimately converted to a `String`
`StringBuffer` is the original synchronized version of `StringBuilder`

You should prefer `StringBuilder` in all cases where you have only a single thread accessing your object.

**The Details:**

Also note that `StringBuilder/Buffers` aren't magic, they just use an Array as a backing object and that Array has to be re-allocated when ever it gets full. Be sure and create your `StringBuilder/Buffer` objects large enough originally where they don't have to be constantly re-sized every time `.append()` gets called.

The re-sizing can get very degenerate. It basically re-sizes the backing Array to 2 times its current size every time it needs to be expanded. This can result in large amounts of RAM getting allocated and not used when `StringBuilder/Buffer` classes start to grow large.

In Java `String x = "A" + "B";` uses a `StringBuilder` behind the scenes. So for simple cases there is no benefit of declaring your own. But if you are building `String` objects that are large, say less than 4k, then declaring `StringBuilder sb = StringBuilder(4096);` is much more efficient than concatenation or using the [default constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#StringBuilder--) which is only 16 characters. If your `String` is going to be less than 10k then initialize it with the constructor to 10k to be safe. But if it is initialize to 10k then you write 1 character more than 10k, it will get re-allocated and copied to a 20k array. So initializing high is better than to low.

In the auto re-size case, at the 17th character the backing Array gets re-allocated and copied to 32 characters, at the 33th character this happens again and you get to re-allocated and copy the Array into 64 characters. You can see how this degenerates to **lots** of re-allocations and copies which is what you really are trying to avoid using `StringBuilder/Buffer` in the first place.

This is from the JDK 6 Source code for AbstractStringBuilder

```
   void expandCapacity(int minimumCapacity) {
    int newCapacity = (value.length + 1) * 2;
        if (newCapacity < 0) {
            newCapacity = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        } else if (minimumCapacity > newCapacity) {
        newCapacity = minimumCapacity;
    }
        value = Arrays.copyOf(value, newCapacity);
    }
```

A best practice is to initialize the `StringBuilder/Buffer` a little bit larger than you think you are going to need if you don't know right off hand how big the `String` will be but you can guess. One allocation of slightly more memory than you need is going to be better than lots of re-allocations and copies.

Also beware of initializing a `StringBuilder/Buffer` with a `String` as that will only allocated the size of the String + 16 characters, which in most cases will just start the degenerate re-allocation and copy cycle that you are trying to avoid. The following is straight from the Java 6 source code.

```
public StringBuilder(String str) {
    super(str.length() + 16);
    append(str);
    }
```

If you by chance do end up with an instance of `StringBuilder/Buffer` that you didn't create and can't control the constructor that is called, there is a way to avoid the degenerate re-allocate and copy behavior. Call [`.ensureCapacity()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#ensureCapacity-int-) with the size you want to ensure your resulting `String` will fit into.

**The Alternatives:**

Just as a note, if you are doing really **heavy** `String` building and manipulation, there is a much more performance oriented alternative called [Ropes](http://ahmadsoft.org/ropes/).

Another alternative, is to create a `StringList` implemenation by sub-classing `ArrayList<String>`, and adding counters to track the number of characters on every `.append()` and other mutation operations of the list, then override `.toString()` to create a `StringBuilder` of the exact size you need and loop through the list and build the output, you can even make that `StringBuilder` an instance variable and 'cache' the results of `.toString()` and only have to re-generate it when something changes.

Also don't  forget about `String.format()` when building fixed formatted output, which can be optimized by the compiler as they make it better.

Comment: Does `String x = "A" + "B";` really compile to be a StringBuilder? Why wouldn't it just compile to `String x = "AB";`, it should only use a StringBuilder if the components aren't known at compile time.

Comment: it might optimize the String constants out, I can't recall from the last time decompiled the byte code, but I do know that if there are any variables in there it will use a StringBuilder implementation for sure. You can download the JDK source code and find out yourself. "A" + "B" is a contrived example for sure.

Comment: I was wondering about String.format(). I haven't ever really seen it being used in projects. Usually it's the StringBuilder. Well, usually it's actually "A" + "B" + "C" because people are lazy ;) I tended to always use a StringBuilder, even if it was only two strings being concatenated, because in future, perhaps more strings would be appended. I never used String.format() mainly because I never remembered what JDK it was introduced - I see it's JDK1.5, I'd use it in favour of the other options.

Answer (score 10):

Do you mean, for concatenation?

Real world example:  *You want to create a new string out of many others*.

For instance to send a message:

String

```
String s = "Dear " + user.name + "<br>" + 
" I saw your profile and got interested in you.<br>" +
" I'm  " + user.age + "yrs. old too"
```

StringBuilder

```
String s = new StringBuilder().append.("Dear ").append( user.name ).append( "<br>" ) 
          .append(" I saw your profile and got interested in you.<br>") 
          .append(" I'm  " ).append( user.age ).append( "yrs. old too")
          .toString()
```

Or

```
String s = new StringBuilder(100).appe..... etc. ...
// The difference is a size of 100 will be allocated upfront as  fuzzy lollipop points out.
```

StringBuffer ( the syntax is exactly as with StringBuilder, the effects differ )

About

`StringBuffer` vs. `StringBuilder`

The former is synchonized and later is not.

So, if you invoke it several times in a single thread ( which is 90% of the cases ),  `StringBuilder` will run **much** faster because it won't stop to see if it owns the thread lock.

So, it is recommendable to use `StringBuilder` ( unless of course you have more than one thread accessing to it at the same time, which is rare  )

`String` concatenation ( *using the + operator* )  may be optimized by the compiler to use `StringBuilder` underneath, so, it not longer something to worry about, in the elder days of Java, this was something that everyone says should be avoided at all cost, because every concatenation created a new String object. Modern compilers don't do this anymore, but still it is a good practice to use `StringBuilder` instead just in case you use an "old" compiler.

**edit**

Just for who is curious, this is what the compiler does for this class:

```
class StringConcatenation {
    int x;
    String literal = "Value is" + x;
    String builder = new StringBuilder().append("Value is").append(x).toString();
}
```

javap -c StringConcatenation

```
Compiled from "StringConcatenation.java"
class StringConcatenation extends java.lang.Object{
int x;

java.lang.String literal;

java.lang.String builder;

StringConcatenation();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   aload_0
   5:   new #2; //class java/lang/StringBuilder
   8:   dup
   9:   invokespecial   #3; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
   12:  ldc #4; //String Value is
   14:  invokevirtual   #5; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   17:  aload_0
   18:  getfield    #6; //Field x:I
   21:  invokevirtual   #7; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   24:  invokevirtual   #8; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
   27:  putfield    #9; //Field literal:Ljava/lang/String;
   30:  aload_0
   31:  new #2; //class java/lang/StringBuilder
   34:  dup
   35:  invokespecial   #3; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
   38:  ldc #4; //String Value is
   40:  invokevirtual   #5; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   43:  aload_0
   44:  getfield    #6; //Field x:I
   47:  invokevirtual   #7; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   50:  invokevirtual   #8; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
   53:  putfield    #10; //Field builder:Ljava/lang/String;
   56:  return

}
```

Lines numbered 5 - 27 are for the String named "literal"

Lines numbered 31-53 are for the String named "builder"

Ther's no difference, exactly the **same** code is executed for both strings.

Comment: this is a really bad example. Initializing the StringBuilder with " Dear " means the first .append() will cause a reallocation and copy. Completely negating any efficiency that you are trying to gain over "normal" concatenation. A better example would to be to create it with a initial size that will hold the entire contents of the final String.

Comment: It is NOT generally a good practice to use a `StringBuilder` to do String concatenation on the right-hand side of the assignment.  Any good implementation will use a StringBuilder behind the scenes as you say.  Furthermore, your example of `"a" + "b"` would be compiled into a single literal `"ab"` but if you used `StringBuilder` it would result in two needless calls to `append()`.

Comment: @Mark I didn't mean to use `"a"+"b"` but to say what was a *String concatenation* about I change it to be explicit. What you don't say is, why is not a good practice to do it. That's exactly what ( a modern ) compiler does. @fuzzy, I agree, specially when you know what the size of the final string would be ( aprox ) .

Comment: I don't think it's particularly *bad* practice, but I certainly wouldn't want any recommendation to do that in general.  It's clunky and hard to read, and overly verbose.  Plus, it encourages mistakes like yours where you are breaking up two literals that could otherwise be compiled as one.  Only if profiling told me it made a difference would I do it your way.

Comment: @Mark Got it. I was thinking more in the *"big chunk of code like a template"* and not really in every regular string literal. But yes, I agree, since they do the same thing nowadays, it doesn't make sense ( 10 yrs ago was a reason to reject a change in a code revision ) :)

Answer (score 8):

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                  String                    StringBuffer         StringBuilder
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------                 
Storage Area | Constant String Pool         Heap                   Heap 
Modifiable   |  No (immutable)              Yes( mutable )         Yes( mutable )
Thread Safe  |      Yes                     Yes                     No
 Performance |     Fast                 Very slow                  Fast
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Why String performance is fast and StringBuffer performance very slow?

Comment: @gaurav you can read its source code, all methods in StringBuffer is `synchronised` and that's the *why*.

Comment: Storage Area of String depends on How we are creating the String, let's say- Approach-1: String str1= "ABC" - The value will be stored in SCP.(it is inside Heap Memory) Approach-2: String str1= new String("ABC")- The Object will be created in Heap memory.

Answer (score 8):

[image: String Family]

**String**

The [`String class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) represents character strings. All string literals in Java program, such as `"abc"` are implemented as instances of this class.

String objects are **immutable** once they are created we can't change. (*Strings are constants*)

- If a String is created using constructor or method then those strings will be stored in ***Heap Memory*** as well as [***`SringConstantPool`***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37785577/5081877). But before saving in pool it invokes **`intern()`** method to check object availability with same content in pool using equals method. *If String-copy is available in the Pool then returns the reference. Otherwise, String object is added to the pool and returns the reference.*

  - *The Java language provides special support for the string concatenation operator (`+`), and for conversion of other objects to strings. String concatenation is implemented through the StringBuilder(or StringBuffer) class and its append method.*

  ```java
  String heapSCP = new String("Yash");
  heapSCP.concat(".");
  heapSCP = heapSCP + "M";
  heapSCP = heapSCP + 777;

  // For Example: String Source Code 
  public String concat(String str) {
      int otherLen = str.length();
      if (otherLen == 0) {
          return this;
      }
      int len = value.length;
      char buf[] = Arrays.copyOf(value, len + otherLen);
      str.getChars(buf, len);
      return new String(buf, true);
  }
  ```
- String literals are stored in `StringConstantPool`.

  ```java
  String onlyPool = "Yash";
  ```

---

**[StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and [StringBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html)** are mutable sequence of characters. That means one can change the value of these object's. StringBuffer has the same methods as the StringBuilder, but each method in StringBuffer is synchronized so it is thread safe.

- StringBuffer and StringBuilder data can only be created using new operator. So, they get stored in Heap memory.
- ***Instances of StringBuilder are not safe for use by multiple threads. If such synchronization is required then it is recommended that StringBuffer be used.***

  ```java
  StringBuffer threadSafe = new StringBuffer("Yash");
  threadSafe.append(".M");
  threadSafe.toString();

  StringBuilder nonSync = new StringBuilder("Yash");
  nonSync.append(".M");
  nonSync.toString();
  ```
- StringBuffer and StringBuilder are having a Special methods like.,
  `replace(int start, int end, String str)` and `reverse()`.

  > **NOTE**: StringBuffer and SringBuilder are mutable as they provides the implementation of `Appendable Interface`.

---

When to use which one.

- If a you are not going to change the value every time then its better to Use `String Class`. As part of Generics if you want to Sort [`Comparable<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31244596/5081877) or compare a values then go for `String Class`.

  ```java
  //ClassCastException: java.lang.StringBuffer cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
  Set<StringBuffer> set = new TreeSet<StringBuffer>();
  set.add( threadSafe );
  System.out.println("Set : "+ set);
  ```
- If you are going to modify the value every time the go for StringBuilder which is faster than StringBuffer. If multiple threads are modifying the value the go for StringBuffer.

Answer (score 4):

Also, `StringBuffer` is thread-safe, which `StringBuilder` is not.

So in a real-time situation when different threads are accessing it, `StringBuilder` could have an undeterministic result.

Answer (score 3):

Note that if you are using Java 5 or newer, you should use `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`. From the API documentation:

> As of release JDK 5, this class has been supplemented with an equivalent class designed for use by a single thread, `StringBuilder`. The `StringBuilder` class should generally be used in preference to this one, as it supports all of the same operations but it is faster, as it performs no synchronization.

In practice, you will almost never use this from multiple threads at the same time, so the synchronization that `StringBuffer` does is almost always unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I don't think there is any real world use for `StringBuffer`. When would I ever want to communicate between multiple threads by manipulating a character sequence? That doesn't sound useful at all, but maybe I have yet to see the light :)

Answer (score 3):

Difference between String and the other two classes is that String is immutable and the other two are mutable classes.

**But why we have two classes for same purpose?**

Reason is that `StringBuffer` is Thread safe and `StringBuilder` is not.
`StringBuilder` is a new class on `StringBuffer Api` and it was introduced in `JDK5` and is always recommended if you are working in a Single threaded environment as it is much `Faster`

For complete Details you can read http://www.codingeek.com/java/stringbuilder-and-stringbuffer-a-way-to-create-mutable-strings-in-java/

Answer (score 2):

In java, **String** is immutable. Being immutable we mean that once a String is created, we can not change its value. 
**StringBuffer** is mutable. Once a StringBuffer object is created, we just append the content to the value of object instead of creating a new object.
**StringBuilder** is similar to StringBuffer but it is not thread-safe. Methods of StingBuilder are not synchronized but in comparison to other Strings, the Stringbuilder runs fastest. 
You can learn difference between [String, StringBuilder and StringBuffer](https://kb4dev.com/tutorial/java/string,-stringbuffer-and-stringbuilder) by implementing them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small code snippet illustrating how you can break StringBuilder in an async environment

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000 * 1000; i++) {
        executorService.submit(new AppendRunnable(builder));
    }

    executorService.shutdown();
    executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

    Stream.of(builder.toString().split(System.lineSeparator()))
        .filter(line -> !line.equals("I just appended this!"))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}

record AppendRunnable(StringBuilder stringBuilder) implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        stringBuilder.append("I just appended this!\n");
    }
}
```

Essentially we append strings to the builder and we expect that all of them are equal to "I just appended this!". But they are not, some of them are prefixed with null chars because the internal char buffer of the builder is not synchronized and it gets wrongly resized. Using StringBuffer in this situation solves the problem. More detailed info [here](https://medium.com/@b.stoilov/when-to-use-stringbuffer-in-java-d0a1f57e2477)