# common methods between String and String buffer

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String, StringBuffer, and StringBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971315/string-stringbuffer-and-stringbuilder)

What are common methods between String and StringBuffer? And what is the difference between string and string buffer?

Comment: Hm, there is plenty of resources out there, which describes the difference and you can easily see the common methods. So, why do you ask this question here?

Comment: Why don't you look it up yourself in the [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/)?

Comment: And to quickly answer your question: String is immutable, while StringBuffer is mutable. When you have complex String, which you cannot construct in single step, you use StringBuffer which is converted to String. When you concatenate strings using '+', Java compiler converts this to calls to StringBuffer under the hood.

Comment: u can easily find this in java docs...??? are u interested in where we should use which???

Comment: yes.May i know where we should use which ? amod0017

Comment: @BoomirajP - there's lots been said about when to use which already on this very site: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+string+stringbuffer

Answer (score 2):

The biggest difference is that `String` is immutable and `StringBuffer` is mutable.

Answer (score 1):

`StringBuffer` lets you join strings faster. For example the following code:

```
String s = "Initial string ";
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    s = s + i;
}
```

on every iteration creates a string representing integer `i` and than also creates a new string of `s` and `i` joined together and moves `s` reference to this new object. It does not reuse the same `s` object by expanding its content.

`StringBuffer` lets you append string more efficiently. There is also a newer version of this class called `StringBuilder` which is basically `StringBuffer` without synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

The first few lines on the [`StringBuffer` JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) give a pretty good answer:

> A thread-safe, mutable sequence of characters. A string buffer is like a `String`, but can be modified.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to concatenate many String literal together, then it might be better off for you to use a `StringBuffer` object, and as when you are done with the concatenation, turning it into a `String` object using the `toString()` method.

EDIT: Please ignore the lines below

*The below instantiates 6 String objects in the String pool theoretically.*

```
String a = "A" + "B" + "C" + "D" + "E";
```

Comment: In *almost all* cases a [`StringBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) should be used over a `StringBuffer`: it provides the exact same API and only lacks synchronization (which is hardly ever useful on a `StringBuffer` anyway).

Comment: I reject the notion that StringBuilder should be used at all *except* in special situations like large template processing. If you have the "+"'s in your code, use what is most clear. Java Compilers may actually use StringBuilder for you!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but the example you gave does **not** produce 6 string objects. It produces a single `String`, because it's a constant expression.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer I always had the impression that 6 String objects are created, can you please reference me to any materials so that i may correct my understanding? ><

Comment: It's somewhat implied in [§3.10.5](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.5): "String literals-or, more generally, strings that are the values of constant expressions ([§15.28](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#5313))-are "interned" [...]." You can also easily verify it using `javap` by decompiling a simple test class.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious shared methods are those specified by the interface implemented by both [`String`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and [`StringBuffer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) (as well as [`StringBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)): [`Appendable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html). It provides 3 methods for appending other values.