# what is the difference between using StringBuilder instead String

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String, StringBuffer, and StringBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971315/string-stringbuffer-and-stringbuilder)

what is the difference (advantages, disadvantages) between using StringBuilder instead String

```
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
String cadena = "";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(fFileName), fEncoding);
try {
  while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    text.append(line);
    cadena += line;
  }
} finally {
  scanner.close();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's faster, but isn't thread-safe.

You can build strings basically three ways.

1. by just concatenating strings ("foo" + "bar") - slowest
2. by using StringBuffer, which is thread-safe, and faster than #1
3. by using StringBuilder, which is the fastest of all, but **not** thread-safe

**Some other distinctions:**

[String](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html): Strings are constant; their values cannot be changed after they are created. String **buffers** support mutable strings. Concatenating strings using the `+` operator doesn't modify the Strings involved, it creates a new String that is a combination of the Strings you're concatenating.

[StringBuffer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html): A thread-safe, mutable sequence of characters. A string buffer is like a String, but can be modified.

[StringBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html): A mutable sequence of characters. This class provides an API compatible with StringBuffer, but with no guarantee of synchronization.

Comment: ..plus, (1) will be creating a new instance of class String every time you do "+" since Strings are immutable.

Comment: ...though given that the compiler will turn most string concatenation (including that above) into a StringBuilder, it's not worth the effort to even worry about it unless you have a profiler telling you there's a problem.

Comment: Agreed. I hardly ever use anything but String concatenation, because that's never been the performance bottleneck in any app I've written, but that's technically the official answer. I'm not a fan of micro-optimizations without proof either.