# Java: How to concatenate Double to String

Tags: java

How can i concatenate `Double` to `String` in java?

I have following piece of code:

```
Double price = 5.34;
String trade = MSFT;
```

now I have `String key = price + trade`, not sure if this is right way of doing it, any suggestions?

Comment: What you propose does exactly that, it concatenates the double and the string. What is your question? Do you need a specific format for the double?

Comment: @assylias : i want to know if that is best way of doing it?

Comment: The best way depends on the context as the answers show: if you need to control the formatting, you can use String.format, if you don't care, using `+` as you do is totally fine, if you do it repeatedly many times, a StringBuilder could make sense, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java string concatenation is done by default with the `+` sign.

But there are times when this is not a good practice since this will create a new string instance every time you do it, so if you are in a loop this will create a new string in memory for each iteration.

So for simple cases, the `+` is perfectly valid.

For other cases, you should use [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

Comment: Agree w/ this answer. Can also use StringBuffer in other cases though (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971315/string-stringbuffer-and-stringbuilder)

Answer (score 4):

I would perhaps use [String.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) and you'll be able to control the formatting of the double in the string. e.g. you can control leading zeros, number of dps displayed etc.

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703396/how-to-nicely-format-floating-types-to-string) for examples. And here's the doc for the underlying [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax), and [the standard tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html).

Comment: what would be best way of doing it?

Comment: can you give an example of this Brian?

Comment: I've linked to some examples in an SO answer above

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.valueOf(price)` to convert. So you'd have

```
Double price = 5.34;
String trade = MSFT;
String key = String.valueOf(price) + trade;
```

Answer (score 0):

String key = Double.toString(price) + trade;

Answer (score 0):

To format the string - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

An example of how to use it.

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1326/java-decimal-format-to-easily-create-custom-output/

To output it, use the + operand. This creates another string if you're looking for performance. You can also use string builder - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert your Double with a toString().

```
Double price = 5.34;
String trade = MSFT;
String key = Double.toString(price) + trade;
```

Here is the detail for the toSting() method:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString(double)

But using a StringBuffer is more efficient.

Regards,
Dekx.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with `String key = price + trade`. It is much more readable than `String.valueOf(price) + trade` or using `StringBuilder`.

Comment: probably, i will go with same approach.