# In what cases String is usefull than StringBuffer & StringBuilder

Tags: java, string

if stringBuffer & StringBuilder are much usefull over String, why String class is not depreciated

Comment: They are used for completely different things.

Comment: StringBuilder is useful in situations where the compiler can't optimise the String manipulation, such is loops

Comment: There's a pretty good explanation about it in the `StringBuffer` documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html).

Comment: Define "much useful". In terms of what?

Answer (score 5):

It is about the purpose of each class.

`String` class represents a string or a set (array) of `char`s that can have a specific meaning for humans.

`AbstractStringBuilder` (which is the abstract non `public` super class for `StringBuilder` and `StringBuffer`) is mainly used to build the contents of a `String` and then generate a whole `String`. This is because `String` class is immutable, which means that any operation on a `String` generates a new `String` object, while any operation over `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` works on the state of the same reference, thus saving memory and gaining performance.

---

From [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2971343/1065197) of the possible duplicate Q/A:

> If your string is not going to change use a `String` class because a `String` object is immutable.

Note that this doesn't mean you cannot define a `String` when you don't know its specific value or if its value is the result of a basic concatenation. Here's an example:

```
String name = "Luiggi";
String helloLuiggi = "Hello " + "Luiggi";
String helloName = "Hello " + name;
```

In case above:

- `name` value will be `"Luiggi"`.
- `helloLuiggi` value will be `"Hello Luiggi"`. The compiler is smart enough to understand that `"Hello "` and `"Luiggi"` are literal `String` values and they should generate a single `String` automatic concatenation of `"Hello "` and `"Luiggi"`, this doesn't generate any performance overhead.
- `helloName` value will be the result of concatenating `"Hello "` and `name` strings. In this case, the compiler will use a `StringBuilder` behind the scenes for you to improve the performance of the operation.

> If your string can change (example: lots of logic and operations in the construction of the string) and will only be accessed from a single thread, using a `StringBuilder` is good enough.

This is **completely true**. Here's a basic example to demonstrate the difference in performance of using plain `String` concatenation and building the `String` from a `StringBuilder` using [JUnit Benchmark](http://labs.carrotsearch.com/junit-benchmarks.html):

```
public class StringVsStringBuilderTest {

    @Rule
    public TestRule benchmarkRun = new BenchmarkRule();

    static final int TIMES = 1000;

    @Test
    public void stringPerformance() {
        String s = "";
        int j = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < TIMES; i++) {
            s = s + j++;
            if (j == 10) {
                j = 0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    @Test
    public void stringBuilderPerformance() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int j = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < TIMES; i++) {
            sb.append(j++);
            if (j == 10) {
                j = 0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Results:

> StringVsStringBuilderTest.stringPerformance: [measured 10 out of 15 rounds, threads: 1 (sequential)]
>   round: 0.00 [+- 0.00], round.block: 0.00 [+- 0.00], round.gc: 0.00 [+- 0.00], GC.calls: 1, GC.time: 0.00, time.total: 0.05, time.warmup: 0.02, time.bench: 0.03
>
> StringVsStringBuilderTest.stringBuilderPerformance: [measured 10 out of 15 rounds, threads: 1 (sequential)]
>   round: 0.00 [+- 0.00], round.block: 0.00 [+- 0.00], round.gc: 0.00 [+- 0.00], GC.calls: 0, GC.time: 0.00, time.total: 0.00, time.warmup: 0.00, time.bench: 0.00

Changing `TIMES` constant value to 10000:

> StringVsStringBuilderTest.stringPerformance: [measured 10 out of 15 rounds, threads: 1 (sequential)]
>   round: 0.04 [+- 0.02], round.block: 0.00 [+- 0.00], round.gc: 0.00 [+- 0.00], GC.calls: 3, GC.time: 0.00, time.total: 0.66, time.warmup: 0.27, time.bench: 0.38
>
> StringVsStringBuilderTest.stringBuilderPerformance: [measured 10 out of 15 rounds, threads: 1 (sequential)]
>   round: 0.00 [+- 0.00], round.block: 0.00 [+- 0.00], round.gc: 0.00 [+- 0.00], GC.calls: 0, GC.time: 0.00, time.total: 0.01, time.warmup: 0.00, time.bench: 0.00

In the last example, we can see the difference in time and GC calls between both. Still, if you don't really mind 0.66 seconds of your time to concatenate 10000 single values and have enough RAM, then continue using `String` concatenation (but be aware that **it is not the best design** and you're doing something wrong).

> If your string can change, and will be accessed from multiple threads, use a `StringBuffer` because `StringBuffer` is synchronous so you have thread-safety.

While this is true, looks like you could use another structure to store the `String`s like a [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) and then work with the `String`s.

Answer (score 1):

They are completely different.

`String`s are immutable and comparable, therefore can be safely used as elements of a set for example.

`StringBuilder` is mutable and not comparable, but it can be used to manipulate its contents. You must never use mutable objects in sets or as keys of maps, and should avoid using them in many other situations.

`StringBuffer` is like `StringBuilder`, but it's also thread-safe. Since string manipulation is rarely spread across multiple threads anyway, `StringBuffer` is indeed less useful in practice than `StringBuilder` and is mainly there for historical reasons.