# String or StringBuilder which takes less time to initialize? And which one is preferable to use?

Tags: java

My program want to store `Strings` and no need to perform any operations on those except storing information as it is.

Then which of the following way is preferrable?

```
String s = new String("sagar");
```

or

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("sagar");
```

Comment: [Check out this link.](http://www.techtamasha.com/difference-between-string-and-stringbufferstringbuilder-in-java/28)

Comment: Unless you're storing some unworldly amount of text within your program, you really shouldn't focus on an optimization like this unless you've proven that this is a bottleneck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [String, StringBuffer, and StringBuilder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971315/string-stringbuffer-and-stringbuilder)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `String` is a reference to an instance in the [`String` intern pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning). Since you aren't performing any string concatenation or manipulation here, I would use

```
 String s = "sagar";
```

I would not use

```
 String s = new String("sagar");
```

Because that ignores the intern pool. As for the `StringBuilder` I would prefer that when manipulating the value because (in contrast to `String`) it is mutable.

Comment: String s = new String("sagar"); also contains literal then it will  go to pool and as well as heap. is n't it?

Comment: If you try it, you will see that `String s = "sagar"; System.out.println(s == "sagar");` is **true**, but `String s = new String("sagar"); System.out.println(s == "sagar");` is **false**.

Comment: can you please elaborate this?

Comment: The first is true because the `String` is one reference in the intern pool, the second is false because there are now two `String` instances with the same value.

Comment: two String instances with the same value?? I did n't get you please

Comment: `new String()` creates a new instance.

Answer (score 1):

For your question "which of the following way is preferrable?"

it really depends on your usage.

If you need to really perform manipulations on your string then `StringBuilder` is more useful then a normal String.

Moreover `StringBuffer` is also thread safe so it can be used effectively in a multithreaded environment.

Strings are immutable in nature.

Hope this helps!

Good luck.

Comment: StringBuilder is not thread-safe. StringBuffer is thread-safe.

Comment: Gosh! missed that, deserved a negative point this.
Thanks for pointing it out @GabrielNegut

Answer (score 1):

You should use `String s = "sagar";` because it enables string literal pooling.

**What is string literal pooling?** - Like any other object creation,String creation/allocation is a memory and time consuming operation. Hence whenever a string is created it will refer to the string pool for the similar object, If such a string exists then it will refer the same.

This feature is possible as strings are immutable in java. Eventually string literal pooling will enhance the performance.

String Builder are intended for manipulations with Strings like concat().

Answer (score 1):

it is based on the using.

Actually at the time of concatenation `String builder` is effective than `Strings`.

In `String Concatenation` you can use `String builder`.

String builders are not thread safe so if you working on single thread it is effective but its not for multi-threading and `Strings` are immutable

Comment: @fastsnail Instances of StringBuilder are not safe for use by multiple threads. If such synchronization is required then it is recommended that StringBuffer be used

Comment: @SagarPudi if you knew the answer you have to answer rather than change someones answer completely

Answer (score 0):

For storage - [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

For manipulation - [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)