# how to indicate white space in java

Tags: java, string

```
public class solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "The horse jumped over the sheep";
        String str1 = "";
        for(int i = 0; i!='\0'; i++); {
            if(str.charAt(i) != ' ')
                str1=str1+str.charAt(i);
        }
        System.out.println(str1);
    }
}
```

The program shows error at variable `i`. Is there any other means to print without white spaces without any in-built function?

Comment: "The program shows error at variable i" -> what does that mean ? which line ? which error ?

Comment: You have a number of bugs in your code. try `for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)` note there is no `;` at the end.

Comment: btw `'\0' == 0`

Answer (score 2):

You have a `;` after for loop here:

```
for (int i = 0; i != '\0'; i++)
    ;
```

Remove it and variable `i` would then be recognized.

Also your comparision of `i` with `'\0'` is wrong. I think you want to compare it till the end of the string `str`.

Which **should be done like**:

```
String str = "The horse jumped over the sheep";
String str1 = "";
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    if (str.charAt(i) != ' ')
        str1 = str1 + str.charAt(i);
}
System.out.println(str1);
```

**Outputs:**

```
Thehorsejumpedoverthesheep
```

**PS:** I suggest you to read this post : [String, StringBuffer, and StringBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971315/string-stringbuffer-and-stringbuilder) as well.

Comment: and `'\0' == 0`

Comment: Can u add chars to strings like that?  I think you need Character.toString()

Comment: bt '\0' also indicates the null which is the end character of all the strings,right?

Comment: @priyapriya Not in `Java`. The length of the `String` is determined by its `length` property. In `C`, `strings` need to be `null` terminated since they are just a plain array of chars

Comment: @Jetstream5500 You won't need `Character.toString()`. `char` would be promoted to `String`.

Comment: @Jetstream5500 you still shouldn't add chars that way, though. A StringBuilder must be used so that it smooths the cost of resizing the resulting String.

Comment: @ShanuGupta I tried it just now and realized I was wrong.  I have updated my code to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

(1) You need to remove the `;` after the for loop to get rid of the error.

(2) I changed your `for` loop to a `for-each` loop as there was an error in your comparison (and it simplifies the code)

(3) I modified the code to include `StringBuilder` which will be more efficient when `str` becomes extremely long

```
String str = "a b c d";
StringBuilder str2 = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
    if (c != ' ') {
        str2.append(c);
    }
}
System.out.println(str2);
```