# Why should a Java class implement comparable?

Tags: java

Why is Java `Comparable` used?  Why would someone implement `Comparable` in a class? What is a real life example where you need to implement comparable?

Comment: Related: [When to use Comparable vs Comparator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266827/when-to-use-comparable-vs-comparator) and [Sorting an ArrayList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814095/sorting-an-arraylist-of-contacts).

Comment: There's a good example here: http://java67.blogspot.com/2012/10/how-to-sort-object-in-java-comparator-comparable-example.html

Answer (score 221, accepted):

Here is a real life sample. Note that `String` also implements `Comparable`.

```
class Author implements Comparable<Author>{
    String firstName;
    String lastName;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Author other){
        // compareTo should return < 0 if this is supposed to be
        // less than other, > 0 if this is supposed to be greater than 
        // other and 0 if they are supposed to be equal
        int last = this.lastName.compareTo(other.lastName);
        return last == 0 ? this.firstName.compareTo(other.firstName) : last;
    }
}
```

later..

```
/**
 * List the authors. Sort them by name so it will look good.
 */
public List<Author> listAuthors(){
    List<Author> authors = readAuthorsFromFileOrSomething();
    Collections.sort(authors);
    return authors;
}

/**
 * List unique authors. Sort them by name so it will look good.
 */
public SortedSet<Author> listUniqueAuthors(){
    List<Author> authors = readAuthorsFromFileOrSomething();
    return new TreeSet<Author>(authors);
}
```

Comment: I just want to note that often you'll want to override `equals` (and therefore `hashCode`) to be consistent with your `compareTo` method. For example, this is necessary if you want the class to play nice with a [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).

Comment: Why not simply return `last`?

Comment: @AnirbanNag'tintinmj' to sort automatically by the first name in case that the last name is the same.

Comment: Plus one for the good explanation of why compareTo returns an int and what it means.  Most helpful.

Comment: So the `Comparable` interface just makes it so that other Java methods, and not just the user, can compare two objects? Because otherwise, I don't see the point of implementing `Comparable` when you could just define and use a `compareTo` method without it.

Comment: @user3932000: Right, that's pretty much the point of all interfaces. But note that "other Java methods" includes methods written by the user! In fact I'd claim majority of interfaces are consumed by the user's code. In larger code bases, "yourself" quickly becomes "others"

Answer (score 42):

Comparable defines a natural ordering. What this means is that you're defining it when one object should be considered "less than" or "greater than".

Suppose you have a bunch of integers and you want to sort them. That's pretty easy, just put them in a sorted collection, right?

```
TreeSet<Integer> m = new TreeSet<Integer>(); 
m.add(1);
m.add(3);
m.add(2);
for (Integer i : m)
... // values will be sorted
```

But now suppose I have some custom object, where sorting makes sense to me, but is undefined. Let's say, I have data representing districts by zipcode with population density, and I want to sort them by density:

```
public class District {
  String zipcode; 
  Double populationDensity;
}
```

Now the easiest way to sort them is to define them with a natural ordering by implementing Comparable, which means there's a standard way these objects are defined to be ordered.:

```
public class District implements Comparable<District>{
  String zipcode; 
  Double populationDensity;
  public int compareTo(District other)
  {
    return populationDensity.compareTo(other.populationDensity);
  }
}
```

Note that you can do the equivalent thing by defining a comparator. The difference is that the comparator defines the ordering logic *outside the object*. Maybe in a separate process I need to order the same objects by zipcode - in that case the ordering isn't necessarily a property of the object, or differs from the objects natural ordering. You could use an external comparator to define a custom ordering on integers, for example by sorting them by their alphabetical value.

Basically the ordering logic has to exist somewhere. That can be -

- in the object itself, if it's naturally comparable (extends Comparable -e.g. integers)
- supplied in an external comparator, as in the example above.

Comment: good example, but it has to be `TreeSet<Integer>` instead of `TreeMap<Integer>`, for the latter does not exist, TreeMaps are always `<Key,Value>`-pairs. Btw, a hypothetical `TreeMap<District, Object>` would only work, if District implemented Comparable, right? Still trying to understand this

Answer (score 15):

Quoted from the javadoc;

> This interface imposes a total
>   ordering on the objects of each class
>   that implements it. This ordering is
>   referred to as the class's natural
>   ordering, and the class's compareTo
>   method is referred to as its natural
>   comparison method.
>
> **Lists (and arrays) of objects that
>   implement this interface can be sorted
>   automatically by Collections.sort (and
>   Arrays.sort).** Objects that implement
>   this interface can be used as keys in
>   a sorted map or as elements in a
>   sorted set, without the need to
>   specify a comparator.

Edit: ..and made the important bit bold.

Comment: I'd say that the sentence *after* the one you've bolded is just as (if not more) important.

Answer (score 9):

The fact that a class implements `Comparable` means that you can take two objects from that class and compare them. Some classes, like certain collections (sort function in a collection) that keep objects in order rely on them being comparable (in order to sort you need to know which object is the "biggest" and so forth).

Answer (score 8):

Most of the examples above show how to reuse an existing comparable object in the compareTo function. If you would like to implement your own compareTo when you want to compare two objects of the same class, say an AirlineTicket object that you would like to sort by price(less is ranked first), followed by number of stopover (again, less is ranked first), you would do the following:

```
class AirlineTicket implements Comparable<Cost>
{
    public double cost;
    public int stopovers;
    public AirlineTicket(double cost, int stopovers)
    {
        this.cost = cost; this.stopovers = stopovers ;
    }

    public int compareTo(Cost o)
    {
        if(this.cost != o.cost)
          return Double.compare(this.cost, o.cost); //sorting in ascending order. 
        if(this.stopovers != o.stopovers)
          return this.stopovers - o.stopovers; //again, ascending but swap the two if you want descending
        return 0;            
    }
}
```

Comment: Class `Cost` has an attribute `cost` as `AirlineTicket`? And the same for the attribute `stopovers` (in the two classes)? It is very strange... What is the implementation of Cost ?

Answer (score 6):

An easy way to implement multiple field comparisons is with [Guava's ComparisonChain](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ComparisonChain.html) - then you can say

```
   public int compareTo(Foo that) {
     return ComparisonChain.start()
         .compare(lastName, that.lastName)
         .compare(firstName, that.firstName)
         .compare(zipCode, that.zipCode)
         .result();
   }
```

instead of

```
  public int compareTo(Person other) {
    int cmp = lastName.compareTo(other.lastName);
    if (cmp != 0) {
      return cmp;
    }
    cmp = firstName.compareTo(other.firstName);
    if (cmp != 0) {
      return cmp;
    }
    return Integer.compare(zipCode, other.zipCode);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For example when you want to have a sorted collection or [map](https://web.archive.org/web/20111221202351/https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html)

Comment: What Fernando means is: if you store "things" that implement Comparable in a sorted container class, the sorted container class can automatically order those "things".

Answer (score 3):

Comparable is used to compare instances of your class. We can compare instances from many ways that is why we need to implement a method `compareTo` in order to know how (attributes) we want to compare instances.

#### `Dog` class:

```
package test;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog d1 = new Dog("brutus");
        Dog d2 = new Dog("medor");
        Dog d3 = new Dog("ara");
        Dog[] dogs = new Dog[3];
        dogs[0] = d1;
        dogs[1] = d2;
        dogs[2] = d3;

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println(dogs[i].getName());
        }
        /**
         * Output:
         * brutus
         * medor
         * ara
         */

        Arrays.sort(dogs, Dog.NameComparator);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println(dogs[i].getName());
        }
        /**
         * Output:
         * ara
         * medor
         * brutus
         */

    }
}
```

#### `Main` class:

```
package test;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog d1 = new Dog("brutus");
        Dog d2 = new Dog("medor");
        Dog d3 = new Dog("ara");
        Dog[] dogs = new Dog[3];
        dogs[0] = d1;
        dogs[1] = d2;
        dogs[2] = d3;

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println(dogs[i].getName());
        }
        /**
         * Output:
         * brutus
         * medor
         * ara
         */

        Arrays.sort(dogs, Dog.NameComparator);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println(dogs[i].getName());
        }
        /**
         * Output:
         * ara
         * medor
         * brutus
         */

    }
}
```

Here is a good example how to use comparable in Java:

http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/03/12/java_comp.html?page=2

Comment: You just copied your main class codebase instead of the Dog class. Where is the code for Dog.NameComparator

Answer (score 2):

When you implement `Comparable` interface, you need to implement method `compareTo()`. You need it to compare objects, in order to use, for example, sorting method of `ArrayList` class. You need a way to compare your objects to be able to sort them. So you need a custom `compareTo()` method in your class so you can use it with the `ArrayList` sort method. The `compareTo()` method returns -1,0,1.

I have just read an according chapter in Java Head 2.0, I'm still learning.

Answer (score 2):

OK, but why not just  define a `compareTo()` method without implementing comparable interface.
For example a class `City` defined by its `name` and `temperature` and

```
public int compareTo(City theOther)
{
    if (this.temperature < theOther.temperature)
        return -1;
    else if (this.temperature > theOther.temperature)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: This does not work.
Without implementing comparable - I get classcast exception