# Sorting ArrayList of Objects using Hashcode

Tags: java, sorting, collections, arraylist, hashcode

I have an ArrayList of Objects(POJOs) that have an Id and another field. I have implemented the equals()/hashcode() override in the POJO for the Id field. When I compare two objects using the equals() method of the Object class, it works perfectly fine. However when I add these objects to an arraylist and implement the

```
Collections.sort(arrListOfObjects);
```

it gives me a classCastexception. I looked up and found that I need to implement a Comparator. This comparator also does something to equals/hashcode override. If that is so then why does the above code not work?(I know that there is no comparator, but my question is, is it not possible to implement a sort based on the hashcode of the object?)

Comment: You are definitely looking to implement the Comparable interface. The `compareTo()` method is what actually determines whether something is "greater than" or "less than" another thing. the `equals()` method can only tell if something is "equal" which does not do much for ordering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the message says, your object needs to implement the Comparable interface to be sortable. Alternatively, you can provide a comparator to your `sort()` method. For example, assuming your objects are Strings and you want to sort based on hashcodes, you could do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("string", "sdkj");
    for (String s : list) {
        System.out.println(s + "=" + s.hashCode());
    }
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return o1.hashCode() - o2.hashCode();
        }
    });
    System.out.println("After Sorting");
    for (String s : list) {
        System.out.println(s + "=" + s.hashCode());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If java 8 is an option you can define it this way:

```
list.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Pojo::hashCode));
```

This approach does not require the Pojo to implement `Comparable` interface.

Answer (score 0):

Comparator does not do anything to equals or hashcode, it uses equals or hashcode to determine what it returns. It is part of the documentation for the [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) method. Take at look at at
[Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface and implement it in your class. You can take a look at the SO Question [java class implements comparable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718383/java-class-implements-comparable) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing a sort based on a hash code is certainly possible, but might not consistently produce the behavior desired. For instance, consider a class `Foo` whose `hashCode()` method is defined to always return a constant value. For example:

```
public int hashCode() {
     return 1;
}
```

Given this hashCode method in tandem with a defined Comparator using this method, lists are almost certain to not be sorted correctly, barring the trivial cases (empty list, single element list, etc.).

In general, a good thing to bear in mind is the hashCode-equals contract documented in the [java.lang.Object.hashCode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) java doc. In a nutshell, it is possible hashCode collisions may result for unequal objects, rendering sorts defined on those methods ineffective.

Answer (score 0):

With Java8 or higher being around I would implement the Comparator using a lambda expression;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("string", "sdkj");
    list.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s + "=" + s.hashCode()));

    Collections.sort(list, (o1, o2) -> (o1.hashCode() - o2.hashCode()));

    System.out.println("After Sorting");

    list.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s + "=" + s.hashCode()));
}
```