# How can i sort the array of objects[contains details like name,address] based on the Alphabetical order in java?

Tags: java

I am trying to enter the details of multiple persons and storing them in different objects.
And i have created an array for that objects, now i need to sort them according to the alphabetical order of their names.

Comment: make your `Person` class implement `Comparable<Person>` and call `Arrays.sort(persons);`

Comment: You can use a Comparator and use Arrays.sort(array,comparator).Try doing it yourself

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort a list of structs by an element of the struct in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474113/how-to-sort-a-list-of-structs-by-an-element-of-the-struct-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

Do some thing like

```
Arrays.sort( array, new Comparator<YourObject>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(YourObject o1, YourObject o2){
            return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
        }
});
```

Comment: Maybe it should be `new Comparator<YourObject>` instead of `new Comparator<Object>`

Comment: Yeah,My intention is the Object is the type in the Array :) Edited

Comment: Note that this will sort the names in lexicographical order.

Comment: @Shiney That's not the correct algorithm. Lets translate that loop into words: `Loop through the array and compare each pair of adjacent entries. If the first of these entries is larger than the second, swap places`. Now lets take a simple example: `2, 3, 1`. Your algorithm would: `Step 1: compare 2 and 3 ==> do not swap place` and we still have `2, 3, 1`. `Step 2: compare 3 and 1, swap place` and we have `2, 1, 3`. Now your algorithm is done. But the array is not sorted. You should read about `bubble sort`, a simple (though inefficient) sorting algorithm in your programming book.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a framework to sort natural language text representations of objects in locale-sensitive order:

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/text/Localizables.html

Either your "person class" would need to implement Localizable or you would have to provide a PersonLocalizer by extending Localizer.

Maven:

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.softsmithy.lib</groupId>  
    <artifactId>softsmithy-lib-core</artifactId>  
    <version>0.3</version>  
</dependency>
```

Download:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/softsmithy/files/softsmithy/v0.3/

Answer (score 0):

implement Comparable<> interface in your class and override compareTo() method in Person class. the method takes Object class as a passed value. For example,

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    //omitted

    public int compareTo(Person other) {
        return name.compareTo(other.name);
    } }
```

check out the following link to learn more http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html

Comment: As @jlordo mentioned in your post, when you call Arrays.sort(persons) will call the method of compareTo(Person other) to compare its name and sort them automatically with the interface Comparable<Person>