# Can two classes implementing same interface use other class's object as parameter in its common methods?

Tags: java, interface

In Oracle docs on [interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceAsType.html) there is a very confusing sentence

> If you make a point of implementing `Relatable` in a wide variety of classes, the objects instantiated from *any* of those classes can be compared with the `findLargerThan()` method—provided that both objects are of the same class.

I am not sure if I understood this.

Suppose there is a class `A` and `B`implementing the interface `Relatable` and I have a code in the `main()` as the following.

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();

System.out.println(a.isLargerThan(b));
```

Assume `isLargerThan()` method returns an `int` as per the interface so that the printing works.

- Would the above code be able to work for any class A and B? I think that shouldn't be possible because of each class having different implementation and most likely due to a cast to the class's type in the implementation of `isLargerThan()` in the respective classes.
- If my above deduction is correct then what is the reason of the emphasis on **any** in the oracle docs? That is my source of confusion.

I know I should implement it to find out if that works but as I am a beginner in Java my implementation itself may make it not work. That's why I asked it here.

Comment: Should not be a problem  ,as long as isLargerThan is defined to accept an Ractable object  which means you'll have access only to static final fields from the interface and interface methods when you do the comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can work for any A and B (that implements Relatable), but the caveat is that when A implements isLargerThan, it must know the type - and therefore the basis of comparison.

For example, suppose A is class Truck, and B is class Car, and both A and B implement Relatable.

When comparing one truck against another, we want the basis of comparison to be load capacity.  However, when comparing against a Car, we want it to compare based on horsepower.

So, A's isLargerThan method could be something like :

```
public class Truck implements Relatable {

    private int capacity;
    private int horsepower;

    public int isLargerThan(Relatable other) {
        if (other instanceof Truck) {
            Truck otherTruck = (Truck)other;
            return Integer.signum(capacity - otherTruck.capacity);
        } else if (other instanceof Car) {
            Car otherCar = (Car)other;
            return Integer.signum(horsepower - otherCar.getHorsepower());
        } else {
            // Maybe throw exception
        }
    }
```

So the emphasis on "any" is as stated in the final paragraph of your link :  "These methods work for any "relatable" objects, no matter what their class inheritance is. ".

Now, Relatable is just a made-up example to demonstrate an interface.  Java does have an interface called "Comparable" that's worth checking out - see for example [Why should a Java class implement comparable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718383/java-class-implements-comparable)

Answer (score 1):

If your interface method signature would be:

```
int isLargerThan(Relatable r);
```

No problem should occur.

Everything would depend on implementation.

If your implementation of A and B would work with interface `Relatable`, will not cast it to a specific implementation and will not use specific properties of each implementation - everything must be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Whether `a.isLargerThan(b)` works for classes `A` and `B` is entirely dependent on the implementation within `A`, which may or may not try to cast its parameter to `A`.

The emphasis on **any** in the docs is used to point out that the `findLargest` method can be  applied to any instances of classes implementing `Relatable`. However, it also makes the assumption that the implementation of `isLargerThan` in any implementing class will always cast the parameter to the implementing class.

Under this assumption, you can use `findLargest` to compare an `A` with another `A` or a `B` with another `B`, but not an `A` with a `B`.

Comment: Upvote for pointing out that the docs are making an assumption.

Answer (score 0):

A parameter can be an interface.  Then any class that implemtents that interface can be used.

Comparable and comparator worth looking at.