# PriorityQueue: Student cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

Tags: java, priority-queue

I'm using the PriorityQueue structure to get some fields set by the user, here is part of the code:

```
package gqg;

import java.util.Queue;

public class Student {
     //variables (ID, Name, ...), constructors, getters and setters...

Queue<Student> StudentQueue = new PriorityQueue<Student>();

public void Add() { //method to add the student at Queue
    for(int x=0; x<1; x++) {
        Student st = new Student();
        System.out.println("+---------------------------+\n"
                         + "|   Students Registration   |\n"
                         + "+---------------------------+");
        System.out.println("| Type the student's ID:");
        stu.setID(user.nextInt());
        System.out.println("| Type the student's name:");
        stu.setName(user.next());
        System.out.println("| Type the student's age:");
        stu.setAge(user.nextInt());
        //and other fields...

        StudentQueue.add(st);
    }
    System.out.println("Done. Student has been added successfuly\n");       
}

/* then I call Add(); in Menu();
 * this method also has Print(); Modify(); Eliminate(); those three works well
 * The only one problem is Add();
 */

public void Menu(){
    //... methods
}
}
```

There is no problem when I add only one "student", but the application throws this exception when I try to capture a second one

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: gqg.Student cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable     at
java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUpComparable(PriorityQueue.java:633)    at
java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUp(PriorityQueue.java:629)  at
java.util.PriorityQueue.offer(PriorityQueue.java:329)   at
java.util.PriorityQueue.add(PriorityQueue.java:306)     at
gqg.Student.AddQueue(Student.java:374)  at
gqg.Student.Menu(Student.java:592)  at
gqg.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:7)
```

Can someone explain me where/why is the problem? I spent a lot of time looking for a solution in web and I couldn't find it, I need some help here...
Tank you for helping me

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you don't provide a custom `Comparator`, `PriorityQueue` uses natural ordering on the objects it holds. That is, it expects your objects to be `Comparable` to eachother. Your `Student` class doesn't seem to implement `Comparable`.

So two options:

- Implement and provide a custom `Comparator` for comparing `Student` objects
- Have your `Student` class implement `Comparable<Student>` with the appropriate logic

Comment: How is the way to implement a comparable? sorry is the first time I use this structure

Comment: @Gus [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) is the class javadoc. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626439/how-to-implement-the-java-comparable-interface) is an example.