# How to custom sort a PrimeFaces dataTable column

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-datatable

I am trying to implement a sorting function on a PrimeFaces dataTable. I have created a list of model objects. We have an issue with sorting order of the table.The sorting column contains integers and string values. When I apply default sort mechanism like `sort=#{var.id}` the list was sorting based on ASCII order. Below is the image of the sorting result. I'm currently using PrimeFaces v5.2.5

```
<p:column headerText="Code Type" sortBy="#{var.codeType}">
    <h:outputText value="#{var.codeType}"/>
</p:column>
```

[image]

Can anybody guide me how to overcome this problem.

Comment: You are ging for "1", "2", "3" .. "10", "11" .. "20" .. "100" .. "Aaa", "Aab" .. "Zzz", right?

Comment: @Jasper: yes, you are correct.

Comment: OK. Updated my answer. Added link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104599/sort-on-a-string-that-may-contain-a-number

Answer (score 6):

There are two options here:

1. Use `sortFunction` on your `p:column`
2. Use a type which implements [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

### `sortFunction`

Create a function which takes two objects and compare them in the way comparable would:

```java
public int sortByModel(Object o1, Object o2) {
    //return -1, 0 or 1 if o1 is less than, equal to or greater than o2
}
```

And use it in your column:

```html
<p:column sortBy="#{var.codeType}" sortFunction="#{yourBean.sortByModel}">
```

### Comparable type

Use a custom type for your column and make sure that it implements `Comparable<YourCustomType>`. This forces you to implement the `compareTo(YourCustomType o)` method which you can use to sort any way you like.

See also:

- [How to implement the Java comparable interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626439/how-to-implement-the-java-comparable-interface)
- [Sort on a string that may contain a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104599/sort-on-a-string-that-may-contain-a-number)

Comment: 3rd option: make sure the 'Integers' are also converted to Strings.

Comment: In the model I mean

Comment: Hmm.. I think I have a comparator or two I'm going to rewrite :-) Thanks

Comment: Sorting when no sort function is set: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/87bb7b52060be59497dc166531f9f435b07d8879/src/main/java/org/primefaces/model/BeanPropertyComparator.java#L71