# Sort list my lastname

Tags: java, compare, string-comparison

I have an Author class written like this:

```
public final class Author implements Comparator<Author> {

    private final String authorFirstname;
    private final String authorLastname;

    public Author(String authorFirstname, String authorLastname){
        this.authorFirstname = authorFirstname;
        this.authorLastname = authorLastname;
    }

    //Left out equals/HashCode
    @Override
    public int compare(Author o1, Author o2) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return this.authorLastname.compareTo(o2.getLastname());
    }

}
```

I want to store them in a `List` collection and sort them by last name. I've read [Java 8 comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), these two examples([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626439/how-to-implement-the-java-comparable-interface),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718383/why-should-a-java-class-implement-comparable)). Have I implemented it correctly?

Comment: Generally, a `compareTo` method on an object should be the canonical and most common comparison for the object. A better option is to use `Comparator.comparing(Author::getLastname)` for when you want a more specific comparator.

Comment: suppose you refer this [post](https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-lambda-comparator-example/) on java 8 comparator.

Comment: To add on to @4castle's point, it's recommended that comparable classes be *consistent with equals*, meaning that `a.compareTo(b) == 0` should always be equal to `a.equals(b)`. I suspect that's not the case here.

Comment: @shmosel - I want to sort the authors by lastname, how would I do it?

Comment: `authors.sort(Comparator.comparing(Author::getLastName));`

Comment: @shmosel - Check my updated code. How about now?

Comment: Very unusual. Was there a problem with my suggestion?

Comment: @shmosel - I don't understand what you suggested. Perhaps a full code sample?

Comment: It's a full solution. It does exactly what you asked for - sorts a list of authors by last name. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, that it's good implemetation.
Second way is:

```
List<Author> list = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Author>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Author a1, Author a2) {
        return a1.getLastName().compareTo(a2.getLastName());
    }
});
```

And use this in place where you want to sort this list.

@Update, third option:

```
public static class AuthorComparator implements Comparator<Author> {
   @Override
   public int compare(Author a1, Author a2) {
       return a1.getLastName().compareTo(a2.getLastName());
   }
}
```

You have to put this in your Author class.
And where you want to sort:

```
List<Author> list = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.sort(list, new Author.AuthorComparator());
```

Comment: Do I have to use the anonymous class here, or is there an alternative?

Comment: You can use static inner class.