# Sort List<Object[]> after three objects

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I have a list `List<Object[]>`.

The  Object[]  has the following objects:

- Date "dd.MM.yyyy"
- String
- Date "HH:mm".

I am able to sort the list after the `dd.MM.yyyy` and then after the `String`. Now I want to sort it after the time too also the result should be sorted "dd.MM.yyyy", sorted "String", sorted "time".

```
Collections.sort(resultList, new Comparator<Object[]>() {
    public int compare(Object[] o1, Object[] o2) {
        int dateComparison = (( o2[0]).compareTo(o1[0]));
        return dateComparison == 0 ? ( o1[1]).compareTo( o2[1]) : dateComparison;
    }
});
```

How can I get it to work?

Comment: What is your actual problem? You need to add another comparison

Comment: Please elaborate or provide an example/use case.

Comment: How can you call `compareTo` if those are just Objects?

Comment: Don't use `Object[]`, especially like this. It looks like each Object array should be an instance of a class. Create a class Foo with three fields then make a `List<Foo>`. You can then make your [`Foo` class implement Comparable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626439/how-to-implement-the-java-comparable-interface) which allows you to call `Collections.sort` without specifying a Comparator.

Comment: @tobias_k Good spot. That, and the fact that there's weird superfluous brackets around the `o2[0]` and `o2[1]`, make me suspect they've edited out a cast.

Comment: Fyi: I updated my answer. Just in case you want to continue with your current approach - you now have some info how to easily do that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick accept :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is: *wrong* abstraction.

When you have "data" that belongs together, then you turn that into a **class**.

Meaning: instead of keeping *three* lists with data, you create a class that reasonably "wraps" around these three pieces of information. And then you create an array/list of that **class**.

Because then you can easily create *different* Comparator objects that compare objects of that class - by looking at *different* fields for example.

In other words: your are (more or less) writing "procedural" code with flat data, and "outside" code that "combines" that flat data. But when using a OO language such as Java, you should instead strive to create helpful abstractions.

But in case you want to go on with your approach, have a look at this pseudo code:

```
int dateComparison = o2[0].compareTo(o1[0]);
if (dateComparison != 0) return dateComparison;

int stringComparison = o2[1].compareTo(o1[1]);
if (stringComparison != 0) return stringComparison;

int secondDateComparison = o2[2].compareTo(o1[2]);
return dateComparison;
```

( obviously you need some casts here and there, but as your input isn't using them I left that out as well )

Comment: And just for the record: I added the "direct" answer part as well.

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
resultList.sort(
    Comparator.comparing((Object[] a) -> (Date)a[0])
        .thenComparing(a -> (String)a[1])
        .thenComparing(a -> (Date)a[2]));
```

Comment: Nice one. I am always surprised to see what interesting (and easy to digest!) solutions are possible using lambdas!

Answer (score -1):

Merge your Date and Time objects into a [java.util.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), then use your String as the key in a HashMap. From here, you can sort the `List<HashMap<String, Date>` by getting the Date first, then comparing the String keys using `compareTo()`.

Just as a side note: if you are using a List of Arrays or a List of Lists, then it's likely a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Comment: What about the `String` element at index `1`?