# Bubble sort java not working

Tags: java, bubble-sort

```
public void sortTracksList()
{
    for(int j=0; j<tracksArray.length; j++)
    {
        for(int k =0; k<(tracksArray.length-1); k++)
        {

            if(tracksArray[k] > tracksArray[k+1])
            {
                int tempTracksArray = tracksArray[k];
                tracksArray[k] = tracksArray[k+1];
                tracksArray[k+1] = tempTracksArray;

            }
        }
    }

    for (int l = 0; l < tracksArray.length; l++)
    {
        System.out.println(tracksArray[l].toString());
    }
}
```

That's my code and it has 3 errors:

```
 //if(tracksArray[k] > tracksArray[k+1]) - bad operand types for binary operator
    //int tempTracksArray = tracksArray[k]; - Tracks cannot be converted to int
    //tracksArray[k+1] = tempTracksArray; - int cannot be converted to Tracks
```

Tracks class:

```
public class Tracks
{   
    int trackID;
    String trackTitle;
    String trackArtist;
    double trackLength;
    boolean trackOffline;


    public String toString()
    {

        String trackData = trackID + "," +trackTitle + "," + trackArtist + 
        "," + trackLength + "," + trackOffline;
        return trackData;
    }
}
```

Needs to be sorted by ID

Comment: What is `tracksArray`?

Comment: Tracks[] tracksArray = new Tracks[100];

Comment: you cannot compare objects with simple operators like `>`. That only works on primitive types like `int`, `long` etc.

Comment: You need to post your Tracks class to better understand how one Tracks object is to be compared to another Tracks object.

Comment: For the error on `tracksArray[k] > tracksArray[k+1]` you should probably go read up on [Comparable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626439/how-to-implement-the-java-comparable-interface). The other two errors are fixed by simply changing the type of `tempTracksArray`, although the error should make that obvious.

Comment: How should it be sorted?  By title, by id?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two issues.

1. `int tempTracksArray = tracksArray[k];` is incorrect.  The tracksArray definition is `Tracks[] tracksArray`; the array holds objects of type `Tracks`.  Therefore the correct temporary assignment is `Tracks tempTracksArray = tracksArray[k];`
2. The `>` operator is not allowed on objects.  Two approaches are shown below to solve this.

Option 1: Compare the integers

```
for(int j=0; j<tracksArray.length; j++)
{
    for(int k =0; k<(tracksArray.length-1); k++)
    {
        if(tracksArray[k].trackID > tracksArray[k+1].trackID)
        {
            Tracks tempTracksArray = tracksArray[k];
            tracksArray[k] = tracksArray[k+1];
            tracksArray[k+1] = tempTracksArray;

        }
    }
}
```

Option 2:  Use the Comparable interface

```
for(int j=0; j<tracksArray.length; j++)
{
    for(int k =0; k<(tracksArray.length-1); k++)
    {
        if(tracksArray[k].compareTo(tracksArray[k+1]) > 0)
        {
            Tracks tempTracksArray = tracksArray[k];
            tracksArray[k] = tracksArray[k+1];
            tracksArray[k+1] = tempTracksArray;

        }
    }
}
```

In which case your Tracks class must implement Comparable:

```
class Tracks implements Comparable<Tracks> {
    int trackID;
    ......
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Tracks o) {
        return Integer.compare(this.trackID, o.trackID);
    }
}
```

The second option is preferred.  Your Tracks class now has a natural method to describe how it should be sorted.