# How to compare instanced DateTime objects?

Tags: java, datetime

I'm writing a program to sort datetimes by date.
There is a DateTime beginning and a DateTime end.
These are put into their own object from user input.
The DateTime beginning and the DateTime end make up their own term.
So each term has an object of its own with a DateTime beginning and a DateTime end.

What I want to do is to sort all DateTime beginning and all DateTime end by date.
How can I do this? I'm thinking about a comperator but I can't seem to do this on custom objects.

So lets say user imputs one `beginning date of 01/01/2000` and one `end date of 01/01/2002`. This makes up one term.
The user then imputs a second term consisting of a `beginning date of 01/01/2001` and an `end date of 01/01/2003`.

What I now want to do is to sort the dates and make the three new terms which would be:

```
beginning 01/01/2000 end 01/01/2001

beginning 01/01/2001 end 01/01/2002

beginning 01/01/2002 end 01/01/2003
```

I'm stuck on how to proceed with this, any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) which implements `Comparable` and has many useful features. Your question looks like you also want to know [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), if time of day does not matter in your use case. Try out some code, then if stuck, ask another question here with a specific code problem.

Comment: Just implement comparable interface? Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626439/how-to-implement-the-java-comparable-interface/21626632

Comment: Why are there 3 terms if you only input 2 terms?

Comment: Share the class that holds your Begin and End, and the code you made to solve this

Comment: I think some more examples, using year ranges with larger spreads, would be useful.  Do you want to create a term for each year in any of the ranges input by the user?

Comment: The end of one term is the beginning of the next term. This is why it goes from two to three terms.

Comment: So do you want to sort them by start date or what? Are you expecting also to split the intervals when they overlap?

Comment: @jbx yes, thats what i want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put every date in a new collection, sort it by the date, and then create new objects that consist neighbour dates from the collection.

Try:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<YourClass> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.add(new YourClass(new Date(100000000), new Date(200000000)));
    list.add(new YourClass(new Date(150000000), new Date(250000000)));
    list.add(new YourClass(new Date(50000000), new Date(300000000)));

    System.out.println(list);

    List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<>();
    for (YourClass yc : list){
        if (!dates.contains(yc.beginning)) dates.add(yc.beginning);
        if (!dates.contains(yc.end)) dates.add(yc.end);
    }

    Collections.sort(dates);

    List<YourClass> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i=0; i < dates.size() -1; i++){
        list2.add(new YourClass(dates.get(i), dates.get(i+1)));
    }

    System.out.println(list2);

}

public static class YourClass {
    Date beginning;
    Date end;

    public YourClass(Date beginning, Date end) {
        this.beginning = beginning;
        this.end = end;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\n" + beginning  + " -> " + end ;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe your algorithm is right, but you shouldn’t use the poorly designed and long outdated `Date` class.

Comment: Yes, its not best solution, just an illustration of algorithm working. LocalDate class is preferred for workig with date and implements Comparable as like a Date class.

Comment: This is doing exactly what I want it to do and half the code I had already. I only added the new Array and sorted it via collections. Thanks for this so far. But I fail to understand why this works. How does the .sort in collections know how I want to sort it exactly?

Comment: Date class,  LocalDate class, Integer class and more else classes implement Comparable interface. It means that inside the class discribed the rule how to compare two this class objects. And Sort method use this rule for sorting.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

> What I want to do is to sort all DateTime beginning and all DateTime end by date.

You can do one or the other but not both.

To sort by start date (seems sensible in practice), implement `compareTo` method.

```
return this.getDateRange().getStart().compareTo( thatStart );
```

To sort by stop date (I do not see any sense in this), implement the `Comparator` interface.

```
return 
    t1.getDateRange().getEnd().compareTo( 
        t2.getDateRange().getEnd() 
    )
;
```

## `LocalDate`

As others noted, you should be using the modern *java.time* classes, never the terrible old `Date`/`Calendar`/`SimpleDateFormat` classes. For a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone, use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).

## `LocalDateRange`

As the [Answer by jbx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53285049/642706) discusses, you should represent your term’s start and stop dates as a pair. But do not write a class when one already exists. Use [`LocalDateRange`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html) class from the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. This project adds functionality to the *java.time* classes.

## `Comparable`

On your `Term` class, implement `Comparable` interface to enable simple easy sorting. Add the method `compareTo`. The obvious approach there would be to compare the starting `LocalDate` of each `Term` object’s `LocalDateRange` object.

The `LocalDate` class implements `compareTo`, no we don’ have to.

```
@Override
public int compareTo ( Object o ) {
    if ( this == o ) return 0;
    if ( o == null || getClass() != o.getClass() ) return 0;
    LocalDate thatStart = ( ( Term ) o ).getDateRange().getStart();
    return this.getDateRange().getStart().compareTo( thatStart );
}
```

See the [Java Tutorial on object-ordering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html).

## Sort by stop date

Your Question is not clear, but you seem to be asking to alternatively sort by the ending date. I cannot imagine how this is useful in practical terms. But anyways, the solution is to sort by providing an implementation of the [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface.

```
    @Override
    public int compare ( Term t1 , Term t2 ) {
        return t1.getDateRange().getEnd().compareTo( t2.getDateRange().getEnd() );
    }
```

## Example class

Here is an example `Term` class. May not be production-quality code, but should get you going in the right direction.

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

import org.threeten.extra.LocalDateRange;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.util.*;

public class Term implements Comparable {
    private UUID id;
    private LocalDateRange dateRange;

    // Constructor
    public Term ( LocalDate start , LocalDate stop , UUID id ) {
        Objects.requireNonNull( start ); // TODO: Add more such checks for all arguments.
        if ( start.getYear() < 2015 ) {  // TODO: Add more such checks for too far into the past or future, for both start and for stop.
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Year of start date is too far in the past. Message # afcd30a0-b639-4ccf-b064-18cc2ea8587b." );
        }
        this.id = id;
        this.dateRange = LocalDateRange.of( start , stop );
    }

    // Alternative constructor.
    public Term ( LocalDateRange dateRange , UUID id ) {
        this( dateRange.getStart() , dateRange.getEnd() , id );
    }



    // --------|  Object  |-------------------------
    @Override
    public String toString ( ) {
        return "Term{ " +
                "id=" + id +
                " | dateRange=" + dateRange +
                " }";
    }

    public UUID getId ( ) {
        return id;
    }

    public LocalDateRange getDateRange ( ) {
        return dateRange;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals ( Object o ) {
        if ( this == o ) return true;
        if ( o == null || getClass() != o.getClass() ) return false;
        Term term = ( Term ) o;
        return this.getId().equals( term.getId() );
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode ( ) {
        return Objects.hash( this.getId() );
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo ( Object o ) {
        if ( this == o ) return 0;  // If same object.
        if ( o == null || getClass() != o.getClass() ) return 0;
        LocalDate thatStart = ( ( Term ) o ).getDateRange().getStart();
        return this.getDateRange().getStart().compareTo( thatStart );
    }

    static public class StopDateComparator implements Comparator < Term > {

        @Override
        public int compare ( Term t1 , Term t2 ) {
            return t1.getDateRange().getEnd().compareTo( t2.getDateRange().getEnd() );
        }
    }

}
```

Try it.

```
public static void main ( String[] args ) {
    Term t1 = new Term( LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JUNE , 23 ) , LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JULY , 23 ) , UUID.randomUUID() );
    Term t2 = new Term( LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) , LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.DECEMBER , 23 ) , UUID.randomUUID() );
    Term t3 = new Term( LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.MARCH , 23 ) , LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.APRIL , 23 ) , UUID.randomUUID() );
    List < Term > terms = new ArrayList <>( List.of( t1 , t2 , t3 ) );
    System.out.println( "Before natural sort: " + terms );
    Collections.sort( terms );
    System.out.println( "After natural sort: " + terms );
    Collections.sort( terms , new Term.StopDateComparator() );
    System.out.println( "After Comparator sort: " + terms );
}
```

> Before natural sort: [Term{ id=27c0b9e6-076f-4ded-9bbd-bf1a2c7914bc | dateRange=2018-06-23/2018-07-23 }, Term{ id=792bf365-eca4-460b-afad-c5cf62cf9a29 | dateRange=2018-01-23/2018-12-23 }, Term{ id=c49f79e1-11cd-4865-aa46-8fbf3c85dbfd | dateRange=2018-03-23/2018-04-23 }]
>
> After natural sort: [Term{ id=792bf365-eca4-460b-afad-c5cf62cf9a29 | dateRange=2018-01-23/2018-12-23 }, Term{ id=c49f79e1-11cd-4865-aa46-8fbf3c85dbfd | dateRange=2018-03-23/2018-04-23 }, Term{ id=27c0b9e6-076f-4ded-9bbd-bf1a2c7914bc | dateRange=2018-06-23/2018-07-23 }]
>
> After Comparator sort: [Term{ id=c49f79e1-11cd-4865-aa46-8fbf3c85dbfd | dateRange=2018-03-23/2018-04-23 }, Term{ id=27c0b9e6-076f-4ded-9bbd-bf1a2c7914bc | dateRange=2018-06-23/2018-07-23 }, Term{ id=792bf365-eca4-460b-afad-c5cf62cf9a29 | dateRange=2018-01-23/2018-12-23 }]

## `abuts`

If your `Term` objects should run up against one another in succession, you can test for that using the [`LocalDateRange::abuts`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html#abuts-org.threeten.extra.LocalDateRange-) method.

The approach in comparing is Half-Open, where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. So a year starts on the first of the year and runs up to, but does not include, the first of the *following* year. You show this in your examples in the Question.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the question is not just about sorting, but also about splitting overlapping intervals into smaller segments. You have to play a lot with [Interval Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic).

With Java 8 you can start by encoding your 'terms' as a time Interval, which in itself is `Comparable`. The second part would be to split your intervals into multiple ones if the user specifies overlapping ones.

```
class Interval implements Comparable<Interval> {
  private final LocalDateTime start;
  private final LocalDateTime end;

  public Interval(LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime end) {
     this.start = start;
     this.end = end;
  }

  public int compareTo(Interval that) {
    return this.start.compareTo(that.start);
  }

  public boolean overlaps(Interval that) {
    return !this.isBefore(that) && !this.isAfter(that);
  }

  public boolean contains(Interval that) {
    return this.start.isBefore(that.start) && this.end.isAfter(that.end);
  }

  public boolean isBefore(Interval that) {
    return this.end.isBefore(that.start);
  }

  public boolean isAfter(Interval that) {
    return this.start.isAfter(that.end);
  }

  public Set<Interval> fragment(Interval that) {
    if (that.start.isBefore(this.start)) {
      return that.fragment(this);
    }

    Set<Interval> result = new HashSet<>();
    if (this.end.isBefore(that.start)) {
       result.add(this);
       result.add(that);
       result.add(new Interval(this.end, that.start));
    } else if ((this.end.isAfter(that.start) && this.end.isBefore(that.end)) {
       result.add(new Interval(this.start, that.start);
       result.add(new Interval(that.start, this.end);
       result.add(new Interval(this.end, that.end));
    } else if (this.end.isAfter(that.end)) {
       result.add(new Interval(this.start, that.start);
       result.add(new Interval(that);
       result.add(new Interval(that.end, this.end));
    }
  }
}
```

You can now keep them sorted, since `Interval`s are comparable by start date.
Whenever the user enters a new `Interval` (term) you have to go through the list and checks whether it `contains()` the existent interval, or whether it comes before it, with `isBefore()` or `isAfter()`. If it `overlaps()` you have to be careful if to also check whether it overlaps with the next interval in the list.

You can then call `fragment()` which will combine the 2 intervals together into smaller ones. You need to be careful to remove the previous ones. So maybe makes sense to just go through the list and check if they overlap or not. If you reach the end you can still use `fragment()` to combine two disjoint intervals.