# Generic methods and implementations used in Magic Cup

Tags: java

I have already turned this in for a 0 in my class as I just dont know what to do or how to start it past what was shown in class, Which was very little. Could someone please teach me or show me where to go for my own sake to learn what im suppose to do here.

The objective is this: In this we will create a Data Structure that represents a Generic Magic Cup. In our lab we should create a generic interface for Magic items and it should be called Magic, as well as creating a generic class called Magic Cup that implements magic. All magical items should give you the ability to show whats in the item, to empty the item, place an item inside of it, or compare the magic item to another item. A magic cup should be able to hold any item of any type. We should be able to check a cup to see if it is currently empty or if it contains an item. Imagine the cup trick that is commonly done by street artist.

To test your work, in a main method you should create a methodology that implements three cups of different type, ie. ints, strings, booleans and even magic cups. Then you should be able to use the method to see if you can find the filed cup or search through all cups to see if magic happened.

so far all I have is this:

Main Method:

```
import java.util.*;

interface Magic<T>{
    void add();
    void remove();
    void check();
    void compare();
    void show();

}
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    //int cups
    Cup<Integer> cup = new Cup<Integer>(8);
    Cup<Integer> cup1 = new Cup<Integer>(32);
    Cup<Integer> cup2 = new Cup<Integer>(10);
    
    //string cups
    Cup<String> cup3 = new Cup<String>("Hello");
    Cup<String> cup4 = new Cup<String>("Test");
    Cup<String> cup5 = new Cup<String>("I am in a cup");
    
    
    //boolean cups
    Cup<Boolean> cup6 = new Cup<Boolean>(true);
    Cup<Boolean> cup7 = new Cup<Boolean>(false);
    Cup<Boolean> cup8 = new Cup<Boolean>(true);
    
    //Magic cups
    magicCup<> magicCup = new magicCup<>();
    magicCup<> magicCup1 = new magicCup<>();
    magicCup<> magicCup2 = new magicCup<>();
    
    System.out.println(cup.getData());
}
```

}

Cup method:

```
public class Cup<T>{
T data;
Cup(T data){
    this.data=data;
}

void setData(T data) {
    this.data = data;
}

T getData() {
    return data;
}
```

}

MagicCup Method:

public class magicCup implements Magic {

```
@Override
public void add(magicCup<T>) {
    T data;
    magicCup(T data){
        this.data=data;
    }
    
    void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    
    T getData() {
        return data;
    }   
}

@Override
public void remove() {
    
    
}

@Override
public void check() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}

@Override
public void compare() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}

@Override
public void show() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}
```

}

If someone would be willing to sit down with me for a little bit and walk me through what I would even do to start. I would greatly appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

First,
Your Magic interface should use or return data in their methods like

```java
interface Magic<T> extends Comparable<Magic<?>>{
    void add(T object);
    void remove();
    boolean check();
    void show();
}
```

Then your MagicCup `add` and `remove` should only set `data` like

```java
@Override
public void add(T object) {
    if(! this.check()) { // Otherwise the cup is already full
        this.data = object;
    }
}

@Override
public void remove() {
    this.data = null;
}
```

Then `check` does check if there's an object inside

```java
@Oveeride
public boolean check() { // isEmpty() would be better
    return this.data != null;
}
```

Then `show` wil return a representation (should be `toString` inheritted from `Object`) like

```java
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Cup contains: "+ this.data.toString();
}
@Override
public void show() {
    System.out.println(this.toString());
}
```

Finally `compare` will be inherited from `Comparable` through `compareTo(Object other)` and compare data with another `Magic` which I let you implement with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626439/how-to-implement-the-java-comparable-interface)

Comment: Thank you for this and your time putting it together. Im gonna sit down and try these and try and understand why we use these.