# How would I go about this Generic code? - Java

Tags: java, generics, runtime-error, csc

I can't get the following line of code to work it [also tells me this, but I don't know what to do with the information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAOqY.png)

```
quickSort(c, 0, c.length - 1);
```

This is the method

```
static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void quickSort(T[] a, int p, int r){
            if (p < r){
            int q = partition(a,p,r);
            quickSort(a,p,q-1);
            quickSort(a,q+1,r);
```

but the line

```
quickSort(a, 0, a.length - 1);
```

works fine

side note: the "c" is supposed to represent a circle object which I have a class made for I think that this has to do with maybe the code in the class but I am really lost on what to put in it, this is what I have

```
class Circle<T>
{
    T obj;
    Circle(T obj) {  this.obj = obj;  }  // constructor
    public T getObject()  { 
        return this.obj; }
}
```

I don't know what else to add to this post if you have any questions or would like me to clarify anything else please let me know

[This is a picture of the whole program minus the class which I inserted above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRsB2.png)

Comment: That quicksort() method works on T's that implement Comparable<T>. Your Circle class needs to implement Comparable<Circle>. See the question [How to implement the Java comparable interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626439/how-to-implement-the-java-comparable-interface).

Comment: You tried to invoke a method that expects an array as the first parameter with a single object `c` that is a `Circle`.