# Repeat Values in array and shuffle it

Tags: java, arrays, shuffle

I'm having trouble shuffling a two dimensional array in Java. There are 10 base cards.

This is the array:

```
String[][] Cards = new String[][] {
        {"CardType1","CardName1","CardProperties"},
        {"CardType1","CardName2","CardProperties"},
        {"CardType1","CardName3","CardProperties"},
        {"CardType2","CardName4","CardProperties"},
        {"CardType2","CardName5","CardProperties"},
        {"CardType2","CardName6","CardProperties"},
        {"CardType2","CardName7","CardProperties"},
        {"CardType3","CardName8","CardProperties"},
        {"CardType3","CardName9","CardProperties"},
        {"CardType3","CardName10","CardProperties"}
        };
```

Each card must replicate itself 4 times to complete a deck with 40 cards and then shuffle it. How can I use Java to do this?

Comment: This is the wrong approach. Use an `Object` like `Card` to store the properties. Then use a `List` rather than an array. Use a loop to populate the `List` and then `Collections.shuffle` to shuffle the `List`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @JBNizet knocked something together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have a little object phobia. Lets start with an `enum` for `CardType`:

```
public enum CardType {
    TYPE_1,
    TYPE_2,
    TYPE_3,
    //etc...
    ;
}
```

Not sure what card name is, but lets leave it as a `String`. Not sure what card properties is either - lets call this a `Map<String, String>`. So our `Card` class would be something like:

```
public class Card {
    private final CardType cardType;
    private final String cardName;
    private final Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();

    Card(final CardType cardType, final String cardName) {
        this.cardType = cardType;
        this.cardName = cardName;
    }

    public Card setProperty(final String name, final String value) {
        properties.put(name, value);
        return this;
    }

    public String getProperty(final String name) {
        return properties.get(name);
    }
}
```

Add [getters and setters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2036991/2071828), also [`toString`](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=55), [`equals` and `hashCode`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27609/2071828) methods. Possibly make `Card` [implement `Comparable<Card>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3718515/2071828).

So to create a `Card` you would call:

```
final Card card = new Card(CardType.TYPE_1, "CardName1");
```

And to set properties, because the method is [chainable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) you can do:

```
final Card card = new Card(CardType.TYPE_1, "CardName1").
        setProperty("prop1", "thing").
        setProperty("prop2", "stuff");
```

Now, to create your deck, you need 4 cards of each type, this is simple. With Java 8:

```
final List<Card> deck = Stream.of(CardType.values()).
        flatMap(type -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 4).mapToObj(num -> new Card(type, "CardName" + num))).
        collect(toList());
```

Pre Java 8 to create the `List` you can use explicit loops:

```
final List<Card> deck = new LinkedList<>();
for (final CardType cardType : CardType.values()) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; ++i) {
        final Card card = new Card(cardType, "CardName" + i);
        deck.add(card);
    }
}
```

In order to shuffle a `Collection` simply use [`Collections.shuffle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) like so:

```
Collections.shuffle(deck);
```

Comment: Thank you @Boris!  
One more thing, where do I put `Collections.shuffle(deck);`

Comment: What do you mean? Where are you putting the rest of the code? You put it where you want to shuffle the deck...

Comment: Forget that one,. how to get the card and it's properties from `deck` and `System.out.print` it?

Comment: In what sense get a card. Draw the top card from the deck? Get some particular card? You need to be more specific with your questions...

Comment: *How to get a card from top of the deck and `System.out.print` it's name and properties?

Comment: I would suggest that you first read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html) - it will explain what a `List` is. And what it can do. If you just want to see the top card you can use `List.get(0)`. If you want to _remove_ the top card the `List.remove(0)` which will also give you the card removed.

Comment: So if I want to get a card's name and property from another class, I would use `Card.deck.get(0)`?

Comment: Why is `deck` a `static` member of `Card`? I don't really understand where you are getting this from.

Comment: This is your code that I combined together, I don't know if it's correct but here it is [link](http://pastebin.com/qkG55hiH)

Comment: I don't believe that that code will compile. You need to read some basic Java tutorials.

Comment: I'd go with that suggestion, but can you correct the code on that link?